# How do I thank the community?

Tags: discussion, thanks

Let's say I'm working on this really complicated application and I took help from quite a few Stack Exchange sites on the way. How do I thank the network/community?

Are there any badges/buttons/images which we can put on our apps/websites saying something along the lines of "Made with help from the Stack Exchange Network" or "Contributions by the community members at StackExchange.com"?

Maybe something like:
[image: thanks!]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same way you do it every time. Add a line into the **Credits** menu item / help chapter etc. Putting a logo is problematic since it implies endorsement, and is legally tricky, so best stay away from using the logo.

Please be specific and acknowledge all sources/inspirations for your algorithms. If possible, **make the application open source**.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, My apps are ALWAYS open source :D

Comment: I haven't seen any apps with a credits section. Don't recall any with a help section either.

Comment: @Dom Apps can be Windows Applications too :/

Comment: @Dom Sometimes that comes under the "about" section. You won't see it if you're not looking for it.