# A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required

Tags: discussion, licensing, feedback, creative-commons

> ### Update: January 15, 2016
>
> **Thank you for your patience and feedback. The changes proposed here have been delayed indefinitely - we'll be back later to open some more discussions.**

---

> Important context for those arriving from reddit and slashdot links:
> **The status quo is not "public domain"; attribution is already required.**
>
> See:
>
> - [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow)
> - [Can we get some explicit clarification on the *intended* legal usage of code from SO answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro/286597#286597)

---

> **TLDR:** This is a follow-up to [our initial proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) for transitioning to a more user-friendly code license. The purpose of *this* post is to address the concern expressed most frequently in response to the initial proposal: no attribution requirement. Also, we want to make sure everyone has ample opportunity to provide feedback and we have time to consider it. We are more concerned with doing this right than doing it fast, so please let us know what you think about this proposed change.

A month ago [we proposed new licensing terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) to cover code posted at Stack Overflow and across the Stack Exchange network. Hundreds of you voted on the proposal, and many of you let us know how we could improve. We gathered all your feedback, and after careful consideration we have amended the proposal.

2 changes:

1. **Attribution now continues to be required** when you use code found at Stack
   Overflow and Stack Exchange
2. <s>The changes will now go into effect **March 1, 2016**</s> The changes proposed here have been delayed indefinitely.

Change 1 was made to accommodate contributors who want credit, plus to help developers identify the provenance of a Stack Overflow code snippet when they find it integrated into a project. Change 2 was made to allow you more time to digest this change and socialize it within your organizations.

Both changes were thoroughly vetted internally, with our lawyers, and with the OSI. We think they are an improvement upon the previous proposal, and a vast improvement upon the status quo.

As always, community input has been instrumental in moving this initative forward. We're fairly certain we've arrived at the best possible balance for everyone's needs, but if you spot anything new you think we've missed, please let us know.

**The Fine Print:**

> When the change goes live, new contributions across the network will be
> licensed to the public under the following terms:
>
> - Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the terms of CC-BY-SA
> - Code contributions will be available for use under the terms of [the MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
> - You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT
>   License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give
>   reasonable attribution. This optional exception to the MIT License
>   will live in our terms of service.

The only difference between the terms described above and the previous proposal is the removal of the requirement to add attribution *only* “upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the copyright holder)”. “Reasonable attribution” is now required by end users of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

**What is reasonable attribution?**

A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution.

There are certainly other forms of reasonable attribution, depending on use, and you are welcome to go above and beyond what’s required and include username, date, and anything else if you like.

You are also welcome to use the MIT License as it is traditionally interpreted: by preserving the full license with relevant fields (copyright year and copyright holder) completed.

Full guidance will be provided in an upcoming FAQ.

**When will the new terms go into effect?**

<s>March 1, 2016</s> The changes proposed here have been delayed indefinitely.

**What about other sites on the Stack Exchange network?**

The new terms will go into effect for all new code on all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

We understand that some users feel the new terms are not a perfect fit for certain sites, but we think fragmenting the license across the network will lead to ambiguity – the exact problem we’re trying to solve by updating the terms.

**What about code contributed prior to this change?**

This change is just a first step in establishing clarity for using code found on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. Code contributed prior to this change will be governed by the CC BY-SA license as it has always been. We are exploring ways we might distinguish code covered by each license regime, and we hope to soon roll out an opt-in mechanism to let users relicense their old contributions under the new terms.

**But what is code?**

We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ, plus guidance on how best to comply with the attribution requirement. But ultimately, identifying code will be a judgement call on your part. We have full faith in your ability to do this.

**What’s next?**

We want to hear what you think. Barring any showstopper, <s>these terms and a detailed FAQ will be rolled out March 1, 2016</s>.

Comment: So we still have a split of how code and non-code is licensed?

Comment: Do you actually expect people to do this? Will code be full of SO links, really? Given how many don't bother to upvote things they find useful, leaving a link in code -- which would typically not help maintainers of the code -- is hardly a consideration.

Comment: I'm going to just start putting an ingredient list on my projects. `This software is made with 45% Stack Overflow recycled content`.

Comment: The voting on the previous meta post is not a reliable indicator for how the community views this version of the proposal in my opinion. There are just too many different concerns mixed into this single number.

Comment: @samthebrand, *"we think fragmenting the license across the network will lead to ambiguity"*. Then why do it? By having one license for 'code' and another for 'non-code', you *are* fragmenting the license across the network. This is lunacy.

Comment: Oy. Analysis of how to properly define a groups' collective response is distracting here, IMO.  I'm editing to get that out of the way, so we can focus on the changes to license itself that were added based on community feedback.  (I'm gonna clean up these comments, too.  You can totally still repost "well, *I* didn't feel positive", but the current methodology debate shouldn't be the core issue.)

Comment: @samthebrand, *"ultimately, identifying code will be a judgement call on your part. We have full faith in your ability to do this."* Why do you have faith in our ability to do this, given that no-one knows how to do this? Wouldn't it be better to retain sane, consistent licensing than to predicate the supposed benefit of your change upon explicitly expecting a miracle?

Comment: I have full faith in any decent lawyer being able to present a convincing argument that whatever judgement call I made, it was wrong.

Comment: "*But what is code? We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ...*" **No**, give guidance **now**. You're trying to change the license of code without clearly delineating boundaries for what is and isn't code. That's a very, very important part of this. Don't just hand wave it into the future long after this discussion should have been had.

Comment: You will find better luck persuading many people if you follow [Shog's advice here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1048539). This reads like, "we're doing this regardless of what you think, but please let us know your thoughts!" which... :(

Comment: @samthebrand, what is the value of attribution without sharealike and with no requirement to include a license? OK, so a first generation derivative work might have to include attribution, but if the first derivative is distributed without a license or under a license not requiring attribution, authors of second derivative works are - bam - not required to attribute! **You have created a gaping code-laundering loophole. Effectively, you are making Stack Exchange [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) for code**. This is a *huge* change. At least have the guts to say it.

Comment: What about snippets of code you copy/paste into your post from a third-party project? Does it suddenly become MIT? And what about Code Review?

Comment: I want to explain my down vote here. This idea is much better than the original post. However, I don't like that some key aspects are being pushed off. Please come back when you have a definition of code, an approach to help everyone understand what is licensed under what license, and the rest of your FAQ complete. Also, like @enderland suggested, [follow Shog9's advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1048539).

Comment: *A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution.* does this include closed source applications?

Comment: @DeerHunter, are you really arguing that it's *delusional* to interpret a post at +500 as anything other than "the community disagrees"?

Comment: @Jaydles - 449 people upvoted the top post outlining our concerns and arguing against the proposal.

Comment: @Jaydles I think the point is that if downvoting would have required 15 rep too, we might have seen something like +500/-1000 on that question

Comment: @Jaydles considering an answer saying, [In summary, please don't do this to us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271113/193412) had +426? I think it's worth saying the community is not quite in agreement...

Comment: Please, roll the FAQ out before you commit this colossal blunder.

Comment: "**A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution.**" Personally, I'd still go back to this: [boilerplate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271105#271105) and reqire full MIT license requirements. No exceptions!

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are trying to solve here? Users aren't pissed off enough already? The community hates this and there has been little justification for the change, so, unless you want more resistance, learn to use meta properly and write a feature-request that details an **actual problem that you want to solve**.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Does this mean that if I use code from an answer in my project I need to add a comment that says "Thanks to John Doe for this code in this answer to my SO question."?

Comment: @CalebKleveter I'd make it more specifically a link to the answer and make the requirement complete with MIT license inclusion as per the full MIT license.

Comment: @Jaydles I wanted to downvote the original Meta post but I only have 101 rep on Meta so _I can only upvote_ (even though I have 9k+ on SO.) Your assumption of community agreement is likely skewed by this fact.

Comment: How are the 99.5% of Stack Overflow users who never visit meta, will never see the post, will never read the new ToS and more-so simply don't care or understand licensing agreements anyway going to be told to attribute code they copy from the site?

Comment: Frankly they should just go with WTFPL and call it a day. If you share code here that isn't appropriate for WTFPL, it probably doesn't belong on a public internet coding site in the first place.

Comment: How are you going to prevent the scenario of a cited post being deleted, and so only being visible from that time on visible to high rep users (a small percentage of total users)?

Comment: @Tim this post is featured, so it is shown on the sidebar on SO and all other sites as well. That is far more exposure than just MSO would grant. And as the change also affects other sites, it doesn't make any sense to only post this on MSO

Comment: Would there be any opt-out feature? If I want my code to be under CC0 or public domain, can we relicense over MIT with a more permissive license?

Comment: Define "showstopper"? The feedback from the previous round and this round are both overwhelmingly negative. What's it going to take to drop this altogether?

Comment: Considering I was told that you would respond to the "what is code" within "[the next day or two](http://goo.gl/tpWDNV)" and I still don't have a an answer to [my question](http://goo.gl/aQTvIx) I have little faith that your FAQ will come in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: This feels like something that will segregate the SO community and cause people with normally stellar contributions to stop doing so. I'm not a fan of that.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, as I've pointed out, the proposed new terms are [effectively CC0](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272963).

Comment: Is it true that if I, as the author of code snippet posted on SO, additionally release it on GitHub under public domain, anyone will be allowed to use the snippet under public domain terms?

Comment: @EricWilson How does the license even affect such users, unless they're actually caught using code without attribution? "Some people will ignore the license" is true regardless of the license content, so I don't understand why that's a relevant criticism of a proposed license change.

Comment: @g-v It depends on where they obtained it from. If they came across the SO post and didn't obtain it from GitHub, they must use it under the license on SO. You can do things to dual-license your SO contributions, though. There are other posts about that.

Comment: Have you actually *read* top rated comments to the proposition ? Or did a poll ? *Anything* ? Seems like you picked positive comments and relied on your confirmation bias

Comment: Instead of saying "please attribute using a URL," why not have an automated "copy attribution to clipboard" button a la Math.SE's `cite` button? And if attribution is made as easy as that, why not add a hidden field to questions/answers selected from a drop-down or something to *specify* a license? (Some users already use their user-profile "about me" section to specify a non- CC-BY_SA license.) This would allow users to revisit their old posts and specify the modified MIT license for consistency.

Comment: *"so please let us know what you think about this proposed change"* - People have been telling SE what we think, and the general consensus as far as I can see is "we don't want it because of x", or "this isn't a good idea because of x" and overall disagreement with the proposal.

Comment: This is a huge improvement over the previous half-baked proposal and addresses two out of my three major concerns, so I don't think you deserve this second massive backlash. The remaining problem (from my point of view) could be addressed simply by retaining CC-BY-SA for the entire post (including code) and specifying MIT as a dual licence applicable to code blocks only. Then there is less of a problem with reuse of the posts. I think there are still very valid reasons why others will object, but I felt I should at least say that you managed to assuage the most important of **my** concerns.

Comment: How much/what kind of _code_ is required to make it subject of the (new) license? E.g. is a generic statement like `a = sum([e for e in el])` copyrightable? Clearly, it's code. But then again it's also a math statement expressed in another syntax. Is a math formula code? Is a regular expression code, considering it's really just a compact representation of an DFA? Is it a violation to post code referring to or making use of some less-permissive licensed software, such as GPL'd software?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar that is called a *colophon*, and I do recommend them linked from one's `CONTRIBUTING.md`.

Comment: Just one comment - *If the license needs a FAQ to define the license, then it's not a license.*

Comment: @samthebrand post this on SO and see how many upvotes/downvotes you get...

Comment: @DeerHunter Please stop imposing your polarized view in the form of insubstantial edits to this post. If you have a disagreement, respond with an answer. Your actions are subversive and have repeatedly been reverted by moderators already.

Comment: Are there any implications on posting code from closed source projects, or open source projects released under other licenses? It would be good to have this clarified (I'm not even sure what the situation is right now...)

Comment: I would downvote on this, and the other post, in order to add my voice, but wait, I don't participate in meta enough to *actually do that!*  So instead, I must comment.

Comment: I am baffled by the community's general reaction to these changes, which are long overdue, legally necessary, and eminently sensible. There are legitimate minor concerns, but the overall sentiment here is insane. Typical meta change-aversion run **wild**.

Comment: Please stop making changes like this. How are they beneficial? Please don't push other users to do what [@K3N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n) did, and [just leave](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297878/2535467).

Comment: @CaptJak The current legal situation of code reuse on the site is ill-defined! Many people are using code illegal without knowing that they're putting themselves at risk! The first version of the license uses on Stack Overflow was explicitly intended for prose, not code. Why the hell are you bothered by this? It isn't political, it's to legally protect both authors and readers. This reaction is unbelievable.

Comment: Your first idea was much better **"initial proposal: no attribution requirement"**

Comment: Edited @JeremyBanks, but regardless, my opinion still stands. This site is for us, is it not? And this change seems to be upsetting to most. Besides, who posts code on a public site, and expects no one to copy or use that code?

Comment: @CaptJak Meta has always been *massively* change-averse by default. This is a major change that most people don't understand, so meta is freaking out. That tells us very ltitle. You can't let reactionaries mobs get in the way of a legally necessary change. I appreciate some of the specific legal objections below -- they are legitimate -- but the overall "don't do anything" sentiment is entirely unjustifiable.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, fine. Those are my 2 cents, take it or leave it. All I know is that no matter what happens, the code I post on SO can be copied, changed, used, sold, reposted, edited, deleted or even ignored and I won't care. The reason I post is to help people out, so if copying my code is what helps them, I don't need attribution.

Comment: @CaptJak I want people to use my code too. That's part of why I support this change. :/ I know for a fact that there are obstacles to using Stack Overflow code at some large companies because of the current licensing situation. More people would probably be able to use my code after this change.

Comment: I prefer the initial proposal. MIT license, no attribution required. Most already include the full MIT license already anyways. The main reason I disagree with this is because I know that people won't attribute with a comment in their code. And if it becomes a legal requirement now, more people will be at legal risk than you could imagine.

Comment: I think [this](https://youtu.be/_X6VoFBCE9k) is an accurate portrayal of my thoughts on this. The community is the guy talking and SO is the other one.

Comment: @CaptJak It's already a legal requirement, just with more ambiguity. -_-

Comment: @CaptJak [Last seen 2 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, sure, he made a [small revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20435650/revisions). Check his activity, not even a comment since June.

Comment: While sad that they're doing this, ultimately it doesn't matter. A snippet of code that describes how to do something doesn't qualify for copyright, anyway. See section (b) under http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102. This is one of the problems trying to determine when code does qualify, since it's really always just a set of instructions telling the computer the process you want it to follow.

Comment: I cannot downvote, but I would if I could.

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/c2/c20d95a9be009c21466a96fa850e79606985b1e83c90ca3981fd7f77c6b78854.jpg

Comment: *Wondering if -1000 will be a showstopper*

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, it will roll-over to 0 again...

Comment: @rene or be magically turned to +1000 by a furious CM... (not naming anyone ;-))

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I think the major reason for this is that, once you start turning over the rocks that cover all the uncomfortable low-probability high-risk legal issues, people get really antsy if the solution you bill as an extremely careful, last-word-on-the-subject panacea has a lot of those nasty holes left in it. I support the general idea of fixing up licensing, but I'm not convinced that we've actually got an improvement worth keeping around for six months, much less indefinitely.

Comment: I still don't get what the problem is with CC-BY-SA - has this been stated somewhere? It's not here or on the initial proposal that's for sure. What problem are you trying to solve with the new license?

Comment: "Upvotes don't mean agrees. Look at my most upvoted answer, see how everyone agrees with me?"

Comment: It's insane that this question is as downvoted as it is, I just saw it in the sidebar now. All of the problems with the first are remedied. Damned if you do and damned if you don't I guess. Thanks for the reasonable attribution requirement.

Comment: Has Stack Exchange reached out to the top experts who have participated on Stack Overflow to determine the impact of licensing on their sharing of contributions? Just going by people with registered accounts on Stack Overflow, people like Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin, Eric Lippert, Jon Skeet, John Resig, Miguel de Icaza, Kent Beck, Scott Hanselman, and Guido van Rossum. In order to excel, a community needs experts of this caliber. How do they feel about this change? Are they satisfied with the quality and protection offered by the proposed license?

Comment: @JeremyBanks For my part, I don't see StackOverflow as a library, a source code repository, or any sort of a working, complete product to be adopted by another code base. That means to me, that there is nothing on this website that can be "licensed" (in my opinion, obviously). I'm sure everyone here has their reasons for their reactions, either for or against, but that's my take. :)

Comment: @KyleStrand My point is not _some will ignore it_ but _so few will follow it that this whole conversation is rediculous_

Comment: Having just filled out an inventory of open source libraries used in my company, including each source name, description, license, and author in order to comply with legal requirements, this new guideline is absolutely insane.  Instead of being able to indicate StackExchange as a single source, I now must provide attribution to each and every separate code snippet we use.  I would be better off avoiding using code from SE or "forgetting" to include any mention to avoid the headache of maintaining this mess. Authors should be able to request attribution "when they post" if this is so important.

Comment: I will no longer contribute code samples in my answers, because I want my work to be placed into the public domain when tutoring others.

Comment: Since everyone is voting as if this is a 'feature-request' then I think that tag needs to be added. Otherwise we have no idea whether people are voting because they don't like the change or they don't like the post (i.e. because it's missing any real details and points to future FAQs).

Comment: Why not have two separate code tags one for each license? and let the poster decide which license they want to choose when posting?

Comment: *"We want to hear what you think [...] these terms will be rolled out on March 1, 2016."* Well now if you wanted to hear what we think then you wouldn't be setting the date already would you?

Comment: When I contribute code to StackOverflow, it's to help people with their projects, I don't care if I get attribution or not, I'm just happy to help, which I think is probably that way most people here feel. There is no way that I can attribute every single piece of code or method that I get from StackOverflow, if I did, it would probably add 1,000,000,000 lines to every file!

Comment: I don't want to be "credited". This makes me not want to post on StackOverflow anymore. Disgusting move.

Comment: Should there be a badge for reaching -100?

Comment: @Vortico except it's not in the public domain now. It's under CC-BY-SA which is a strong-copyleft GPL incompatible license.

Comment: There's going to have to be so much attribution, I doubt anyone will *actually* follow these rules. I also doubt you will be able to enforce it on a large scale, because it will take so much time and money to hunt down those pesky developers who don't include a comment with the URL they got their code from

Comment: "Just a link to the SO page/coimment".. Jeez, what if an answer describes a certain solution with multiple fragements of code to explain a way of working.. When it is so spread out. What if in a next project you do, you adopt the technique, or explain the technique to others in your company via word to mouth.. Does everyone have to add the license? See where I'm going at? This will become a big mess!

I understand this for poetry, prose and citations. But code..? Come one.. SO had always been different than GIT, where codebases were under license.. Licensing snippets of code.. hmhmm.. Odd

Comment: FYI, I mostly add a link in comment to the article as a reference to get back to the explenation.. But if attribution is necessary, se my previous post.. How will you manage word to mouth and knowledge sharing.. Please don't enforce attribution - if they want attribution, they shouldn't be on SO, or else, link their code to a git repo with licensing info.

Comment: What if a StackOverflow answer only contains a Gist link whose license requires no attribution? Do you think people might move into this direction?

Comment: I am sure other people have mentioned this as well bust just for the record: I have 101 reputation on this site because of the network bonus which means that I only have enough reputation to upvote and I first would have to participate on this site to be able to downvote. I personally upvoted it just because I thought it was an important issue, just as well as I upvoted answers which outlined my general negative opinion. But my point is: How can you claim positive feedback when most of the people visiting the site do not have the ability to downvote at all?

Comment: @Vortico You can still do that: there is nothing to stop you (as copyright holder) dual-licensing with a more permissive license than that that is currently applied. (I've had CC0 in my profile for years precisely because CC-BY-SA doesn't reflect the fact that my own contributions are in my opinion in the public domain.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: The idea of using a permissive license for code is good. The implementation, on the other hand, is... better than the previous iteration, but still a huge mess. As for the downvotes, I'm sure some people are downvoting because change=bad, or because they misunderstood the proposal (which, of course, says something...) or are just jumping on the bandwagon. But judging by the top answers, the *main* reason is the way the "friendly" upvotes on the last meta post were apparently taken as unconditional approval. So now people are making sure not to send that wrong message again.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I for one voted here to prevent SE drifting away from the fundamental approach laid out in [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/). So far, they seem to have followed it and I think it worked well and I want them to stay that way (yeah that's typical meta change-aversion yet again if you wish)

Comment: “We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ” ← don’t do that. If you want people to not stand up against this, otherwise very good, proposal, give them the full information, and do that **right now**. In fact, this particular question is the only thing that I still disagree with on this proposal, all other complaints have been addressed, but it’s a crucial question, for some sites more so than for others.

Comment: Stop delaying and just proceed with the original plan on the original date.  Continuing to try to dance around the issue just undermines SE's credibility.  Make the changes because they're necessary, and people will either get over it or leave.  There's nothing you can propose that's going to make everybody happy.  Usually the best thing to do in that case is show some leadership, make a decision, and stand by it (until the _actual_ outcome is known, at least).  Or else be paralyzed forever by pedantic nerd-rage and held hostage by a small but vocal segment of your userbase.

Comment: I foresee a new (sensible) Stack Overflow clone rising elsewhere with a sensible licence.

Comment: Like many others, I can't downvote in this meta, so here's a virtual downvote for you: -1

Comment: Aye, never having needed meta account before I took cannot downvote.  This is a terrible, terrible idea.  -1

Comment: -1 from me too. if i answer with code, it's to help, i don't want attribution.

Comment: This will be really annoying to developers who don't care for legal aspects. This change is so uncool, that my first thought was: we need an alternative to Stackoverlfow. Immediately!

Comment: This is more about advertising / promoting Stack Exchanges sites to appease the shareholders and get more moolah, and less about the users who create the content.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, *"It's under CC-BY-SA which is a strong-copyleft GPL incompatible license."* I believe you will find that [CC-BY-SA 3.0 is in fact compatible with GPLv3](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2236).

Comment: If all people did with code snippets on SO was copying/pasting them into their own code, this would be sensible. It kind of sucks for anyone who reads the code, learns from it and then writes their own based on that. Suddenly you're in a legal grey zone where you need to consult a lawyer to figure out if you need to provide attribution? Awesome. Suddenly SO becomes something you can't use without asking Legal. This also seems like a move to encourage more selfishness, really. Use SO to advertise your coding skills, not to help people or share knowledge. Can't say I'm a big fan of that.

Comment: I dislike that proposal. I would downvote to show my anticipation, but I can't. I have **50k reputation on SO** and I posted tons of code there, yet you don't even give me the chance to correctly express my feelings about this. Maybe **THAT'S** a problem you should consider solving first before you start fiddling around with a licenses that (almost) nobody has really asked you for.

Comment: As a contributor to SO, I'd rather people not attribute me. I'd rather my code on SO be licensed in the most free way possible. But then again this proposal isn't about me or any other contributor, it's about SO getting a new and novel method of SEO backlinks on github and other public repos. Good job SO, cynical marketing ploy disguised as "THINK OF THE CONTRIBUTORS!"

Comment: This is the most stupid thing I've seen come out of this othervise excellent organization. I've put in a comment here and there in source code leading to posts in SO that explains some neat hack or describes a complex solution, but I find it laughable that I'm now somehow obliged to attribute anything I use from here. *"Change 2 was made to allow you more time to digest this change and socialize it within your organizations"* - Ha! Screw you. What is this, Experts Exhange?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. I can't stress that enough. Implementing this will cause the downfall of stack exchange and stack overflow. Users, myself included, will actively usurp you. I would go out of my way to find or build an alternative website to this... this madness. Why on earth would you make all of our lives more difficult with this over burdensome requirement? We won't do it, and you will destroy stack exchange. If it ain't broke, don't fix it! P.S. I'd downvote if I could.

Comment: Nice idea!!!!! You don't mind forcing people to write a note to explain a downvote but you want to force people to do something that you can't control at all. Great!
What is code? 1 line, 2 lines, 3 or more? Who will be the judge? 
Perhaps you can ask people to send their code to Stack Overflow to ensure there is no code that is not well identified with Stack Overflow source.
Instead I suggest that it would be better to force people, when they take code, either a single line, to stand up and shout loudly "Thanks god to have created StackOverflow" :-)

Comment: Why don't I see this "question" on the expected last place if I view all the meta-questions and sort by votes? Is that caching so strong?

Comment: This answers none of [my questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271110/147191).

Comment: Who are these "contributors who want credit" and why aren't they standing up to defend this **egregious** proposal?

Comment: If you want kudos for the code you post, you get that right here on Stack Exchange. There is no earthly reason why the attribution needs to find its way into the code-bases of people who copy and paste. The point of this whole enterprise is to make software development (and other such things) easier for people. Why make it unnecessarily harder?

Comment: Alex - +100 for your question. "What is this, Expert's Exchange?" Yup - I remember investing hundreds of hours as part of the Expert Sex Change community... They lost the plot and look at them now.

Comment: I don't care if people cite me or not. In fact, I don't want to be cited. I only expect to be upvoted if my an answer is used.

Comment: I have no strong feelings about the issue (code in the tags I frequent is so trivial that I can safely ignore attribution requirements), but I can't believe the hapzardly fashion in which you make legal announcements. "We change the license but postpone the decision to what the license applies" - I cannot imagine your lawyer told you this is in any way acceptable. People put more effort into the errata for their RPG manuals.

Comment: I don't mind a license change per sé. I contributed on Wikipedia when they changed their license to a dual license. The major problem I am having with this proposal right now is that it is unclear to what it applies. Even with a FAQ, in the future I always have to *guess* what applies. That bothers me. Right now it might be unclear what cc-by-sa means for code, but at least no matter what I encounter, I can do the same thing. In the future I have to check the date of the post, and do more than a common sense check if the code I want to use must be attributed.

Comment: Honestly this should be up to each person answering to put on their answer what license the code is under, that way someone could answer and put in code gotten from a gpl, mit, etc codebase. And mark what license it is user based on where it came from.

Comment: I hope the fact this is the most downvoted post in Meta.SE history is a bit of a showstopper.

Comment: "Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement" Did you just retroactively change what I've agreed to for all the code I've posted so far?  Isn't that a license violation in and of itself?

Comment: Joel Spolsky once wrote: "Here are seven things we learned about providing remarkable customer service. I’m using the word remarkable literally—the goal is to provide customer service so good that people remark." I find it hard to believe he is mandating this new policy.

Comment: guys, it's funny, please don't invent yet another OSS license incompatible with others and not well understood by community. There is an answer below mentioning BSD and Apache licenses if MIT is not an exact fit.

Comment: @Alex This is so grotesquely unfair that I'm frankly disgusted. The entire purpose behind Stack Exchange's licensing scheme is to avoid the Experts Exchange scenario! That's literally been the primary motivation for it since before the site even existed. Content must be released under a permissive license so that it can be migrated to another site if the community loses faith in the company. They've decided that the existing licensing scheme isn't permissive enough, so they're making one that's more permissive. How can this not be an improvement?

Comment: Automatically applying this license and attribution requirement to code *snippets* seems completely bogus.  To license some code, it should be explicitly mentioned in the post.  I do NOT want attribution for my 2-line snippets (My longer code is on GitHub under the Apache license). Some of those are copied from elsewhere on the web, official docs, or SO (so long ago that I wouldn't remember the source).  Also, attributing code to an author that didn't write the code seems shady.  So... who are these posters that want their code snippets attributed?  Am I in the minority?

Comment: Sam and everybody at Stack Exchange! Thank you for doing the right thing (TM) in postponing the decision, please take your time to fully consider the licensing issue and review both the substance and the presentation before starting more discussions on meta.

Comment: SE/SO. Thank you for delaying the decision. I hope that our responses have not provided any hint of animosity. Rather, it should show how passionate and responsive the SE/SO community is. I think that fact in itself is why you should weigh any future decisions with us.

Comment: I want the code I have contributed to be public domain.  If I am not able to do this, I will remove my code based answers from SE/SO and other sites.  If I cannot remove my past answers because I have already licensed them to SE/SO, I will update each of my answers to explicitly mention the SE/SO licence regime, and my disagreement with the license regime.  Additionally, I will not add new code to SE/SO unless it can be public domain.

Comment: @mpb, you probably don't understand the law concerning "public domain". However, as several people have already pointed out (please, read the thread!), you can already dual-license your contributions under CC0 (or WTFPL, or whatever). That is as close as anyone can get, in an internationally legally meaningful way, to making their contributions public domain. Nothing about the proposed new licensing will affect your existing ability to do this, so based upon what you have said, the change is arguably immaterial to you.

Comment: @ProjectJourneyman, creative works are copyright by default in most jurisdictions, and in many jurisdictions that is not legally waivable. Whether any given code snippet expresses sufficient creativity to possess copyrightability is for a court to decide if a legal challenge arises. If you want to dual-license your own contributions under Apache or some other license, you have always been free to do so.

Comment: @CptEric, in that case, dual-license your contributions so that they don't require attribution. Simples! You can do that already, if you want to. Also, the proposed new terms won't change a thing for you in that regard if you do that.

Comment: @user3791372, *"I foresee a new (sensible) Stack Overflow clone rising elsewhere with a sensible licence."* Right. Stack Exchange *already* uses a sensible license: [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), and this does permit the content to be forked if necessary. There's no need for SE to replace it with a crayon license.

Comment: i won't bother dual-license anything. it's stupid.

Comment: I built over 21k rep on SO assuming the code I was writing was public domain. It's silly to expect or want people to add attribution, up votes were always attribution enough for me. I will no longer contribute to SO if people are forced to add attribution.

Comment: Now that this second proposal has been suspended, I expect there to be a next round. I hope that we can do better than continuing to hit a brick wall. Please consider [Code licensing proposal — Point of order!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273119/148099)

Comment: @CptEric, there's nothing stupid about licensing your work to others in a way that expresses your desires about how you want them to be able to use that work. If you don't do that, they won't be able to, and you end up defeating only yourself.

Comment: @DanielImms Except it's not public domain. People here are so confused. ***ALL THE CODE IN STACKEXCHANGE WAS ALWAYS UNDER CC-BY-SA*** That means that unless it's fair use (which no license will affect) , ***YOU HAVE TO ATTRIBUTE ALL YOUR CODE AND CANNOT, I REPEAT, CANNOT USE CODE ON SE IN A CLOSED SOURCE PROJECT***. This debate is so frustrating. I understand you want to your code licensed under the GPL or something, fine, but the complaint that SE is forcing you to do something is just absurd

Comment: it isn't "my work", it's my contribution to a Q:A website. i shouldn't hold property over a single line written here, no matter how extense,  when i help, i expect nothing in exchange.

Comment: @DanielImms, *"I will no longer contribute to SO if people are forced to add attribution."* I hope you haven't been plagiarizing. But let's assume you mean attribution *to you*. If so, see my earlier comments in this thread about dual-licensing. Also, it sounds like you have either not bothered to read the current (excellent, IMO) license, or else misinterpreted it profoundly. If you aren't aware of the current license, look at the footer of any SE page. It's been mentioned there for years, and you would have agreed to it when you signed up for whichever was your first site in the SE network.

Comment: @CptEric, *"i shouldn't hold property over a single line written here, no matter how [extensive]."* Sorry, that's not how copyright law works in most countries. As I say, if you want to give up additional rights, then dual-license appropriately. And maybe look up the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_convention).

Comment: @sampablokuper Yes I'm talking about code I write in answers being freely available without attribution. I'm going to add a dual license to my profile now.

Comment: don't call me kiddo and stop pinging me, i don't ping you. no matter the current liscense, this website should be CC0.

Comment: @sampablokuper I do however largely agree with CptEric's opinions; attribution should be opt-in and people are insane if they think developers around the world are not violating the license by copying trivial snippets of code a ridiculous amount of times every day.

Comment: @DanielImms, *"attribution should be opt-in"* well, we disagree. Personally, I care about upholding - and being granted by others - the [four freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=695656324#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms). Copyleft helps to preserve those freedoms. Copyleft without attribution is meaningless. So attribution should be required by default. If someone wants to harm the community by opting out of the mechanisms that best protect the four freedoms, then that ultimately destructive & anti-social choice should require deliberate, concious action.

Comment: @sampablokuper well I don't really want to get into a copyleft vs public domain discussion as they both have their benefits. But that (which appears to be solved via MIT) and attribution for tiny snippets of code is the issue. 200_success said it well with "We're sharing knowledge, not code."

Comment: It's certainly not clear there is currently a license and attribution requirement. I've been on SO since 2009 and never recall seeing this and the only indication now is on the very bottom of the page, a place few people look at, in very tiny print. I doubt that few users of SO are aware of this policy and I think it's pretty dumb.

Comment: @sampablokuper I guess my concern is not so much with the license, but with the attribution requirement being on by default.  Particularly because lots of the code is already from Apache or MIT - a lot of code is just a remix of existing code.  The attribution requirement is a burden to the development community in I suspect it's common that if the user doesn't explicitly state that it's their code and they want attribution, on SO there's a decent chance it's not original work meant for copyright.

Comment: @Zack, *"I've been on SO since 2009 and never recall seeing [the existing] license and attribution requirement... I think it's pretty dumb."* Six years and you never once noticed that *every single page* has a link to the license, and you never once thought to look for a license? I would say *that's* pretty dumb.

Comment: Nope. I didn't. Its a public Q&A site and the link is in tiny print at the very bottom where I never scroll.

Comment: @Zack, so you assumed the content was just Copyright (C) The Author? That's [the default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_convention), after all.

Comment: URL attribution is good practice if you're copying code from SO, that way you can read the description of why it is written that way. That said, I downvoted this, partially as I don't believe it should be required, mainly as MIT with attribution is *not* MIT.

Comment: @hayd http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/ you need to include the license when you use MIT licensed software, that's the attribution.

Comment: @hayd, *"MIT with attribution is not MIT."* Have you actually read the [OSI MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)? It explicitly says, "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software." That's an attribution requirement.

Comment: It is stunning to me how many comments in this thread express false premises.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what problem this change would address. According to the SE TC, SE is granted the _"perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, (...) distribute, modify, create derivative works (...)"_ by any contributor. Hence, SE itself is the _licensor_ of any work published on the site. The only legal concern that this change addresses is that of someone pressing charges _against users_ for using content, as protecting SE itself would require a change in the T&C. However, SE itself is the licensor already, and they are hardly going to sue users. What am I missing?

Comment: You hope to increase the "provenance" of SO content from within code? Why? Any coder worth a nickle already knows and likely uses SO, so who are you really telling about SO? Also, no, I'm not going to throw links to SO posts all in my code just because someone on SO helps me figure something out. The only time I will ever do this is if I found the post particularly enlightening and want to *personally* be referred back to it from within my code.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on the law, but a snippet of code I don't believe is copyrightable. It has to be a working program first. You can't copyright a sentence, but you can copyright the essay.

Comment: @JosephWright Good idea, thanks. I will do that, and that solves my problem.

Comment: @hsanders - Much as I enjoy a good conspiracy theory, yours doesn't hold up.  The original proposal was _attribution optional_.  They've change it to be _attribution required_ not because they want to see links to SO filling up github repos everywhere, but because some contributors were _deeply offended_ by the idea of having optional attribution.  Stack Exchange IS trying to think of the contributors here.  Which is silly because many of them are being unreasonable in terms of what they expect to get back from code snippets that they put on SO.

Comment: Need to define what code is. Most of the time i check stack overflow i look for ways to do something, not specific code, and those 2-3 lines are, most of the time, just generic code (could even be available on the documentation). Also, 85% of votes on the proposal were upvotes? I can't downvote this crap, but oh surprise, i can upvote it...don't use a skewed metric for your benefit, that lacks transparency.

Comment: As pretty much a daily visitor and poster to SO, I find it disturbing that all of this was going on behind my back. I only found out via slashdot. How is it that not even a link has been posted on SO? We have polls for moderators that popup, but silence on this? Weird. Do I need my tinfoil hat?

Comment: @John3136 Both this post and the previous one have been network-wide featured in the sidebar.

Comment: @JosephWright I've never seen then. Not once. I think a change this big needs some wider coverage - SO is probably one of the main sites it impacts right?

Comment: What surprises me with some of the feedback here is that it's not like no-one has noticed that the CC-BY-SA conditions for contributions might need to be supplemented by a license for code. For example, on TeX-se we've got a [meta thread starting in 2011](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers) pointing this out and allowing individuals to specify a (dual) license for reuse purposes.

Comment: @John3136 SO _is_ the 'main site' (certainly that's how we always refer to it from TeX-se, where I'm most active). I visit SO much less often than I visit the TeX site, so all I can say for certain is that it's been in our sidebar. Others will have to comment on the visibility for other sites. (My impression is copyrightable blocks of code are an issue on a number of sites but all with a 'programming' bent, but that of course includes SO.)

Comment: @fredsbend, *"a snippet of code [is not] copyrightable."* As you would have seen if you had read the other comments on this page, that is not necessarily [true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required/272963#comment887056_272989).

Comment: @EricWilson, *"Do you actually expect people to do this?"* You may have misunderstood the point of Stack Overflow. See [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/), from its co-founder: **"The whole point of Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and every other Stack Exchange site is to give credit directly [i.e. by attribution] to the talented people providing all these fantastic answers."**

Comment: @cdvv7788 "*those 2-3 lines are, most of the time, just generic code (could even be available on the documentation)"*. To be sure, even code examples from documentation should not be considered "generic". They should, legally, be treated according to the terms under which they are licensed. If in doubt, check the license for the documentation.

Comment: @sampablokuper Ha. The actual point of SO is to help programmers get their work done, no blog post will convince me otherwise.

Comment: @EricWilson, ah, the "La-la-la, I can't hear you!" argument ;)

Comment: @sampablokuper In all seriousness, this discussion befuddles me. I would be very interested to have an actual conversation with a programmer that answers SO questions and cares about attribution. I really can't imagine why anyone would care, and I don't know that I've ever talked to anyone that views SO as anything but: 1) A place to get useful answers 2) A place to answer questions. If you (or anyone) thinks you can help me understand _why_ a programmer would care about SO attribution, feel free to email me (wilson.eric.n - gmail).

Comment: @EricWilson, how about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273117) post by Thomas Owens? *"I'm not only helping people, but I'm building a professional reputation. If people take things that I've spent energy to create and don't attribute it to me, it's harder for me to build professional reputation and a solid demonstration of my knowledge base. For me, having more incoming pointers to my posts on Stack Exchange sites is important."*

Comment: @EricWilson, also, try talking to a professional composer some time about whether they care about attribution. Or a professional author. And so on. Some of them probably will :)

Comment: @sampablokuper Except his argument doesn't make sense.  There's no way to "take" a code snippet in a way that deprives others of access to it.  There's no way to "take" it in a way that removes it from the public record.  The verb doesn't apply to a form of property where an infinite number of exact replicas can be created at essentially zero cost.  Your reputation is captured by your public profile on SO, and does not diminish (or increase) according to whether or not people provide attribution.  Contributions enhance your reputation regardless of how they're used by each individual user.

Comment: @aroth, *"Your reputation is captured by your public profile on SO."* Hardly. I for one wouldn't trust anybody who took SE rep too seriously. Here's what you need to understand: upvoting a post by Thomas Owens on SO is *totally different* from saying, "I (re)used this specific piece of work by Thomas Owens." Neither of those two actions entails the other. The latter is crucial if (as Owens does) you measure prestige/reputation at least in part by how many people incorporate your works into theirs.

Comment: @aroth, *" There's no way to "take" a code snippet in a way that deprives others of access to it. There's no way to "take" it in a way that removes it from the public record"* That remark of yours is a straw man argument, as Owens does not say that there is such a way to take a code snippet. He is evidently using the word "take" in the sense of "copy", which in this context is a legitimate use of the word.

Comment: @sampablokuper If I meet a professional SO answerer, that will be an interesting conversation. And your reputation doesn't come from SO links in code, but from your profile page. I would be interested to have a conversation with Thomas, he does seem to represent this confusion well. But the musician/author comparison is the latest foolishness of this conversation, please email only from here.

Comment: @EricWilson, *"your reputation doesn't come from SO links in code, but from your profile page."* That's entirely a matter of opinion. I regard profile pages & "Flair" as largely "talk". As Linus Torvalds said, ["Talk is cheap. Show me the code."](https://lkml.org/lkml/2000/8/25/132) Also, it's quite possible that some relevant codebases (and the attributions & licenses therein) will outlive the Stack Exchange network. Also, should people really be facilitated in obtaining SE rep via plagiarism? Your statements make it appear you think they should, which strikes me as dangerous.

Comment: @EricWilson, *"your reputation doesn't come from SO links in code, but from your profile page."* This additionally ignores the possibility of SE content being used (and attributed) outside SE by people who do not have (or do not use) SE accounts. Furthermore, there is no requirement to give rep, regardless. And lastly, upvoting/downvoting has so little logical entailment that it implies almost nothing. For all these reasons, the statement of yours that I've quoted is scarcely credible; it is not a sound conclusion. P.S. I won't email you, but I am content to end our discussion here.

Comment: As someone who is mainly a contributor to SO, I don't really care what the licensing arrangements are as long as people are still able to use the answers I give to help them. However as one of the many SO users based  outside the United States I wonder if this debate has any relevance for users in other parts of the world i.e. do these licenses  apply anywhere other than the U.S.A? If Bob in Australia or Jane in Norway decides to copy some lines of code without attribution, what is anyone going to do about it anyway?

Comment: @Nathan: Licenses do indeed apply internationally.  There's the Berne conventions in which (a majority of) the world agrees to respect each others' copyright laws.  And there are a great many GPL projects with contributors outside, or even totally originate outside, the USA.

Comment: @Nathan, *"I wonder if this debate has any relevance for users in other parts of the world"*. Copyright infringement claims can be brought anywhere that distribution of the copyrighted works occurs. ([Source](https://sfconservancy.org/copyleft-compliance/vmware-lawsuit-faq.html))

Comment: Well, you can always just post a link in your answer to a public repo/gist with licence of your choosing. Right?

Comment: @rluks I was wondering this as well. I hope so, otherwise I won't be posting a single answer with code again taken from a project that's already releases under some other license. Why? Well, because that's illegal. And if it's my own project, I already chose the license it was under for a reason. MIT isn't the solution to everything, hence the fact that there are more licenses than just the MIT.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire you are right. Posting code where you don't have the rights to (re)license it under CC (or maybe MIT in the future) is illegal! But posting link only answers is frowned upon. Posting code and a link makes it illegal again. But that's actually already a problem. It just seems like everyone ignores it.

Comment: @Vortico FWIW you can still put your work in the public domain. Just mention it somewhere like I've been doing so in my profile. Though from now on I will probably say so in every single answer I post, in order to make it clear that you don't have to follow the silly attribution rules for my code.

Comment: Funny, it seems that StackExchange opposes license compliance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do/200178?noredirect=1#comment890475_200178

Comment: @ShmuelBrin as mentioned by others, both your comments are technically incorrect. Please review https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ccbysa and https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode 1a, 1d, 4b.

Comment: @Nemo didn't realize that CC-BY-SA is now GPL compatible. OK. Then fine, change the license on code to GPL V2, V3, V2+ and then vote if people want to change the license to CC0. I just don't see a need to keep code under a CC license when it's explicitly not recommended for code

Comment: @Nemo Just the point is that people are screaming that 1. MIT is too open ("I can't place my proprietary code on CR") 2. MIT is too closed ("I wan't a CC0 license"). The truth is that it's none of the above. The code is relieved under a bad form of GPL

Comment: My downvote is for *how* your are going about this. Rolling out a FAQ to clarify what we are discussing here *after* you have created facts .. is just awful. You are changing everybody's rights and are not doing it in a responsible fashion. I ask to you reconsider.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/candidness - looks like it is. Not to be confused with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidiasis

Comment: @DeerHunter oh lord.

Comment: @EricWilson Your code should already have the links - now you just don't need to go and get the authors permission first. I always link to the original source for StackOverflow links so I know where the inspiration came from and people can see why I did something that way.

Comment: @samthebrand any update on this? The post says March 01, but the header says it will be further delayed.

Comment: I don't understand how this benefits anyone, nor how anyone plans to enforce it.

Comment: @samthebrand Any updates on the detailed FAQ that is supposed to come on March 1?

Comment: did this happen yet?

Comment: @GaretClaborn no, it's been ditched for now.

Comment: @EricWilson *"Do you actually expect people to do this? Will code be full of SO links, really?"*  Attribution is already required (by CC-BY-SA). This proposes a less restrictive licence. In my opinion, links in code to a SO answer are likely to be useful, because the answer (and question) provides background and more information about the code.

Comment: @JohnB.Lambe I had totally forgotten about this discussion, and returning today, I see that I have the most upvoted comment! That's fun.

I figure that 99% of programmers use SO, and at max 10% have an account. At most 10% of those participate in Meta. And probably *at most* 10% of those care about attribution. So I figure one in a thousand programmers give any thought to this, and it could be more like one in ten thousand.

What's my point? Nothing really. You guys do your best to figure it out, and the rest of us will keep doing what we are doing.

Comment: https://legalict.com/2016/01/07/what-is-the-license-status-of-stackoverflow-code-snippets/

Answer (score 740):

> 85% of votes on the proposal were upvotes.

I upvoted the initial proposal because I believe it is important, but I strongly disagree with it. I suspect a lot of other folks did the same...

> Your response to the proposal was positive

I'm sorry, this conclusion is wrong and everyone knows that. At least lets be honest and say:

> Your response was not positive but we still believe that this is the right thing to do.

I understand your concerns, and I sympathise that you made an effort to hear us, but I still stand by the [most voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271113/228554) on the initial proposal.

Comment: The wording has changed a bit, but the answer's still fair.

Comment: @Raystafarian Actually that 85% removed is just a weaseling out of the real issue. They are doing this for the wrong reasons and see the thing in rose tinted eyes because its a "business" decision.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to edit your answer lest I get your take wrong, but I tried to fix the info to more clearly reflect, "positive voting, but with valid critical feedback that we've tried to incorporate."

Comment: @joojaa, what's the implied sneaky greedy business goal you think might be behind this? (I genuinely don't know what one would be.  This is simply about shifting to a license that's less ambiguous as it relates to code.)

Comment: @Jaydles I dont really care about the lisense per se. This does not touch me in the slightest as the license claim you make does not change anything as far as I'm concerned short code snippets do not get copyright in my locale anyway. Im more concerned of the fact that the train went and despite some negative feedback you think your getting positive feedback.

Comment: @Jaydles I think most people agree with that idea, the biggest issue is that "code" hasn't been defined

Comment: @joojaa, to be clear, we got lots of feedback.   A lot of it was positive, and a lot of it wasn't.  And no solution will make everyone happy, but we've worked hard to try to find the best possible balance.  And if I'm honest, the assumption that it's for some secret business reason felt unfair, mostly because it genuinely isn't - a change like this is mostly hassle for us, but we've come to recognize that NOT giving users a clear license isn't fair to contributors or those who want to comply with the rules.

Comment: @Jaydles that's entirely fair. But what's not fair is taking a very clearly divisive post and then broadly generalizing by ignoring the significant negative feedback from other answers on the post -- that's... disingenuous at best. So don't wrap that attitude in a "the community response was positive!" wrapper...

Comment: Now, I will just use the button I made here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272546/

Comment: I probably mischaracterized the community's response to the initial proposal - it was positive, with a few "buts". I've modified this follow-up so it's less of a black-and-white interpretation of the way the community feels. But can you tell me exactly what it is you disagree with in the current proposal (as opposed to the way that we proposed it)?

Comment: I have to disagree with you on the highest-voted answer from the last thread. It simply gets the "internet" flat-out wrong. I have trouble taking seriously anyone who comes to Stack Overflow with the intention of sharing code with restrictions on who can use that code and where. If you don't want people using your code, don't share it on a public (and largely anonymous) site.

Comment: @TylerH What about Code Review? That's a code site on the Stack Exchange network. Or Code Golf?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: @TylerH I doubt many people are posting questions on Code Review in the expectation other people will be able to use it freely. Similarly for Code Golf, I doubt every solution/entry is intended to be freely available for anyone who wants. They aren't question-answer in the same way Stack Overflow is, and they don't have the same licensing needs.

Comment: @thegrinner I doubt any people are posting in Code Review with the expectation that other people won't use that code freely. If any do, they need to manage their expectations. If you post code on a free, public (and largely anonymous) code help site, there's no license that can protect it. If you need a code review of code that needs to be restricted/private (and for some reason your workplace doesn't offer that), use one of the many private 1-on-1 code review services out there where there's accountability built-in. Any anonymous passerby can copy your Code Review snippet and use it.

Comment: @thegrinner As for Code Golf, that's just a joke site, right?

Comment: @TylerH, do you expect people who post code on GitHub (a free, public and largely anonymous site) to feel the same as you expect people who post on Code Review? And if not, why?

Comment: @TylerH Re Code Golf: Sure, but according to the comments below [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69279) it's GPL'd, and it wasn't posted with the intention of changing that. For the rest, I think otus's comment is a good way of looking at it. Just because something is made publicly visible doesn't mean it's meant to be used without restriction.

Comment: @otus No, I expect them to feel only slightly different, because whole repositories and complete code bases go on Github. Github also has private gists for that, too, so that comparison isn't the best. Stack Exchange sites are for snippets with isolated problems. Like someone has suggested already on this page, do you expect a two-line snippet of code to instantiate a new class to be protectable by licensure? Or appropriate for licensure in the first place? Code that is substantive enough to require a license is probably code that doesn't belong on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @TylerH, I agree that substantive code probably does not belong on Stack *Overflow*, but Code Review requires complete, working code and Code Golf is arguably substantive code as well.

Comment: This is insane. It is utterly baffling how any intelligent person could think this is workable, or indeed even sensible.

Comment: For all those  complaining about code being given away, it is **given away now too**. You put proprietary code on Code Review, and I'll take it and implement it in my open source project under the CC-BY-SA.

Comment: "I doubt many people are posting questions on Code Review in the expectation other people will be able to use it freely." -- Your doubts are not facts. Anyone not expecting that is foolish.

Comment: "do you expect people who post code on GitHub (a free, public and largely anonymous site) to feel the same as you expect people who post on Code Review? And if not, why? " -- Anyone who posts code on GitHub without an explicit copyright notice should expect it to be treated as Public Domain. The same is true of SE or anywhere else.

Comment: @TylerH As a moderator on Code Golf, I can tell you that while we like to have fun, we are most certainly *not* a "joke site." We have some incredible solutions to intellectually stimulating problems. I invite you to join the community and see what we're all about.

Comment: @AlexA. I meant more of a non-serious site as in, not solving real-world, vocational problems; asking questions for asking's sake. Not to say that there aren't any serious, real-world questions for minification, just that I never saw any the dozen or so times I scrolled through CodeGolf.

Comment: @samthebrand I disagree that you are proposing a change that is not consensual and expect people to accept it. This is a kind of change that, for me, requires that the different options are put on the table (e.g. 1) don't change anything, 2) make code MIT; 3) make code MIT attributable; 4) ...), let people add, modify, and delete the options and its argumentation, and then let people vote on what they believe to be the best path (even if this vote is non-binding to the decision). IMO this is more informative to all of us than the method "lets do A?" -> No; "what about B?" -> No...

Comment: @TylerH More often than not, the real challenging aspect behind the problems posted on Code Golf isn't the minification, it's the problems themselves. We've had problems ranging group theory to image processing, music to statistics. Though finding clever tricks to shorten your solution is also a big part of the challenge. But you're right, Code Golf isn't really a Q&A site in the same way Stack Overflow is; our questions are challenges and our answers are solutions, much like Puzzling.SE. I'd say we're more "nonstandard" than "non-serious." ;)

Comment: The sneaky greedy business goal is to increase traffic, increase page view, increase revenue. People won't just be coming here to learn, now we'll get page views from people who want to a repository of code snippets they can freely copy and paste.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão So you stand by an answer that does not provide any solution at all. All right, it explains problems pretty well, but there's a lot of people interested in how things should be done.

Comment: Someone had made a fortune on one answer :P

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I believe that my reputation in MSO does not reflect my contribution to it. This answer happens to summarise what lots of folks fell about the proposal. There are more constructive answers out there, and you should check them instead.

Comment: @otus CodeReview just requires a pastebin really

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/relicensing-content-under-cc-by-sa

Answer (score 581):

> 85% of votes on the proposal were upvotes.

Not everyone active on Stack Overflow is active at SE.Meta. For those users, they can upvote (thanks to cross-network bonus) but not downvote (that requires explicit participation on this Meta, not the SO.Meta).

I'm using SO as an example, but it applies to all concrete SE sites due to how "main" Meta works.

So, your votes are necessarily *heavily* skewed. And yes, I'm posting this after being unable to downvote.

*If you want [my opinion on how that may be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273063/260060) - use highest reputation across the network as SE.Meta reputation and disable Meta reputation changes just like on concrete Meta sites. This is not a complete fix (novice users still can't vote - I assume you value their opinion as well) but an improvement.*

---

Not to mention the fact that you used this as an approval rating without asking for such input - it's not the *usual* [semantics for votes on questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), <del>even Meta questions</del>.

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Well, now you're getting a much more accurate picture when we know the "rules of the game".

**Update:** This part of the criticism may be invalid, since [(another) FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) expressly says:

> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. **On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.**

This may be a FAQ problem: various parts disagree.

Comment: Upvoted your answer, since I can't vote down at SE.

Comment: This. Just saying, I posted the comment of the similar contents on the question itself, it scored 16 and was deleted (the justification is probably "we've removed these stats from the post", but it's still the fact - users just can't express their disagreement). This is even more annoying.

Comment: And, now you can downvote :)

Comment: @kkhugs True - in fact, I was able to within like 30 seconds of posting. And I did - not because I disagree with MIT in principle, but because I agree it's not fleshed out enough and using vote count as approval rating was wrong.

Comment: @Xan - Exactly. I would downvote if I could, but I also suffer from the cross-network bonus, not being active on SE meta.

Comment: Users are also penalized with -1 reputation for downvotes.

Comment: @BenMordecai Not on questions. And not on any _other_ Meta.

Comment: +1 I can't UV this enough. Migrating the post from MSO was a horrible move imho.

Comment: Given the system is so opaque that I thought so, one must imagine that other people think so and its just another factor in the meaning of the votes

Comment: Yep, looks like we misread this. Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273000/change-rep-required-to-downvote-on-mse if you're interested in changing rep required for downvoting on MSE.

Comment: +1. If they're going to count upvotes, they should've done it on SO, not here.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I have expressed my idea in more depth in the question you linked. Thanks.

Comment: Some users (hey, it's me!) can't even upvote answers in contrast with the proposals. I know my opinion can't matter as much as the one of an active SE user, but this way feedback from thousands of SE users and lurkers is just completely ignored, as if they didn't even exist.

Answer (score 522):

### The year is 2018…

… and the economy is in a slump.  Pundits on CNN are attributing the decline to a lack of growth in the computing sector.  According to Alyssa P. Bitdiddle, senior analyst with the Society of Innovative Computer Programmers,

> This has been a disaster in the making since March 1, 2016, a day that will live in infamy.  That was the day when lawyers were invited into the software development process.  Ever since Stack Overflow Inc. declared that all code snippets should be licensed as code rather than treated as knowledge, there has been a fundamental shift in programming culture.  "Intellectual Property" lawyers throughout the industry have had a field day looking for violators.  Nearly every software company outside of [Somalia, Chad, and North Korea](//stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-percapita) is vulnerable.  By my estimates, software development productivity has dropped to pre-Stack Overflow levels.  The average developer quality has declined as well, as programmers aren't putting their code up for [review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) anymore.  Software companies now spend a majority of their budget on lawyers, and they simply aren't hiring.

She added,

> Ironically, this culture of licensing paranoia started with noble intentions.  The founders, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, wanted to [promote remixing and reusing content](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W781).  Creative Commons licensing was used as a pact with the contributors: since the *community* owned the content, [the knowledge base could never be privatized like IMDb, CDDB](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29204), or [Experts Exchange](/questions/92683/what-experts-exchange-thinks-of-stack-overflow#comment239420_95311).  Later, concerns were raised that somehow [code should not be Creative Commons-licensed](//opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1717/655), one thing led to another, and now the entire industry is paying dearly.  We will never know for sure, but if Stack Overflow had been a normal forum without the Creative Commons license, software developers today would not have to struggle with licensing code snippets — as if the software patent minefield weren't bad enough already!

### How did we get there?

Despite a [top-voted analysis](/a/271113/148099) that said, basically, "Please don't do this", Stack Overflow staff billed the feedback as "highly positive".  This ignored the fact that some people upvoted the question because they thought that licensing was an important issue that deserved attention, rather than because they agreed with the proposal.

I think we've learned our lesson this time.  This question has been downvoted off the front page of Meta.SE.  Is that a clear enough signal?  If not, then what would constitute the "showstopper" that you require?

### What did people say last time?

Key points from the previous round were:

- What exactly is the problem that the proposal aims to solve?
- We're sharing knowledge, not code.
- Permissive license is inappropriate for questions.
- Permissive license is inappropriate for Code Review, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, and most sites other than Stack Overflow.
- License fragmentation is an administrative nightmare.
- Administrative overhead of licensing has the potential to break the Creative Commons culture and our Stack Exchange communities.
- What is the status of pre-transition snippets that get edited after the new policy?
- If code that appears on Stack Exchange is treated as licenseable, can we discuss code for which we don't have the right to relicense?
- Is there a threshold of originality before the MIT license kicks in?
- A crayon license is legally unsound, logically inconsistent, and perhaps unenforceable.
- Attribution is important to many of us.
- If you are serious about license enforceability, attribution and transitivity are essential to cover second-generation copies.
- What exactly did OSI say about the proposal, and how did they miss the legal unsoundness that was so obvious to many of us?
- For a permissive license, CC0 or WTFPL may be more appropriate than MIT.
- If there is a second license, then code should be dual-licensed, not permissive-licensed.
- What constitutes "code"?
- Is permissive-licensed code visually distinguishable from the rest of the content?

Out of all those issues, this revised proposal addresses approximately three.  Even if this were a good idea (which I think it isn't), it would still be a half-baked idea.

### What "code" are we talking about?

[@MarcoAurélioDeleu has pointed out the absurdity](/q/272257/148099) of requiring attribution for short snippets.  If you're [using Stack Overflow as a resource](http://www.theallium.com/engineering/computer-programming-to-be-officially-renamed-googling-stackoverflow/) to start learning some programming language, it would be as if you, as a tourist, had to give credit to your foreign language phrasebook for every utterance you made.  Yes, the phrasebook is copyrighted.  No, you are not allowed to reproduce the book.  But using the book for its intended purpose is just not a copyright or a licensing issue. If you string together the lookup results for "Hello", "My stomach hurts," and "Where can I find the bathroom?", that's fine. If the book's appendix has a sample cover letter and you use it to apply for a job, that's fine too, even though the appendix is a non-trivial creative work.

Does this licensing proposal apply to the [Stack Overflow documentation project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/1157100)?  If so, you might as well kill that project now.  Who would want to use that documentation resource if it meant you had to cite all the example code from it?

Do reasonable (i.e. non-troll) Stack Overflow contributors actually post original works worthy of licensing?  My impression is that Stack Overflow answers are either going to be short enough that the answerer is giving it away as free advice for no-strings-attached usage, or it's substantial enough that it's going to be hosted on GitHub under the author's own terms.

[So, what problem, exactly, does the proposal solve?](/q/273119/148099)  By declaring code as subject to licensing, aren't we just feeding the trolls?

Comment: Sadly, I've expended all my votes on this question before you posted this answer. A virtual +1 from me for the SICP quote.

Comment: That last point about "worthy of licensing" I think is really the crux of the issue for me. In a simple Q&A format, its hard to think of a reasonable example that is worthy of copyright or license.

Comment: "So, what problem, exactly, does the proposal solve? By declaring code as subject to licensing, aren't we just feeding the trolls?" I think the problem this solves is that code is *already* subject to licensing. And it's subject to a license that was never meant to be applied to code, and which the Creative Commons themselves recommends against applying to code. This change addresses *that* issue.

Comment: @Ajedi32 By making a code-vs.-advice distinction and putting different license terms on them, we are endorsing the mindset that copyright trolls would like to promote. CC-BY-SA would work just fine if Stack Exchange declared, for the sake of clarification, that all content is treated as advice.

Comment: @200_success Wouldn't doing that implicitly outlaw copy-pasting code snippets from SO into your codebase? And even if you're not directly copying, just basing your implementation on a code snippet you saw in a SO answer could theoretically get you into legal trouble. Ever heard of [clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design)? Currently that's the only way to be 100% sure you're not violating the copyright of some codebase. I think a lot of people here don't realize just how bad the status quo is.

Comment: I would upvote this if not for the intro.

Comment: I advocated regarding all answer code as CC0 or Unlicense, essentially public domain. I was downvoted heavily for it :p

Comment: @otus I just chose to ignore the first part and upvote based on my 1 billion percent agreement with the rest of the post. :P

Comment: Why are there no robot assassins in this story? I was told there'd be robot assassins. What kind of half-rate dystopia doesn't have robot assassins? Are you gonna tell me that all the killer robot companies got sued out of existence and the future will have no roving killbots at all?!

Comment: @Ajedi32 IANAL, but copyright requires minimum creativity to be valid. Very basic code is so generic that it is not copyrightable (no one holds rights for `print("hello world")`, although someone probably does for the compiler below that). A lot of the generic loop/syntax stuff could've just as easily been copied from a doc or from a person standing next to you...

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Right, but where do you draw the line? Unless you are a lawyer, you probably aren't qualified to make that determination. In all but the most trivial of cases, the only way to be sure is to assume the code is protected by copyright and proceed accordingly. When CC-BY-SA is involved, that's where things start getting really messy...

Comment: I'd recommend using the OSI-approved FPL over the CC0 or WTFPL, but I'm biased.

Comment: Alyssa P. Hacker and Ben Bitdiddle got married? When did I miss this?

Comment: @JasonS they wanted to keep it secret but Cy D. Fect spoiled it

Comment: I'm confused how this story couldn't happen now with the CC-BY-SA copyleft license. Wouldn't the MIT license involve fewer lawyers than the copy-left license? Help me understand

Comment: @StingyJack I have posted a lot of code on SO that (in my opinion) passes creativity thresholds, even if short.  Obfuscated compact code that solves a complex problem can have a ridiculous amount of creativity baked into it, despite being short (and seemingly noise) (which is non-troll and applies to code golf stack exchange). Real non-golf examples: [Creative?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29533782/1774667) [Creative?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090751/1774667) [Creative?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31197222/1774667) [Creative?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26655685/1774667) -- or am I a troll?

Comment: @DougT. Because if you don't make a fuss about licensing by singling out code, then common sense prevails, that it's just sharing knowledge the way a Q&A site should be used. See the foreign language phrasebook analogy. As soon as you declare that the code needs to be treated specially, you break that social norm, and your Q&A site becomes a gimme teh codez site.

Comment: @Yakk - my comment was toward the post, not taken in context of other later comments. It doesn't matter how creative I am being, if I post code here, I should have a reasonable expectation that it be used as-is. With that sharing and expectation I cannot reasonably expect someone to follow any license whatsoever.

Comment: @StingyJack So are you saying your comment is wrong and you want to retract it in light of later evidence?  (that code posted in SO can be "creative" enough to warrant copyright protection under the law, or at least that isn't implausible)  Or are you saying most copyright violation doesn't get prosecuted?  (Sure, I expect people to break any copyright rules I request, and expecting otherwise is unreasonable) I'm confused.

Comment: Similar to YouTubers, devs will fear CodeID strikes.

Comment: "We're sharing knowledge, not code." - No. Quite often we share **both**.

Comment: "Is there a threshold of originality before the MIT license kicks in?" - Does it really matter? Currently its CC-BY-SA; if it's original enough for MIT then it's original enough with the current license as well.

Comment: @Yakk - No. I don't understand where the break in the communication of this idea is happening. The creative value of a piece of code should not matter. If you post here in order to help someone, then you should expect them to use what you posted, and not have to abide by some viral license.

Comment: This answer is very confusing to read in 2018, when [there actually is something of an economic slowdown that CNN are attributing to a lack of growth in the computing sector](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/10/24/tech/tech-earnings/index.html) (but not because of anything to do with SO licences!)

Answer (score 157):

This is a greatly improved step in the right direction. But I still have problems.

---

**BEGIN TL;DR**

First, I want a complete proposal. I don't want things that aren't provided. I want to see everything laid out before this change happens and with enough time to have community review of it - the full and complete proposed terms of use / terms of service, FAQs, guidance, mockups of user-facing tools. Preferably things in both human readable English as well as the appropriate legalese deemed necessary by lawyers.

Second, I want whatever license is applied to code to be comparable to [CC BY-SA 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/):

- I want people to be able to copy and redistribute my source code as source code files or in binaries.
- I want people to be able to transform or modify my source code.
- I want my source code to be available for both open and closed source software.
- I want my source code to be available for both non-commercial and commercial software.
- I want visible attribution.
- I want to ensure that it is clear that I may not endorse the use of or user of my Stack Exchange Contributions.

The only aspect of the CC BY-SA license that I don't necessarily care about is Share Alike - I don't care if people distribute my contributions under the same license or not, as long as I am granted visible attribution.

**END TL;DR**

---

**This is an incomplete proposal.**

A lot of this information is still not disclosed. Full guidance for reasonable attribution "will be provided in an upcoming FAQ". You are still "exploring ways" to distinguish code under various licenses. You "hope to soon roll out an opt-in mechanism" for relicensing contributions. You don't define what, exactly, code is.

Based on this post, you'll be releasing these other things on March 1st. That's the same day that the license change will be rolled out. That give us 0 time to review *everything* and find errors or raise concerns.

Please, come back when you have these details ironed out - they are important for me (and I'm sure others) to decide if this is truly a good idea.

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should also [learn from Shog9 and how to persuade other people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617).

---

**You leave defining code up to the judgement call of the person using it.**

This is not acceptable. There are many, many users on Stack Overflow. I'm sure there are almost as many definitions as to what should be and should not be code. This is a legal matter with copyright and licensing. It should not be a judgement call, but needs to be clearly defined and documented somewhere.

---

**Your definition of "reasonable attribution" isn't reasonable.**

First, the MIT license requires two things for attribution: the copyright statement and the reproduction of the license. You are requiring one thing: a link to the post. I agree with the idea of making it easier to attribute a post. However, your scheme of attribution has issues.

The proposed method of attribution requires an Internet connection and access to Stack Overflow. I regularly work in areas without access to the Internet. If I were to follow your proposed rules for attribution, if someone viewed the code in this environment, they would not be able to see the name of the author, the date it was posted/modified, or the license that it was released under.

The proposed method also is effective to no attribution in a closed-source project. The MIT license does allow for use in closed-source projects. This is a good thing, and allows my contributions to SO and other SE sites to be more widely used. However, I would not get any visible attribution in these instances. Again, I think it's OK to not require the full text of the MIT license, but perhaps a requirement for a text file that lists the URLs and author names to all code contributions and a one line statement that some of the code base is MIT licenses would be sufficient for me.

I agree with the modified terms, however any attribution should also include the user name of the author of the code as well as the license that it was released under. I don't think the full license is required, but a two or three line attribution is all it would take.

For me, attribution is the singular most important thing to my participation on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. If I submit code that meets the criteria for copyright (and therefore can be licensed), I expect nothing short of a visible indication of the use of my work. I fully support allowing a less verbose attribution than the standard MIT license, but I don't support an invisible attribution or an attribution that requires connectivity to Stack Overflow / the Internet to view. If I don't get that, I don't want my code hosted here.

---

**There is no protection against using my name to promote a product.**

I would recommend looking at the Apache 2.0 or BSD 3-clause license.

The [license currently applied to contributions to Stack Exchange](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) has this segment in it:

> You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties.

I think this resolves some of the concerns brought up by Jon Ericson in the comments, and it would make me feel better, too. I do think some modifications would need to be made to not require the full license text to be copyied (and I'd be OK with these modifications).

Comment: The last paragraph resonates with me. On "Jobs", there is a theme about "showing your awesomeness" - that's what "developer stories" are for, so I assume SO _gets it_. Attribution to the originator of an original thought or expression is a key reward for contributors here, magical unicorn points aren't enough. But simply linking to SO will tend to dilute that individual recognition -- eventually it could be akin to the ubiquitous quotes which cite "Wikipedia", wherein the _vehicle_ of communication appears to get the attribution owed the _creators_ of content.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather not have my name attached to all possible closed source projects that might reuse my code. For instance, if a pornography website uses a bit of SQL that I contributed to Stack Overflow, they are welcome to the code without attribution since I don't want my name publically associated with that sort of thing. In general, I would be fine with attribution in a comment regardless of how visible the code is. The important thing (to me at least) is get credit from the people who really appreciate my contribution: the project's developers.

Comment: @JonEricson That's a personal decision. However, I contribute here (meaning all SE sites) because I know that I will be recognized for my contributions. The BY part of CC-BY-SA is the most important thing to me. Under these new terms, I'm not getting the attribution that I expect or require.

Comment: Right. The current license certainly doesn't require closed source projects to publically acknowledge code they found on a Stack Exchange site. That's probably for the best. For one thing, it's a big burden to track (making content significantly less useful). For another, it can be misleading without actually seeing how the code is used. Obviously it would be nice to see how your code propagates, but why should your preference be privileged over other people's?

Comment: @JonEricson It actually prevents closed-source commercial applications from using the code. That's the SA portion. I'm not entirely sure about freely available closed-source applications.

Comment: @JonEricson: Note that the status quo (CC BY-SA) protects you against smears by association.  Any site that can't comply with the attribution requirement and also the "You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work" requirement simply can't use the content at all.  **This protection would be lost under the MIT-lite plan.**

Comment: @BenVoigt I believe using Apache 2.0 or BSD 3-clause would add the protection of using the contributor's name as an endorsement of the product.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Yes, those protect the author significantly better than MIT does (and the proposed MIT-lite is even worse than vanilla MIT license)

Comment: When I worked for a government contractor, we never distributed code (or executables). But if I found a useful answer on Stack Overflow, I'd stick a comment in the code. (I rarely copied code wholesale, but I believe attribution is the right thing to do when I got help.) I think it's a fine idea to require that level of attribution. Requiring more would likely make getting approval to open source from a [Software Release Authority](https://code.nasa.gov/#/guide) more complicated. If it's easier to skip attribution than include it, I imagine many people will take the path of least resistance.

Comment: @JonEricson I work for a government contractor and we do distribute binaries (libraries or executables) and never source code. Right now, I'm not able to directly use SO code. I'd like to be able to, and changing to MIT (or, preferably Apache or BSD 3-clause for the reasons Ben Voight pointed out) would help. We already have guidance for these three (and other common) open-source licenses on how we can or cannot use code under those licenses in our products from legal. We regularly use software with these licenses, in binary or source form, and generally have no issues with it. YMMV.

Comment: Also, like I've said in other places, these rules are to guide honest people. There's nothing stopping people from taking SO content and using it in ways that are not permitted. And in a closed-source application, it's unlikely that anyone would find out. And if an honest person were to use my contributions, I know that I'd want visible credit, in an open-source or a closed-source application. If binaries were distributed without source, I still want my name visible.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd make the attribution a point of **professional courtesy** rather than trying to jam it into a licence. Stack Exchange content gets used all the time by ethically-challenged people and there's not a lot we can do about it. Changing the license isn't going to fix that problem. If some other programmer thinks my answer on Stack Overflow helped enough to acknowledge in release notes, that's far more valuable (to me at least) than if it was a requirement they followed out of duty.

Comment: @JonEricson There are two kinds of people - those that will follow the license and those that won't. The license terms should be easy to follow, but I want those honest people to know that they need to visibly attribute me by name when they use my contribution.

Comment: As a closed source developer, I strongly suspect that a requirement to include a stackoverflow.txt file with applications stating that questions by users A, B, C, D, and E, and answers by users F, G, H, I, J, K, L, and M were looked at during the creation of the software instead of references in the code would result in stackexchange being banned and blocked at the corporate firewall.

Comment: @DanNeely And those are the same organization that would likely prohibit the use of any open-source code. My organization has explicit rules for what you can and cannot do with software (source and binaries) released under each common license.

Comment: @JonEricson & others on this thread, another reason to support [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) is this part of its clause 4a: *"If You create an Adaptation, upon notice from any Licensor You must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Adaptation any credit as required by Section 4(c), as requested."* That is, if someone (e.g. a porn site) adapts your work and you don't want your name on their adaptation, you have the right to insist that they remove your name from their adaptation.

Comment: @sampablokuper I believe that using Apache 2.0 or BSD 3-clause would account for that. I do agree that CC needs to go for code since even Creative Commons recommends using somethign else for code.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, *"even Creative Commons recommends using somethign else for code."* IIRC, someone on the Creative Commons wiki once said CC-BY-SA wasn't ideal to use for shipping software products, or sth along those lines. I think that's barely relevant to Stack Exchange sites, in which knowledge in many forms is shared (i.e. not exclusively code, not even on Code Review). Nor do I think it was ever authoritative guidance. CC-BY-SA 3.0 works well for heterogeneous content like on SE, & if anyone *does* need to extract code and ship a software product, they can legally relicense under GPLv3.

Comment: @sampablokuper No CC license is idea for shipping software source code or binaries. It is OK for software documentation (user's manuals, developer guides, etc). There are many, many issues with CC-BY-SA on Stack Exchange, though.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, *"No CC license is idea for shipping software source code or binaries."* Stating that does not make it true :) *"There are many, many issues with CC-BY-SA on Stack Exchange"* Only for people with [sketchy business requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange#comment884204_271166) :)

Comment: @sampablokuper CC actually stated that no CC license is suitable for source code or binary. I'm on mobile, but ping me if you can't find the page.

Comment: The Apache 2.0 licence is [not compatible with GPL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License#GPL_compatibility). If SO were to adopt Apache 2.0, a large chunk of open-source software (using GPL 2-or-later or 2-only) couldn’t legally use code from SO.

Comment: @chirlu That's a valid point. Perhaps BSD 3-clause is better for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ThomasOwens that is incorrect. *There is* one CC license that is deemed suitable for code (and incidentally, it's the one I use in my open-source projects, and I license any code I post on Stack Overflow under it). That license is [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode). (quote from the CC FAQ: "Also, the CC0 Public Domain Dedication is GPL-compatible and acceptable for software.")

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes [CC0 is not a license. It's a waiver that acts like a license if the waiver is ineffective for any reason,](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#How_does_it_work.3F). It's also not suitable for SE content as it doesn't require attribution.

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/relicensing-content-under-cc-by-sa

Answer (score 136):

> We want to hear what you think. Barring any showstopper, these terms and a detailed FAQ will be rolled out March 1, 2016.

Please do not do this.  The FAQ should be out and we should have some time to go through it before the changes are actually made.  You have also stated that a definition for what is considered "code" would come out at the same time

> We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ, plus guidance on how best to comply with the attribution requirement. But ultimately, identifying code will be a judgement call on your part. We have full faith in your ability to do this.

This is another reason to have the FAQ out before the changes are made.  We should have the time to go over all this before the changes are made to the license and terms of service.

Comment: I wonder if having nearly -100 score on the post (as of this writing) would count as a showstopper. :P

Comment: Over -200. Still no sign.

Comment: @AlexA. -250 now, and, apparently it **does** count as one :P

Comment: -255. Show has been stopped.

Comment: @AlexA. was the question previously featured? It's not currently.

Comment: @Nemo It was.  That lasted until about -200 and something.

Comment: @NathanOliver that definitely explains the slowdown in downvoting!

Answer (score 96):

### Meta meta-Meta

For a post that was intended primarily to address one of the concerns raised (repeatedly) in the previous discussion, this sure has kicked up a lot of dust. I got to talking with a few people in chat earlier, and they... Kinda seemed surprised by a few things that I thought were obvious.

And I realized... I've been sorta following this conversation internally for months, and seeing where all the different pieces arose, why the plan has taken the direction it did. But y'all haven't. There's been one previous post, and both that and this *kinda* make it sound like a done deal and **not** checkpoints on a long road toward solving a difficult problem.

So I think it's worth noting a few things, for the benefit of the folks who don't hang out in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta):

1. We're working on this because folks have been complaining about it for *years*. Search the site - you'll find angsty posts about licensing going clear back to '09, full of fear and frustration. That hasn't gotten any *better* with time; unfortunately, several recent high-profile court decisions have made a bunch of people all sketchy about software copyright law, and [monsters under the bed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow/25957#25957) in the form of database companies in particular - nevermind that nothing anyone does on SO is likely to get you sued, seeing huge companies lose cases over literally a few lines of code has a chilling effect on everyone, and uncertainty surrounding the license used here just fuels the fear.
2. There's no hard time limit on getting this done. We've set a deadline so that we're all motivated to work on it, but it's the third deadline so far and there's no reason it can't be bumped again *if there's good reason to do so*. We're doing this to be good stewards (see #1), but no one's breathing down *our* neck about it - if it takes another month or another year to get it right, so be it; the important thing is to **get it right** and *only then* **get it done.**
3. The voting on Meta doesn't really matter; voting here is a means of prioritization, not a mandate. It's fun and interesting and useful *when it flushes out useful arguments*, but don't get all sad if someone downvotes your opinion or mad because you can't downvote theirs - it's far more important that you take the time to *express* your opinion here in a way that others can understand than it is that you vote; this is a **discussion**, not a straw-poll.

That out of the way...

### Thoughts on licensing

...I've occasionally participated on these sites too, so I feel entitled to chime in with my own opinions here. Especially since I haven't voted yet. There are a few things expressed here (and in the previous discussion) that I think are... Understandable, but naive. So I'm gonna talk about them. I wanna stress, *these are **my opinions*** - they haven't been vetted by any lawyer, any president of vice, or any sane person. This goes for just about everything I write here, but on the off-chance that you haven't learned that already, I wanna make double sure ahead of time that you know I'm as likely to be full of it as I am to be right (and that's *pretty damn likely*).

#### Licensing does not prevent careless or malicious use

If you're worried about a more permissive license leading to a heyday for students cheating on their homework or careless workers engaging in [Stack Overflow-driven Development](https://dzone.com/articles/stack-overflow-driven-development-sodd-its-really), then... You're a real optimist. This nonsense was rampant back when I was first getting into this stuff in the late '90s, and no amount of licensing has made a difference that I've seen. Folks who want to cheat will cheerfully lie about where they got the code they're submitting or committing, strip identifying comments, even obfuscate the symbols. I was dealing with this crap from cheap fly-by-night consultants long before Stack Overflow was even a glimmer in Jeff's eye, and I'm sure the old-timers here have been dealing with it a lot longer. Licensing doesn't stop it any more than laws against stealing protect that $20 you carelessly dropped on your front lawn; laws and licenses - like door locks - exist to **keep honest people honest**, not to rein in the committed dishonest.

Nor does licensing force folks to treat code as examples for writing their own, much as we might hope it would. When I was still working as a programmer, this was something we had to teach *every* new recruit, sitting them down and working through the process of taking some MSDN snippet and re-writing it with proper error-handling, structure and testing. Often as not this was the first code review. It's a critically important skill, but not an *obvious* skill - especially when the forbidden fruit seems so sweet. I'd love to see folks come together to create some guidance for folks struggling with this, but a license isn't gonna force it.

#### An effective license is one that the licensee understands and can comply with

This has been the achilles heel for CC-BY-SA all along; it's trivial to apply for *posts*, but folks struggle to apply it correctly to *code*. Chances are, the vast majority of one-liners out there aren't even copyright-able... But how do you know that? When does the attribution requirement kick in, how does that even apply to compiled or server software, what does the "viral" aspect even *mean* when all that's being "shared" is a binary? These are all questions that any proper *software* license answers, but which CC-Wiki ignored because it wasn't meant for software.

Common-sense tells you that - when someone asks, "How do I do X?" on SO and someone else responds, "Use this function" - you should expect the latter person *wants* you to use that function in your code. And so most folks do just that, and don't even think about the licensing. End result? **Licensing punishes the conscientious.**

So what do we really need here? Something that folks can apply in a common-sense fashion without being dishonest and *without violating a license*. This is what Sam's been poking away at for months now, the idea that we can make *more people honest* by making it more obvious what that even *means.*

I *think* we're getting closer. I'm not a lawyer, or even a licensing wonk, but on a gut level "tell people where you got this" seems like a reasonable expectation for using stuff that was posted **publicly on The Internet.**

But ultimately, I think this has to be something that **everyone** can get comfortable with. And there are still some rough edges, so I'm gonna shut up for a bit and finish reading what the rest of you have had to say about it.

Comment: Good point: **Licensing does not prevent careless or malicious use**. I'm surprised about how many people are thinking that this license will let them steal their code, because it's already happening right now. I don't want to sound pessimistic, but when [thousands of people break a license/law/contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/how-is-it-possible-for-millions-to-use-pirated-software-at-home-and-never-get-ar), it's a bit of a lost cause. You're not significantly damaged in a direct way, so honestly, let it go...

Comment: ... All I want is to make sure that no one can come up to me if something of mine screwed something on there side. Aside from that, I don't care about people who don't attribute me: chances are, they have no moral sanity, and I will appreciate the people who do, and help me out. As it is, I'm 16, I share what I know with a good heart, and in a well-spirited manner, and at the end of the day, knowing that I was able to help someone out makes my day.

Comment: I was clearly referring to durians, @abby. Which are, in fact, forbidden in some places with good cause.

Comment: why don't we all just agree that given the size and scope of posts on SO that they are all **FAIR USE** and that by posting it you agree that anyone using any code posted here is indeed fair use.

Comment: @Mgetz Because I don't want someone to sue me if my code breaks their system. Fair Use is not a defined term, and would make for a worse situation than the status quo.

Comment: Well, *we* can't actually declare anything "fair use", @Mgetz; that's something that has to be decided in court, if the concept even exists in your country. Aside: mourn the TPPA.

Comment: The basic problem is that the current license is Share Alike (i.e. Copyleft), and the proposed licenses are NOT.

Comment: And how is that a problem, @Jesse? D'you think folks are commonly *sharing* the codebases they use code from SO in *now*? Is that even an expectation we're setting, or have ever set? A rule that everyone breaks is worse than no rule at all.

Comment: @JesseWatZ Quite honestly, I doubt anyone follows that. No one copies code directly. Do we even need things to be copyleft? Probably not - people who work on the job just want help, and they should have some sort of freedom in that. Beside, the copyleft suspects are generally the GPL. Eww... (Disclaimer: I have an unknown tendency to absolutely hate, with a passion, anything that contains the letters **G**, **P**, and **L**, especially when they are right beside each other, or come after an **L**, or an **A**.

Comment: @Shog9 the sad part is without fair use, then any code found on SO is unusable, regardless of license. This proposal makes it even more unusable because of the license split. To me this proposal is a death knell for SO.

Comment: @Mgetz, why would (the fairly narrow) legal idea of "fair use" be the only way code shared here (or anywhere) is usable?  It's just ONE way.  Lots of code is too short or functional to be covered by copyright at all. Other code is explicitly licensed for use by others (whether by CC-SA or some other license).  Even if "fair use" does apply to code use, it's only *one* of the ways someone can legally use someone else's work.

Comment: "There's been one previous post, and both that and this kinda make it sound like a done deal and not checkpoints on a long road toward solving a difficult problem." I think what made it sound like a done deal was when the previous post said **this will be in effect by January 1st**. It is rather hypocritical to blame the users for a failure to communicate. Even this current post has an air of urgency, noting an upcoming change written in stone for March 1st. If these really are just "checkpoints", then call them that and let everyone retain at least some of their dwindling sanity.

Comment: I'm not blaming the users, @TravisJ - I'm blaming me, us: when you've been talking about something weekly for months it gets hard to remember who you've talked to and who you haven't. Hence this answer - I'm trying to clarify and dump some of the things that've been tossed around in our internal conversations but don't seem to have made it into the public dialog.

Comment: @Jaydles the short answer is the legal liability of non-fair use using of code from Stackoverflow would dramatically outweigh the benefits of asking questions here. Given that at the current state all code snippet use is de-facto fair use, that has not been a problem. But trying to convince a legal department to allow you to use a 5 line snippet from some site on the internet isn't going to happen. They are going to tell you to figure it out yourself and have IT block SO at the firewall. **At the end of the day legal departments are not sane**.

Comment: @Mgetz, this does nothing to change what "fair use" is (or isn't).  If code fell under fair use for CC-SA, it's still fair use under MIT, or anything else.  "Fair use" is a literally a case where a license or grant of rights is not required, so WHICH license might be if it *weren't* fair use is moot.

Comment: I was completely unaware that "folks have been complaining about it for years", and most of the people I've talked to about these proposals in chat also don't seem to be aware of that. So it seems like the whole idea of changing SE's license came out of nowhere without any real justification. I'm still waiting for a follow up post that makes some attempt to convince me there's even a real problem here in need of solving. Until then, the only opinion I can reasonably support is that changing the license for no apparent reason is a really bad idea, no matter what that change is.

Comment: No offense, @Ixrec, but... you're kinda new here. Why *would* you be aware of that? [Start at the beginning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow), follow the "linked" sidebar down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @Shog9 -- the problem is, because a distinction between code and non-code, in this context, is very difficult and unclear (IMO), licensing "code" under a non-copyleft license will bleed over to offering *everything* under such a license, which undermines a lot of (my, and I suspect others) willingness to contribute it.

Comment: My suggestion: change CC-BY-SA 3.0 to 4.0, which resolves textual ambiguities regarding its application to code, but is otherwise morally the same. Reassure people that this is really, genuinely the same as it always has been, and actually pretty restrictive--compatible with the very rigid GPL 3. This should satisfy copyleft advocates. And then tell them that, if they want, they can specify their own licence(s) (maybe make a field for it in the profile) offering as permissive terms as they wish. That should placate the public-domainers. Nobody would reasonably be able to complain about this.

Comment: Of course, everyone would complain about it @OleksandrR. CC-BY-SA 4.0 isn't magic. More specifically, *it's still not a code license.* It resolves some of the big problems inherent in taking CC-licensed code and using it in (for example) a GPL project, but does nothing for the ambiguity of using it in a closed-source project, or even an open-source project with an incompatible license. Note that [there are currently only two non-CC licenses deemed compatible with CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses/) - that leaves an awful lot of open source out in the cold.

Comment: @Shog9 it wasn't me who chose CC-BY-SA as the licence for StackExchange, was it? I know it wasn't you either, but now we're stuck with it. You can improve matters by at least changing the licence to one (4.0) that doesn't explicitly assume the licensed work is artistic in nature. The other two situations you raise are not ambiguous, by my reading: they are simply not allowed under CC-BY-SA, and everyone ought to know it. After this discussion it seems that the only thing people will agree to is choosing their own licence, but if so you can still try to convince them to pick CC0 (or whatever).

Comment: We should probably break this discussion out into a separate Q&A, @OleksandrR. That said, I didn't mean to imply 4.0 wouldn't be an improvement here; merely that it wouldn't really go very far toward addressing the problems that folks have had with 3.0. To be clear, CC-BY-SA is a *really nice license*... For prose, for collaborative works, and even for code that is intended to supplement informational publications.  And those are all critical aspects of what SO/SE *is about*. It's just not all that great a license for code you'd expect to use verbatim in a larger project.

Comment: @Shog9 I understand. I just think that this sort of reuse is beyond the scope of SE's responsibility to the community. People have, in general, no rights whatsoever in code they find on the Internet, and should not be using it at all except in accord with whatever licence they have been granted. We both know that a lot don't care and you can't do much about them. But, by emphasizing that everyone can choose their own licence, you could help people understand that this is something for them to decide, and not a problem StackExchange can "just solve". CC-BY-SA is enough for SE's own needs.

Comment: As far as SE *the company*, our needs are met by literally *any* public license, or no public license at all - as long as the terms of service grant *us* a license, we're golden; just look at the terms you agree to when you post anything on any of the social media services... But that's short-sighted and selfish; we're doing this to make programming better, not just to line our own pockets. And for *that* purpose, a good public license is all but essential, @OleksandrR. BTW, you may like this discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273277/is-a-license-change-necessary/273280#273280

Answer (score 63):

Thanks for listening to the community. I felt there was a huge resistance and that was primarily caused by not listening. So thanks for taking our opinion in consideration now. *(I still don't agree, but at least we can have some influence on the outcome)*

To talk in a little more detail about the updated proposal:

I think the proposal lacks a very important part: old posts and updated posts. **In short: this proposal isn't ready yet!** Okay, there will come a FAQ entry in some time, but how things are handled should be discussed *now*, and not in some time in the future. We all need time to go over it. In my opinion, old posts should have the old license. An indicator of which license is applicable would be very nice then.

Another suggestion regarding the above: a suggestion has been done a few times already to have a 'copy the code' button. *If* that can be implemented, can you put in a prefabricated comment in there with the required attribution? That would make users actually follow the guidelines you set now.

Another thought: on SO we had some 'Our answer to your questions' post. I think that would be useful for all the high-scoring answers on the previous post, so we have an official and clear statement on the questions posted there.

Comment: "Starting March 1, 2016, **new** contributions across the network will be licensed". Nothing is said in terms of the old contributions; I'm sure nobody is going to relicense / require relicensing them...

Comment: @nicael I think the question was whether an update to a post counts as a new contribution. Maybe?

Comment: Did you read "What about code contributed prior to March 1, 2016?" @nicael Rainbolt gives one concern, maybe there are more. **But we don't know** since it is not here.

Comment: I think asking for a FAQ *now* is a little bit pushy. I would be happy with a FAQ some time before the changes take effect.

Comment: I am not asking for a FAQ. Just a set of guidelines.

Comment: Most edits will produce a derivative work, which will continue to be licensed under whatever license applied to the original code. However, a substantial edit might be said to create an entirely new work, in which case the MIT would apply. To be on the safe side, always include a comment with a link back to the post so that revisions and authors can be tracked. No matter the license, giving credit is always a good choice. This is something that will be clarified further in the FAQ, but I encourage you to post this as a question in Meta so we can get started drafting the FAQ now.

Comment: Okay, what is the keypoint of that question @samthebrand When the license changes on a existing post?

Comment: @samthebrand can someone else editing a post actually change the license? Isn't that something the original poster would have to agree to? Edit: In general, I'm still very concerned about what happens when someone who is not the original poster edits a question or an answer.

Comment: One other thing that the FAQ should answer is what happens if I quote code from another work. I cannot license it under the not-MIT considered here, but then I cannot license textual quotes under BY-SA either. It is the whole work that is licensed, quoted material remains its original authors'.

Comment: @samthebrand is it still useful to start [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273142/245360) or should we wait?

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/relicensing-content-under-cc-by-sa

Answer (score 55):

I get from your comments ("in response to specific concerns about the license not being appropriate") that the current situation might be less than ideal (lots of people think it is) - but I don't really know enough about the legalities behind it to suggest what to do. But I trust SE enough to believe there must be an issue if they want to change something.

I can, however, read feedback. Which it seems you haven't.

This is an important topic - but you say this:

> *"Both changes were thoroughly vetted internally, with our lawyers, and with the OSI. We think they are an improvement upon the previous proposal, and a vast improvement upon the status quo."*

The main thing that is missing is the community being involved. Sure, you've asked us on Meta.SE (the wrong place) and you've posted a banner containing this:

> *"Thanks, everyone, for your feedback to this proposal. We're going to digest this one over the holidays and should have a follow-up announcement* **answering your questions** *and* **addressing your concerns** *after the new year."*

Highlighting mine.

I assume this is said follow-up - but I don't think it has done either of those points.

You've not answered any questions here - certainly not mine. Most notably, "What is code"?

And the "addressed the concerns" part? Let's check the first post. It had 592 upvotes and 95 down, so 86% of people "agree". It also has 37497 views, so only around 1.8% of people voted on it. Maybe that could be off by a factor of 5. That's not a lot of people.

You seem to be ignoring the concerns I've read. These comments come from the top answers. I'm not cherry picking - the top 12 are negative.

[image]

As much as I love SE (I really do admire what you have made), you seem to have ignored this quite a lot. Maybe this is as SE get's bigger, it's harder to involve the community. Maybe the SE format of Upvote and Downvote *is not the right way* to get feedback on this. And (almost certainly) Meta SE is the wrong audience.

The top answer has 460 upvotes and 23 down. That suggests that 95% of people agree with them. And disagree with you. That's throws the 86% figure out the window, eh?

Sure, something seems to be done. But you're a) Twisting the facts and biasing the vote by posting here, b) Not suggesting the right thing (I don't know what that is) but this is *not* based on other answers and c) not doing what you said you would - answering questions of addressing concerns.

---

For anyone interested, here is the Word Cloud of the first announcement:

[image]

And here is it for this one:

[image]

Comment: I like everything you've said above except, "I get it. The current situation is less than ideal. And this is an important topic. ... Sure, something seems to be done." Is CC-BY-SA really less than ideal? So much so that something needs to be done? In what way is it bad? So, for the time being, I'm neither upvoting nor downvoting your answer. Might upvote if you clarify these points. P.S. You might also want to clarify your point about "5% of people": it's a bit ambiguously-worded :)

Comment: thanks. I figured that if you felt confident enough to say *"I get it. The current situation is less than ideal."* then that "I get it" part meant that you "got" the way in which the current situation is less than ideal. (Otherwise, you surely *don't* get it.) So, if you do get it, please articulate it. And if you don't, then please don't say you do. Thanks again :)

Comment: it's a bit better now, and I appreciate your effort. Still, though, you say, *"I know that I trust SE are trying to solve a problem and that CC-BY-SA is bad for code and software."* In what way is CC-BY-SA bad for code and software? I'm not persuaded that it is. Indeed, I think it is an excellent license for Stack Exchange sites and that changing the licensing terms is wholly unnecessary. So when you imply that *you* "get" that "something needs to be done" to replace CC-BY-SA 3.0, I would be grateful if you would either justify that remark or remove it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Tim, *"I trust that they wouldn't say that without good reason."* May I encourage you to be a bit less trusting in this case? Please consider the case critically (on its merits) instead. *"CC-BY-SA says in it that it's not for software, quite blatantly."* Not that I can see. [Here's the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode). Please show me where it says that :)

Comment: Tim, fair enough. I agree with your unhappiness about how SE did this and that they are proposing to force it upon the community. I respectfully disagree with you about the rest. Thanks again for your time and consideration :)

Comment: I agree with a lot of this. You did a wonderful job summarizing the sentiment visually. However, I'd like to know, if Meta.SE is not the right audience, then what is? (Keep in mind that the proposal was [first posted to Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312598/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code?noredirect=1) before being migrated to Meta.SE because it would affect all Stack Exchange sites.)

Comment: @200_success Sure, it affects them all. Now look at the % affected? Stack Overflow is such a large amount (e.g. (95% + I guess) and so few participate here...

Comment: Asking out of curiosity — are those word clouds weighted by comment/answer score as well as frequency?

Comment: @200_success no, just word frequency. I removed all Vote counts etc from the page to unbias the cloud

Answer (score 44):

The only justification you've given so far for this change is the following:

> ...it’s always been a little ambiguous how CC-BY-SA covers code. This has led to uncertainty among conscientious developers... Uncertainty is a drag on productivity...

So, if I understand correctly, this rather significant change is intended to increase developer productivity.

Would you please expand on this, showing, perhaps, actual instances where developers have actually been hampered by the existing licensing scheme? (ie, not theoretical situations, but actual complaints)

Building this change on a foundation which shows the change is needed, necessary, and will provide significantly more benefits to all users than detriments might go a long way toward convincing the "who moved my cheese" users that this is an improvement.

If this is merely a philosophical choice, with no actual basis in objective needs, that's fine, but you're still not explaining the foundation well, and you're going to get a lot more pushback until you express the why more clearly than you are right now.

Comment: *Ambiguity is the path to the dark side. Ambiguity leads to uncertainty. Uncertainty leads to futility. Futility leads to suffering.*

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this. Also, I've found a [comment from Tim Post elaborating a bit more on these changes necessity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required#comment886562_272961).

Comment: I can't share what people have contacted us privately to discuss, but the ambiguity surrounding how _exactly_ CC-BY-SA applies to code is sufficient for many project managers to say "It's probably not compatible with what we're using" That's not to say it's incompatible, or that CC-BY-SA would bring unknown future complications - that's just it, it's hard to tell. Code trolls are an unfortunate part of life and companies are getting more defensive than ever. It wasn't that big of a problem 6 years ago (and I'm sad that it is now).

Comment: We are definitely not doing this for philosophical reasons. We're doing this in response to specific concerns about the license not being appropriate for code. I'd love to be able to share more about it but am being told that we can't for some reason I don't fully understand.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Just my view from the sidelines, but that lack of transparency is probably responsible for some of the pushback on this proposal.

Comment: @DavidFullerton it might help if you provide the _generic_ concerns (examples) that have been raised, no one expects you to share _who_ has raised them specifically. If there can't be given a sound rationale for this change it is likely to have some goofy background and the community is right to reject it, if for nothing else than 'unclear what you are intending' (to paraphrase a common close reason)

Comment: @TimPost Would you consider reaching out to those who have been affected and requesting they comment on this proposal, or they give you permission to share some reasonable level of detail about their difficulty? Alternately, consider reducing it to numbers - more than a thousand but less than 100,000, or more than 100k but less than one million, etc people contacted Stack Overflow, Inc about this problem? The highest voted meta question about this issue isn't very highly voted or commented on - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/

Comment: @AdamDavis Based on this level of secrecy, I suspect that the parties are unable to speak out because they are involved in an active lawsuit. Stack Overflow staff have been consulted for assistance with the defense. This rushed proposal is an attempt to contain a problem before it spreads. (In my opinion, the proposal — or even the fact that the proposal was raised — would make things worse, by endorsing the trolls' mindset that code is licenseable and thus giving them the home court advantage.)

Comment: @200_success Interesting consideration.  Perhaps Stack Overflow has been named in one such lawsuit. Would be interesting to search court cases filed where Stack Overflow is party.

Comment: Even if one accepts the premise that the current situation generates uncertainty, the proposed change does not actually fix it.

Comment: @abligh I agree, but honestly I can't come up with a better licensing solution.  I think this solution protects Stack Exchange better, and it appears to align better with what the OSI is trying to accomplish generally - one aspect of which is clearly delineating between code licenses and other copyrights. Because Stack Exchange is a business, they can't just use a fully permissive license, they must demand attribution, which complicates the problem significantly. They tried to resolve it with the previous iteration of this license and got bonked on the head because it won't work.

Comment: @abligh But I've come to the conclusion that this change isn't worse than the previous license.  I'm still going to have to do my little clean room reverse engineering thing anyway. I just don't think there's a way to get around that with any license. If this is the path they want to pursue, then while I won't support it, I don't think I'm going to try to convince them to try another path - I don't think it matters at this point.

Comment: @AdamDavis I don't quite understand why *StackExchange* need attribution for a couple of lines of code snippet (the code) as opposed to the rest of answers. I understand why some authors might want it. This is the distinction between helping, and supplying intellectual property. In any case an attribution could be to the author without reference to SE.

Comment: @abligh This is largely to protect Stack Overflow from copycat sites who repost stack exchange data without attribution.  It hurts the business financially.  So anything and everything on the SE network needs to be protected with some attribution requirement for them to avoid the worst of the copycat sites.

Comment: @AdamDavis if only the code had a 'no attribution' alternate licence (but not the remainder of the question or answer) this would still defeat the scraper sites. Of course this requires defining 'code'.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Your comment should *definitely* be part of the OP.

Answer (score 44):

Another META META site question that impacts a site I have high rep for that I cannot downvote because its moved to Meta Meta. Thanks.

Also this post does not cover the scenario where a SO user advertises a different license or waving of any attribution requirement in their network profile. How is that to be handled or affected?

Comment: The meta-meta issue is something we're working on. As for custom-licensing your code: As always, you will be free to dual license your contributions however you like, but users will be free to also use your code under the license in the terms of service.

Comment: Yeah, I am in this boat for downvoting privileges (20k rep on SO, but nothing here).

Comment: @Frank Post an answer and you'll have your rep within minutes, I'd guess....(not that that fixes the underlying problem, but still.)

Comment: "Also this post does not cover the scenario where a SO user advertises a different license or waving of any attribution requirement in their network profile. How is that to be handled or affected?" That's outside the scope of SO. Anyone can license their code (which they own) under any terms they want, in addition to the terms they've granted SO. That's not specific to SO, that's just how the law works.

Comment: It's not outside of scope, as they may conflict. What happens if I add a more restrictive license in my profile (all your code belongs to me)?

Comment: @StingyJack there are two choices: Either you publish anything you write under *both* your licence (as a separate choice to the user) *and* the SO standard licence under a dual-licence scheme (which means users can just ignore your more restrictive licence and go with SO’s, or – in my case – they can ignore SO’s more restrictive licence and go with the one from my profile) **or you violate the SO Terms of Service** contract.

Comment: @mirabilos - thats fair, I would just expect it to be spelled out either above  or before it goes into effect.

Comment: @StingyJack The licencing in effect here works like this: You write a post, you can licence it however you want, using different licences for different or even the same target groups. When you post it at SO, you implicitly (via the TOS) grant SO a licence under (currently) CC-BY-SA, which SO then uses to display the post. You can issue a separate licence to people who view your post, but you’re not allowed to remove from the CC-BY-SA licence to SO just as SO is not allowed to change the CC-BY-SA terms they got from you (e.g. require a link, or change old posts to MIT). It’s law not site policy

Answer (score 43):

Last time this was brought up, I posted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271083/262823). This new version still has many of the problems I set out in it.

1. **You're *still* creating a crayon license.**

   If you're going to do MIT, do MIT like MIT was meant to be done. The requirements for using code haven't *really* changed - all you've done here is say "now you have to have a comment in your code". *That's less than is required with the current license.*

   More to the point, you haven't actually changed *anything* here. Let's compare last time round:

   > You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

   to this time round:

   > You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution. This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

   You have essentially removed *two* words: *upon request*. The attribution is *still* not MIT attribution, and is *still* creating a crayon license.
2. **It's still far too easy to claim an illegal use is legal.**

   Essentially, someone can get my code from somewhere I use it - perhaps in a commercial open-source product of mine - and <s>not attribute it to me</s> attribute it to me with a single comment. When I chase them down on that (because they aren't complying with standard MIT), they can simply claim "oh, I got it from Stack Overflow", and get away scot-free.

The fact that I'm able to directly copy-paste most of last time's answer to this one should tell you that the changes made here are *not enough*.

So now I've had my little rant, how do you fix this?

I've already mentioned it in the first point. **If you're going to do MIT, do MIT like MIT was meant to be done.**

Comment: Don't post code on the internet if you don't want other people to use it...

Comment: Why do you feel the need to have your name credited in someone else's code. Who is ever going to see that?

Comment: @brso05 That's not how licensing/copyright works, thankfully.

Comment: @thegrinner if you don't want others to use your code don't post on SO!

Comment: `they can simply claim "oh, I got it from Stack Overflow"` How can they claim that, if they don't have a link to the post they got it from (because in your hypothetical, that post doesn't exist)? If they don't have a link to the post, they're already in violation. If they're simply lying, they could just as easily have lied "Oh, I got it from a public domain project."

Comment: @DavidRobinson I never said the code wasn't on Stack. It's true that this argument is weaker this time round now that attribution is at least required in some form, but I felt that it was worth putting in because it likely *does* create some janky loopholes.

Comment: How did the code get on Stack? You just said they got it from somewhere else (`someone can get my code from somewhere I use it`)

Comment: @brso05 Don't forget [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). The license being discussed here *explicitly impacts all Stack Exchange sites*.

Comment: @DavidRobinson ...I can still post it on Stack, can I not?

Comment: Then it would be under this license and therefore legal... how would them getting it from a different project be relevant? You're saying "What if they did something illegal, but by coincidence it happened to be legal."

Comment: @DavidRobinson As I said, this argument is far weaker this time around.

Comment: This answer remains a very good point, even this time around. If it says "Licensed under MIT" at the bottom of each page, but the exceptions hidden away in the TOS make it illegal to post MIT licensed code here, it's hard to see the labelling as anything but deliberately misleading. I know that's not the intention, so we need to get away from using a name that already exists for something different.

Answer (score 29):

I've had a scenario pop up in my head in discussions in comments, and I kinda want to see how this is expected to be handled.

- Alice answers a question on Stack Overflow, and provides some code for, say, frobnicating widgets in JavaScript.
- Bob, knowing the code is MIT-licensed, re-uses that code in his company's widget portal software. It's all closed-source code, but the MIT license is okay with that. Normally, he'd need a full copy of the MIT license to accompany his code, but Stack Overflow waives that. A quick comment in the JS at the top of the widget.frobnicate() function is all he needs!
- Carol works on the re-write of the widget portal a year later. Part of this includes putting a proper minifier in place in the build process. Carol looks through the whole codebase, doesn't see that one little comment, and moves forward. Unfortunately, the minifier is stripping out comments, so Carol and Bob's company is now shipping code without attribution (I.E. illegally).

The problem isn't limited to JS and minifiers, obviously. Any time you re-use someone else's code that happens to include a Stack Overflow attribution, this can come up.

Legally, the fault in my scenario lies with Carol and/or the company. Code being re-used without checking it with a fine-tooth comb is always a potential source of copyright violations. But I'm really uncomfortable with Stack Overflow, quite possibly the largest source of programming help/resources/etc. in the world is helping to create landmines like this.

Don't get me wrong, I love the idea of not having to include the whole license text when I use stuff from Stack Overflow. But I worry that not having that license requirement is just asking for people to miss the much shorter attribution line, and break the law. And, given that the whole point of this exercise is to try to align the legal situation with reality, I'm worried it's a bit self-defeating on that point.

I've been mulling this over in my head for an hour or two, and I'm still not sure if it's really a big problem or not. So, what do other people (Stack Overflow employees or otherwise) think about this? Is this a problem, or is it merely something people will have to take note of in the future?

Comment: I regularly strip the attributions out of code that I find in the repository. They rarely add value in terms of readability or maintainability, and more often than not actually add confusion as the code changes but the attribution remains. 

It never has occurred to me that I might be violating licenses by doing so. And at what point, as the code goes through changes over time, can the attribution finally be removed?

Comment: Billy, you say *"the code is MIT-licensed"* and *"Legally, the fault in my scenario lies with Carol and/or the company."*. As you'll know from our discussion below [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272963), I believe those statements are false. The result is that neither Alice, Bob, nor Carol has broken the law in your scenario, in my view. That is the strict implication of the proposed new Stack Exchange licensing terms, and illustrates well why those terms completely fail, ultimately, to ensure respect for the Stack Exchange contributors.

Comment: @Sterno, please revert any such changes you have made to software that you are distributing, if they breached licensing terms. In the case of such software already distributed, please make every effort to contact every recipient and supply them with all attribution and licensing statements required by law. I'm not joking.

Comment: @sampablokuper Well, that's my point. I have no idea what the licensing terms might have been if I'm not the one who added it. I'm not following every link to a URL I find in our source code to try to decipher whether or not having that URL in our code somehow makes it compliant for licensing.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'm betting most of the places I've done it don't meet what "code" is probably going to end up being defined as. I mean, would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202521/134310) really require attribution (ignoring for the moment it's self-answered... although that also makes me wonder if you need attribution when you self-answer, too)?

Comment: @Sterno, *"would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202521/134310) really require attribution"*? In the event that the author/owner claimed it did, and the defendant claimed it didn't and did not offer to settle, then that would be for a court to decide. Here is an example of a similar case over 9 lines of code: [*Oracle v. Google*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.). ([Here](https://majadhondt.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/googles-9-lines/) are the 9 lines in question.)

Comment: @Stemo  "I'm not following every link to a URL I find in our source code" - you should be !  That's part of the process.  If you aren't following it you open yourself up to lawyers.  If you are a one-man-band, then perhaps it's less enforceable, but larger companies will open themselves up to litigation.  At least one company I worked for, had someone who's responsibility it was to chase these things up.

Comment: Just distribute both the minified and non-minified JS, which you ought to have been doing *anyway*, and which is already a *requirement* for inclusion e.g. into Debian which (for *extremely* good reasons) insists on being able to build from (nōn-minified) source.

Comment: @sampablokuper Thanks for enlightening me. This is pretty much making me never want to use StackOverflow again. Certainly not without heavily rewriting the answer to one of my questions.

Comment: @Sterno, you're welcome :) And there's no need to stop using Stack Overflow just yet! The licensing terms are linked at the bottom of every page (and have been for years). Act in accordance with those terms, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 28):

> The changes will now go into effect March 1, 2016
>
> We want to hear what you think. Barring any showstopper, these terms and a detailed FAQ will be rolled out March 1, 2016.

I would like to see the changes be delayed an extra month or 2, just so there will first be feedback on the FAQ that will be rolled out on the 1st of March and any missing information can be filled in so the community **fully** understands what this means for their post and the usage of code from SE sites and what exactly changes **before** implementing it.

Comment: Can’t upvote this enough…

Answer (score 28):

This doesn't really answer any of my concerns that started with the original proposal.   A *comment* from the posting mod on [my response to the original proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271100/225437) said, about determining what's code and what's not (emphasis added):

> Just to clarify, we never said code is anything inside a code block.
>   It might be up to a user to decide what's code and what isn't, just
>   like he/she may have to make a judgement about whether something
>   crosses the threshold of originality. **Ultimately, always, it's on a
>   code user to decide how he/she wants to use what they find here.**
>   – [samthebrand♦ 12 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange/271100#comment879049_271100)

This was one of the biggest sources on confusion for me, and it seems like it'd be one of the easiest to address.  Leaving it open causes a number of issues:

- Inline code, or just code blocks?
- Documentation strings in code?
- Comment blocks in code?
- What about edits that turn one into the other?
- Why on earth would it be up to the *user*, not the *author* to make this determination?

I'd like to say that this revision answers some of these questions.  It doesn't though.  These issues just get punted a little longer, except that a little bit of the confusion is cemented (emphasis added):

> **But what is code?**
>
> We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ, plus
>   guidance on how best to comply with the attribution requirement. **But
>   ultimately, identifying code will be a judgement call on your part. We
>   have full faith in your ability to do this.**

This shouldn't be on the *user* of the code.  If I walk into a bookstore and there are free flyers for local events on a table by the door, *I* don't get to decide that the contents of the bookshelf nearest the door are also for free; the bookstore gets to decide that.  It **needs** to be clear what content is available under what terms.

> **What’s next?**
>
> We want to hear what you think. Barring any showstopper, these terms
>   and a detailed FAQ will be rolled out March 1, 2016.

I'd say that the lack of a detailed FAQ *is* the showstopper ([negative sense](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/showstopper.html)).

Comment: w00t;  didn't realize how easy it'd be to get a "Reversal" badge on Meta

Comment: JoshuaTaylor, I agree with your post entirely except for this: *"I'd say that the lack of a detailed FAQ is the showstopper."* I totally agree with that sentence's sentiment that clarification is needed. But an FAQ isn't the place for that clarity. [This excellent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required/272989?noredirect=1#comment886749_272956) by [rolfl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241497/rolfl) sums it up:  **"If the license needs a FAQ to define the license, then it's not a license."**

Comment: @sampablokuper I entirely agree. (Though a well written license may still generate frequently asked questions, since many license readers aren't necessarily lawyers, so there are many legitimate questions about what the license means.)  I think that by the time such a FAQ is in place, the license will have been pinned down, too.

Comment: 1. The license should stand alone. 2. In order to get community feedback on that license, there needs to be a FAQ addressing the many questions from the community. All the answers should already be covered by the license, but a FAQ makes discussion much more likely and useful.

Answer (score 26):

**Update:** I'll take back my claim that SE does not have adequate legal support. However, as mentioned in comments, they are yet to provide a justification for their action.

### Why must you dictate?

Even on the previous post, there was a comment criticizing your attitude over the whole issue. And again, even on this post, it does not *propose March 1 as a starting date*, instead it declares that *March 1 onwards, we will bring this license.*

Was there any significant support for such a license on the previous post? Is there any list of reasons why this license is better than *every* other license there exists?

### Are you capable of deciding?

And lastly, does SE lack the legal support to actually determine the best license (and justify it adequately to the public), instead of relying on the up-votes (which themselves are disputable) of an online crowd? I have a strong feeling that this is so.

I personally have no opinion on the issue (read no clue what's right or wrong), but it does look bad on your part that the SE admin is boldly declaring their intentions only to receive a flood of down-votes. If you cannot decide (or else justify your decisions), then why do you?

Comment: We have one of the best lawyers in the world (in this field) working on it with us (he teaches this sort of coursework at Fordham). We look at votes to get an idea of how people feel about it.

Comment: @TimPost Then he should be able to justify his decision rather than having a moderator just declare it to us.

Comment: @TimPost You're normally really good at this - but recently that has... changed. I'd like to see at least the impression of democracy back. What's the point in these posts if you give the impressions you've decided everything?

Comment: They are very much capable of deciding and that is clearly visible in their previous and this version of proposal. (It is another matter how an SE user perceive their decision: clear and helpful or ambiguous) What they are trying to see here is what the community think about their decision, since no matter how hard they try, community (given its diverse nature) has the *possibility* of coming up with a better decision or at least  with some critical input which may have been overlooked during decision making.  The problem I see in your answer is that I don't understand why it has been posted.

Comment: @TimPost - A teacher? You need to hire a real law firm. Researchers have terrible track records when it comes to the private sector.

Comment: Check what [the creator of SO](https://blog.codinghorror.com/about-me/) states under his ["90% of all community feedback is crap"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/). (he is right).

Comment: @Fermiparadox But how will you get the 10% useful feedback if you don't provide the reasoning behind your decisions?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code My comment was related to the "Why must you dictate" part of the answer. Dictating sometimes can be very beneficial.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Not against a unanimous feedback

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Why not?

Comment: @Fermiparadox Even if 90% of the users give useless feedback, that doesn't mean they all will down-vote. I would have agreed to the fact that people are down-voting excessively *if* the mod had provided justification the new license over the old (in layman's terms). Since he hasn't, the post is poorly written, for starters. If this was a feature-request by a user instead of a declaration by a mod, it would have been closed due to lack of reasoning given.

Comment: Indeed it seems StackExchange is not doing their homework. They might have hired a teacher (but why not someone more experienced like FSF, CC, EFF or Software Conservancy?) but they apparently didn't ask to be taught about dual-licensing among other things http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?page=1&tab=votes#comment886562_272961

Answer (score 26):

**If you are going to fix it, fix it properly; do not apply a band aid**

I don't support this, but for different reasons to the remaining answers (as far as I can tell). I have a feeling I'm going to get a pile of downvotes, but...

The original proposal gave (almost) the right answer, but you went about it the wrong way, and it was incomplete (for all the reasons set out in almost every answer). The right answer (as far as I'm concerned) is to MIT licence new posts (not MIT with attribution) as you suggested, but with a dual licence for CC-BY-SA, and to leave old posts as they are. Then ensure the licence is actually listed with the code.

What you're now suggesting is MIT with attribution. Really, that doesn't help. MIT with an exception that the licence does not have to be reproduced with attribution [is not an OSI approved licence](http://opensource.org/licenses), and we don't need yet another licence around - licence proliferation is a bad thing. If you are going to require attribution, use an OSI approved licence that has an attribution requirement rather than making another one up.

But is attribution really necessary? In my view, the answer is no.

Firstly, Stack Exchange contributions are to share know-how. They are not to share intellectual property. **Typically we are talking about small pieces of code - if not, why are you pasting them on Stack Exchange?** Whether these are sufficiently large to constitute an independent work protectable by copyright that does not come under a 'fair use' provision is going to turn on the facts, and be a matter that can be debated by lawyers. So if I want to use a little code that's on Stack Exchange, the licence is of no help to me. As Ian Ringrose pointed out, [does a call to create a new GUID require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117970/how-can-i-default-a-parameter-to-guid-empty-in-c/5118005#5118005) attribution or not? Under the existing CC-BY-SA licence, we don't know (because we don't know whether the one line of code is a 'work', and we don't know whether it is within a fair use extension), and under the proposed new licence (MIT with attribution) we also don't know. I'm guessing not for one line. If it's 100 lines, may be yes (but what's 100 lines of code doing there?). Five lines? You are not actually helping your readers.

Let's not assume that this only impacts people writing proprietary software. Even an open source project using an Stack Exchange contribution has just as many licence compatibility issues as under the previous licence (because that open source project is unlikely to be using your mangled MIT licence). You haven't helped.

And you aren't actually helping your contributors. If someone wants to create a new GUID, and I tell that person how to create a new GUID in the most efficient possible way (with a line of code), I want to do just that. I want to teach them, and to make their life better. I do not expect every time they use that technique to reference an article on Stack Exchange to acknowledge that I was the guy who taught them how to create a new GUID (NB it was actually someone else). This is a qualitatively different action from publishing software on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), where (incidentally) I get to choose any licence I like. I don't need the attribution, so don't give it to me. Just like I don't need it to be a GPL type licence (and you didn't give that to me).

The only conceivable result is those using short bits of code will be no more happy with MIT+attribution than they were with CC-BY-SA. I.e. they will either just ignore it, or be in a position where they don't know what the right thing to do is, and possibly rewrite in order to disguise a copy. This helps no one.

**Additional (technical) issue**

The licence has the text:

> "Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement"

So, if Alice copies Bob's code, Alice has to copy it with an attribution, but may omit the text of the licence licence. Charles then copies *Bob's* code, and no longer has to acknowledge the original author (Alice), because the license that requires it has been removed. But had Charles copied it directly from Stack Exchange, Charles would have had to do something different. This makes very little sense.

Even better, unpleasant Stack Exchange scraping site B can legitimately copy every post on Stack Exchange, attributing them properly, but not replicating the licence. Unpleasant Stack Exchange scraping site C can then copy scraping site B without attribution. Yuck.

Comment: "if not, why are you pasting them on StackExchange?" You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: "They are not to share intellectual property." -- All of my creative content - my words, my code - is my intellectual property that I'm choosing to release to the world under a particular license. I expect that license to require attribution. If it doesn't, I won't contribute under another license.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm talking about the *purpose* of a post to SE. The purpose of posting on SE (as far as I'm concerned anyway) is not to share something which is intellectual property (like it is uploading s/w to Github where you get to pick your licence). The purpose is to ask questions or help people out. That may incidentally require sharing something that might or might not be protectable intellectual property. In my view this objective is not achieved by licences whose obligations are unclear or (see last para) bizarre. And by your argument, you should get to pick whatever licence you want.

Comment: *"...if not, why are you pasting them on StackExchange?"* Don't forget SO isn't all of Stack Exchange. Code Review requires complete, working code, as does Code Golf.

Comment: This is a good argument regarding the situation on SO, but the matter is worse on other SE sites such as Code Review – here people routinely share their fully functional, often quite large programs so that others can provide feedback. With the license change, new questions would fall under the faux-MIT which might be quite unattractive for many contributors, though I'll doubt most would even be aware that by asking for feedback, they've released their code under an extremely liberal license…

Comment: @thegrinner & amon fair point. Comes down to how SE defines "code" (which is not defined anywhere AFAICT). Code Review in particular is in less need of fixing in the first place.

Comment: @abligh it really does, and the lack of the definition concerns me. Admittedly, I'm more afraid of what edits (and the review queue) will do to make that more ambiguous :(

Comment: **MIT without attribution is not an OSI approved licence,** Ummm... Yes it is. CC0 is the public domain dedication. It's basically an open source license - The reason why it wasn't approved **is not** because of the attribution segment, but because of patents - which is a completely separate issue.

Comment: @Zizouz212 thanks, I wrote that completely wrong and have fixed it. I meant that the mangling of the MIT licence proposed is not an OSI approved licence, IE the provision that you can omit the the licence itself if it's attributed.

Comment: @abligh, *"if Alice copies Bob's code [and solely attributes, then Charles can obtain it under Bob's license terms instead of Alice's]. This makes very little sense."* Right. In [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272963), I've fleshed out the scenario you describe.

Comment: @sampablokuper yep. Public domain / CC0 or whatever is actually a viable option, but if SE are intending that, it should be explicit, not a loophole.

Comment: No, waiving MIT's license inclusion requirement doesn't magically make the code public domain. Under the Berne convention, everything is copyrighted, all rights reserved by default. Licenses grant permissions that are normally protected by copyright. So without the license, you don't have permission until you follow that SE URL, and find out that there is a license (SE's custom MIT or whatever).

Comment: "Typically [...] small pieces of code" -- for which copyright often doesn't apply, as non-creative works, so what are you complaining about?

Comment: @phyzome Both the current situation and the proposed new situation give significant uncertainty as to the obligations of someone using the code snippet. It's SE (not me) that is advocating the change, and I am pointing out that the change they advocate does not actually reduce the uncertainty, i.e. 'it's not helpful'.

Answer (score 22):

In case no one has said it already: add a licence selector to a posts where code is detected. If there are multiple blocks, give the option to select fine-grained licences for each one of them. Default it to no licence, or a user-configured one.

I personally consider any code I might write in SO public domain, not MIT or a modified MIT. And I certainly do not want code spammed with SO links.

Comment: The problem is that public domain may not exist in all areas. It's a meaningless thing.

Comment: @ThomasOwens What do you mean by "areas"?

Comment: @TylerH Countries. Legal jurisdictions.

Comment: @ThomasOwens At that level you're getting into international law between nation states... there isn't anything an individual can do there no matter *what* license you use.

Comment: @joojaa Which is why SE shouldn't change the license. They should go with an existing license without modifications. Those should generally work around the world.

Comment: @TylerH Teams of lawyers have written and vetted things like MIT, Apache 2.0, and BSD 2- and 3-clause for use around the world.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes but the problem is that my jurisdiction does not accept wrapper licenses, so whatever stackexhange does is problematic still. The entire concept that the TOS is valid is at stake

Comment: @joojaa I don't know what you mean by "wrapper license". You'll have to provide something for me to read on the subject. If vanilla MIT/BSD/Apache/OSI-approved/FSF-approved licenses were used, I'm not aware of any jurisdiction that would have a problem with them or where they couldn't be enforced.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Okay, but if a country doesn't honor another country's licenses then what are you going to do?

Comment: @ThomasOwens its not that, but the problem is that users aren't bound by conditions set by others, Ticking a checkbox saying i understand the deal isn't necceserily binding.

Comment: @TylerH A country doesn't develop a license. They also don't honor licenses. Individuals honor licenses. Organizations honor licenses.

Comment: If by "wrapper license", you mean that you would not be able to offer the use of the material under another license, that is not so. You still hold the rights to the content, and can offer it under whatever terms you like. You just can't prevent it from being available under MIT _as well_. But perhaps I misunderstand you.

Comment: @joojaa I find that suspicious. You need to provide citations on that.

Comment: @ThomasOwens So what are you going to do if an *individual* person doesn't honor your license? Sue them? What if they're in a country that doesn't honor your country's laws or internationally-agreed upon licenses? Try to get that individual renditioned to your country for trial?

Comment: @TylerH If I felt it was important. I like having that option open to me, yes. It's my content and my intellectual property, I'm going to protect it to the level that I see fit. Would I for a Stack Overflow answer? Probably not. But it's nice to have a strong legal foundation to stand on.

Comment: How would edits work with your licence selector?

Comment: @ThomasOwens After reading your considerations here, I hope I never need one of your answers to help me with a problem.

Comment: I think this would be a good solution, although I think licensed is a better default than unlicensed (and potentially I'd even leave out the "unlicensed" option as too legally confusing/harmful).

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu That's nice, but I hope that you realize that I'm asking for code to be made available under a license that provides similar protections to the current CC BY-SA license and that are well understood and vetted around the world. I would hope that anyone who wants to provide high quality answers and share their knowledge (and on some sites, like Code Review, their "questions" and code for review) would also want the ability to protect their intellectual property as well.

Answer (score 21):

David Thornley has some good insight on this issue which hasn't received much positive attention:

> CC-BY-SA is not an all-permissive license like the modern BSD type.
>   It's much closer to the GPL, in that derivations have to be under a
>   share-alike license.
>
> For some programmers, this is fine. I work on internal software, so it
>   really doesn't matter what Free/Open Source licenses we use. All we
>   need is permission to use, modify, and distribute internally, and
>   that's what we do.
>
> On the other hand, some of us make money by selling software in the
>   traditional sense, and CC-BY-SA isn't compatible with that business
>   model. (I've had a couple of jobs like that.) Some of us work for
>   companies with lawyers or managers who don't "get" free/open source
>   software. (I've had some clueless managers.) In this case, anything
>   short of a BSD-type license might frighten them.
>
> Nor does the "excerpt" idea necessarily help. There is, as far as I
>   know, no official lower bound of what is copyrightable, and there is
>   not necessarily a right to use excerpts. In the US, "fair use" is in
>   the copyright law, but again there's no actual definition: it's a
>   judgment call that should consider several things. There's legal
>   dangers with rewriting snippets also, in that it isn't clear what's a
>   derivative work. All of these would potentially have to be decided in
>   a court of law, and that's expensive.
>
> So, there is a very real problem for individuals or companies that
>   sell proprietary software and don't want to be in the position of
>   having to defend what they include in court.
>
> I think it would help if we had a handy BSD-type license we could slap
>   onto code snippets as we wished.

From [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26008/2915).

Another example where the existing license is shown to be wholly inadequate:

> If you are talking about taking code from Stack Overflow for use in
>   your work, I would be very careful. Even if it is the opinion of the
>   people here that posts to Stack Overflow are covered by Creative
>   Commons, you will need to be able to prove that you got the code from
>   here.
>
> A Short Story To Illustrate:
>
> - Someone else decides the code is a good solution for a problem they
>     are facing, and decides to copy it into their open source GnuFizzBuzz
>     project, covered by the GPL.
> - Five years from now, someone is doing an
>     open source audit on your code (maybe you are selling to a nervous
>     customer, or your company is going public).
> - The open source audit
>     finds the snippet of code you got from Stack Overflow, and recognizes
>     it as originating in GnuFizzBuzz.
> - You are now stuck explaining how/why
>     you have GPL code mixed into your commercial product, or proving that
>     the code was actually from Stack Overflow. Can you prove that the
>     person posting the code to Stack Overflow owned it to begin with
>     (maybe they actually copied it from GnuFizzBuzz to begin wih).
>
> It may
>   sound unlikely, but I have seen this exact situation with my own eyes.
>   The safe thing to do is to regard any code snippets you find as
>   explanations of how something could work. Read, understand, and write
>   a solution based on your understanding. Don't ever cut/paste code you
>   found on the Internet if you are working on a commercial product.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12537/2915))

Comment: Other problems with CC-BY-SA (3.0): it is incompatible with GPL (although version 4 is compatible with GPLv3); it has an anti-DRM clause that makes it impossible to use in e.g. App Store or Steam; the "share alike" clause doesn't differentiate between source and binary forms, so it's a broken copyleft.

Comment: @congusbongus, I think you'll find that CC-BY-SA 3.0 [*is* effectively compatible with GPLv3](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2236).

Comment: Adam Davis, *"the existing license is shown to be **wholly** inadequate"* Er, no. It is admittedly - and rightly - inadequate for people with [sketchy business requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange#comment884204_271166). It is wholly adequate for everybody else :)

Comment: @sampablokuper Are you indicating that the two people I've quoted above that showed problems with the existing license have sketchy business requirements, and we should dismiss their experiences because we disagree with their work?

Comment: @otus This post is intended to demonstrate the issues with the existing license.  At least the first person suggests that a BSD like license (which the MIT is) would resolve their problem. They haven't been on this network for a few months, though, so I'm not sure if these specific changes would resolve their problem. The point of this answer is to demonstrate a need for a license change.

Comment: @AdamDavis, no. I am indicating that those two people haven't shown problems with the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license. It is your claim that CC-BY-SA 3.0 is "wholly inadequate" for SE, and your suggestion that the quotes you provided in any way back up that claim, that I believe to be false.

Comment: @sampablokuper You and I apparently disagree, then, on a more fundamental issue of licensing.  From your perspective I can see why you'd oppose this change, and why you would make this particular distinction. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @AdamDavis, ok, the part you deleted seemed to indicate otherwise (i.e. that the suggested license change would do nothing).

Comment: @otus Yes, your comment helped me to see that it was confusing the issue, so hopefully the answer is more self-consistent.

Answer (score 20):

A few thoughts (that may be familiar to those who read [my last answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271149/256282)):

## 1. The CC BY-SA license should apply to the whole post

Making only non-code contributions be licensed under the CC BY-SA is a completely unnecessary complication. Dual-licensing the code will be much smarter.

## 2. You need to define what "code" is

Some other posters are saying this will be very complicated, but I don't think it will be. If the dual licensing applied only to code in code blocks, then I think that would be a clear and unambiguous definition. It wouldn't catch all code ever, but that's okay. (Yes there would also be some false positives, but I think the simplicity of a definition like this outweighs the downsides.)

## 3. Don't pretend this is the MIT license!

Don't pretend you're using the MIT license when you're not. If you need a unique license for a unique situation then just use a unique license. While crayon licenses in general are a problem, I think that this the Stack Exchange network is a situation where a new ultra-basic license would be warranted. And I know you'll use your legal team to prevent the problems with other crayon licenses.

## 4. It would be best to make a new license

I think it would probably be best to write a new license which is very basic and allows reuse as long as a URL of the post is attached to the borrowed code. It may make sense to make that a non-transferable license, so that those who want to redistribute it again must do so only under the full MIT.

## 5. The license needs to be self contained

You can't have the license, and then list exceptions to it in the *terms of service*. The terms of service are an agreement between us users and the Stack Overflow corporation, but the post license is an agreement between us and the post authors. **Confusing the purposes of a copyright license and a website terms of service is a fundamental mistake.**

If a post is contributed under the MIT license then that is its license, and I doubt it would even be legal for the terms of service to give an exception to it. In addition, the license should apply no matter when you find the post, whether it be here, at some kind of mirror, or at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

## 6. Each post should show its applicable licenses

Each post should indicate below it what the relevant licenses are. If the user has selected only CC BY-SA or CC0 then it could show it. Old posts would show only CC BY-SA (unless perhaps their author edits them and ticks a box saying "update to the new SE-Attribution license"). Posts edited by multiple authors would show only the compatible licenses: new posts without any user opt-ins would be the same as if they only had one author, but if the user did opt-in to CC BY-SA only, then the posts would be only CC BY-SA.

## 7. Fix your footer "attribution required" link

It is [against the terms of the CC BY-SA license to require specific attribution formats](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/429/136). It is dishonest and disingenuous to keep that link in the footer.

Comment: `Applying a blanket definition of "code" to anything in code blocks will end up with a lot of false positives as well.`

Comment: @Mego Sure, but again I don't think it's a big problem. The definition needs to be clear and reasonably reliable.

Comment: It's clear, but not reliable at all. Though code blocks may mainly be used for code on SO and a few SE network sites (Code Review, Code Golf, Programmers, ...), there are many sites that have absolutely nothing to do with code (SFF, RPG, Arqade, ...). On those sites, under your proposal, anything in code blocks would be treated as code, even though it is almost surely *not* code. It's a flawed definition.

Comment: @Mego: Other sites (that don’t use code) shouldn’t use code blocks. Among other things, they make it hard for people using screen readers.

Comment: @chirlu I have myself sometimes used them as a substitute for tables. (Which Stack Exchange really should just support directly!) But even so, I don't think it's a prohibitive use case.

Comment: All good points, this one particularly so: *5. The license needs to be self contained* (and by extension, of course, it won't and can't be the MIT license).

Answer (score 17):

Reactions to this proposal fall into different camps, because there are **different kinds of users** of the Stack Exchange sites, in particular Stack Overflow. I am **not sure this license change will serve all of them**. In particular, I believe other mechanisms might be a better solution to the problems this license change is trying to combat.

---

### Jonny can't get his code to work, and dumps it on Stack Overflow

To be clear, this **already is a problem**. If Jonny works on some commercial project, or is contributing to a copyleft-licensed project, it is **quite unlikely they can share that code** under CC-BY-SA on Stack Exchange. Of course, the real solution is that they **create a MVCE** specifically for their Stack Overflow question rather than dumping their actual code. But by changing the default code license from CC-BY-SA to the faux-MIT, **this problem is worsened**. Whereas sharing a short snippet of internal code with a copy-left license might be forgiveable – it's unlikely to be used in other projects given that the copy-left CC-BY-SA is not compatible with proprietary code –, giving everyone a license to do what the f* they want is far more troubling. I would be **surprised if a reasonable company would continue to allow** their employees to freely ask questions on SO.

The “**what about Code Review?**” argument also falls into this category. Here, large complete programs are shared to be improved. This is already unlikely to be done with commercial code, so questions are mostly by people learning a new language or otherwise improving their skills in their own time. The **CC-BY-SA license is fairly safe** here, but I doubt most question askers on Code Review would be fine with giving their programs away under an extremely liberal license: **I wrote this program, and all I got was this lousy link**.

---

### Janine likes helping people, and is fine with her code being used

Then she can already point out all her code is free. This **does not necessitate a network-wide license change**. Most positive reactions I see to this proposal seem to fall into this category, but it is **the least important**. If you'd like to make this *easier*, you could introduce a **per-post license selector** rather than forcibly relicensing all contributions to this mind set. Such a license selector would merely add formal support for the **already common practice** of dual-licensing code in posts via a notice in the user profile.

---

### Jerome searches for his problem, finds an SO answer, copies the code

While this may be common practice, Jerome is **not allowed** to do this under the CC-BY-SA license<sup>[1]</sup>. He would be **well-served by this change**. As already pointed out elsewhere, the only safe way to use code found on SO is to do a clean-room re-engineering, or to rely on Fair Use laws or limits to copyrightability, which are not consistent across the world.

I am not convinced that this should be encouraged. Maybe SE is right and this is a futile war on license violations, and the best way forward is to legalize what everyone is allegedly already doing? Or SO could invest in better education explaining what is OK and what is not OK to do. In particular, this would imply moving the focus **away from debugging questions back to knowledge questions**.

<sup>[1]: Jerome can *only* incorporate CC-BY-SA code in his project if (a) the project is never published, or (b) the project is also licensed under CC-BY-SA ([see section 4.b](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)). This rules out usage of SE code in most commercial and open-source projects.</sup>

---

### Julia likes sharing her knowledge, not her code

This is where I find myself in this discussion. I love writing stellar answers that provide lasting value. In my experience, the best answers on many sites I participate on (Programmers, Code Review, Stack Overflow) do not actually contain much code. And I am fine with people using this knowledge for whatever purpose. Curing Cancer? Coding Porn Sites? I'm fine with that: knowledge can't be copyrighted.

But expression of knowledge can be, and this extends to code examples I might include in my answers. When I write an answer, I want to be attributed. Properly, with not only a link but also my nick, and with a reference to the license so that people that read my writings know their rights (and restrictions).

In particular, I don't want to feel like I'm doing work for free for other people (which is why I stopped answering all those debugging questions on SO). The copy-left CC-BY-SA license does not forbid commercial use, but it makes sure my answers and all parts thereof will continue to stay free. This is in stark contrast to the faux-MIT license suggested by SE, which would allow my contributions to be made non-free.

Changing the license **will alienate contributors** like Julia or me. If this change comes, I'll think twice before I use runnable code to illustrate my knowledge – maybe, more text or pseudocode would be a better mechanism.

---

### Peter doesn't use Stack Overflow, doesn't care

Why is SE complicating licensing for half the SE network that has nothing to do with code? **From Seasoned Advice to Super User, this change adds no value to every site that isn't Stack Overflow.** Yes, I'm exaggerating. Other sites that might benefit from this change are Game Development, Tex, Wordpress, …, but these are the minority. I understand the desire to limit license fragmentation across the network, but this is a change that should really be applied **on a per-site basis, after discussion on that site's own meta to assure that this change is a benefit.** SE will already need a per-post license indication because they can't re-license old posts, so a per-site policy would make it even simpler for many users!

---

In summary, I do see the appeal of this change for the majority of passive SO users, but I don't see the value for active SO users, or non-SO users.  **I'd very strongly rather not** see this license change happening. And I'm saddened I had to do this analysis myself. It would have been nicer, less sneaky, for SE to demonstrate up-front how this change would impact different users.

Comment: Related answer on the predecessor: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271179/257849

Comment: I'd like to see actual examples of people actually copying code from SO/SE/CR. If you read a solution and want to use it, it's very unlikely that you will actually copy some creative part of it. You will use the knowledge gained from the demonstrated solution in your own project, in your own way, and the result will be your own work. The result is no more a copy than this sentence is a copy pieced together from words copied out of the OED.

Comment: Interesting...I identify completely with "Julia" and you as far as the character of my contributions to SO, but I'm perfectly okay with MIT (although I [do wish it wasn't _faux_-MIT](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273004/159251), as you say.

Comment: *"Jerome searches for his problem, finds an SO answer, copies the code. While this may be common practice, Jerome is not allowed to do this under the CC-BY-SA license."* False. Under CC-BY-SA, everyone is explicitly *allowed* to copy content (and make derivative works, and sell them for profit, etc), as long as they do so in accordance with the terms of CC-BY-SA.

Comment: @sampablokuper CC-BY-SA does allow copying and creating derived works, but those would have to be licensed under a compatible license (see §4.b in CC-BY-SA v3.0). If I copy a CC-BY-SA code snippet into a larger work, I'd argue this larger work would fall under CC-BY-SA as it is an adaption of the original code. Since outside of the code on SE practically no real code is available under this license, it is safe to say that Jerome cannot copy code into a project that would be published under a different license, e.g. GPL or a proprietary program. This wouldn't be a problem with the non-viral MIT

Comment: @amon, your statement in the comment above (*"CC-BY-SA does allow copying and creating derived works, but those would have to be licensed under a compatible license"*) is true. However, the earlier statement you made that I said was false, was false, & at time of writing it is still in your answer. A logically sound argument cannot contain false premises. Therefore the argument in your post was (& remains) logically unsound. Logically unsound arguments should, IMO, be downvoted. If you want to make your answer worth upvoting, please edit it to make it into a logically sound argument. Thanks :)

Comment: @sampablokuper A logically sound argument can use simplifications, and focus on the common cases. I tried to create personas for different user types, but not everybody will find themselves in one of those I suggested. In particular, Jack is missing. Jack works on a personal project, researches a problem on SO, and copies some code. Jack is fine as long he never publishes the project. However, I think it's reasonable assume that most license violations happen by employed programmers or programmers working on projects that will be published.

Comment: @amon, "*A logically sound argument can use simplifications, and focus on the common cases."* Only if the stated premises are true within the universe of discourse. Otherwise, the argument becomes logically unsound. The statement of yours that I called out was false, even in the universe of discourse of your illustrative use case (correct me if I'm wrong!). Anyhow, the footnote you've added in response to my comments improves your post somewhat, so thanks for that :) You *might* find [this](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2236) interesting and relevant.

Answer (score 16):

So you are saying that every time anyone writes

```
Guid optional = new Guid()
```

they must include a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118005/57159) in  a comment?

Just having the possibility of a company getting into legal problems due to their employees not keeping to this, will be enough to get stackoverflow outlawed by lots of legal departments.

Comment: doesn't CC-BY-SA require them to do this *already*? I'm not clear how this proposal changes what does or doesn't *require* attribution...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield,  maybe it does, but this mess needs sorting out if you every expect people to respect a licance..

Comment: This is currently required by CC-BY-SA. The ambiguity in the language of the license when it comes to code is precisely what we want to fix, because it can have precisely the effect you describe. Not because it's known the code came from SO, but because it's unknown if CC-BY-SA is compatible with whatever license they're using.

Comment: This is an extension of the point I made last time. By treating the content as licensed code rather than advice or knowledge, we would be bringing lawyering into the software development process. Precisely the kind of productivity drag that developers loathe.

Comment: @TimPost Can you get a lawyer to confirm that? That line of code does not meet the threshold of originality in the United States, so it's not copyrightable. Since I don't hold a copyright on that line of code, I can't license it to anyone else. The same goes for simple sentences: if I have the sentence "No, I don't think you should do that.", no one needs to do anything special if they happen to use that one sentence. Now, that "answer" would probably be deleted on SE, but that's not the point.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Correct. And this license change doesn't affect that fact, because it legally _can't_. It only applies to code which it *can* apply to. (Obviously.)

Comment: This is not how copyright works. You can independently write the exact same code and remain its author.

Comment: No at both Ian’s question and most comments – such a trivial line is not covered by copyright law and thus doesn’t require a licence. It’s truly in the Public Domain, anywhere.

Comment: Just because it is OK in the USA TODAY does not make it safe, as software is worldwide and lasts for a long time.

Comment: @mirabilos is right.

Answer (score 15):

I generally agree that the license change is a good idea. I would have personally preferred something even less restrictive, but I can understand why the MIT license was chosen.

One part that is getting a bit lost in the discussion here is how problematic the current license for code is. The Creative Commons licenses were never meant for code which leads to various issues when you use them for code as SE is currently doing:

> We recommend against using Creative Commons licenses for software. Instead, we strongly encourage you to use one of the very good software licenses which are already available. We recommend considering licenses made available by the Free Software Foundation or listed as “open source” by the Open Source Initiative.
>
> Unlike software-specific licenses, CC licenses do not contain specific
> terms about the distribution of source code, which is often important
> to ensuring the free reuse and modifiability of software. Many
> software licenses also address patent rights, which are important to
> software but may not be applicable to other copyrightable works.
> Additionally, our licenses are currently not compatible with the major
> software licenses, so it would be difficult to integrate CC-licensed
> work with other free software. Existing software licenses were
> designed specifically for use with software and offer a similar set of
> rights to the Creative Commons licenses.

I'm not a laywer, but because the CC license isn't meant for code it means I'd probably need one to figure out the implications of using CC-BY-SA code in a project. The license is not compatible with all the common open source licenses, and the SA clause is likely to be very problematic in closed source programs.

For me, code in answers is meant to be used. Having a license that can prevent some people from using it is problematic, and something worth fixing in my opinion.

Using a license meant for code makes sense and removes ambiguity. That is why I like the idea in general. There are certainly issues with the current proposal, but I think they're much smaller than the issue we have right now with the existing license.

Comment: *"I can understand why the MIT license was chosen."*. Ahem. The 'MIT License' [was not chosen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272963).

Comment: @sampablokuper I'm not a lawyer, I suspect you're wrong, but I can't be sure. So I'll just contine assuming the chosen license is MIT, at the very least that is the intent

Comment: *"I'll just contine assuming the chosen license is MIT, at the very least that is the intent"*. If it were the intent, why did SE's staff decide to expend great effort (hiring counsel, etc) on overriding such a core part of the license as the notice preservation requirement? Seriously, if they intended to go with the OSI MIT License, nothing was stopping them just doing so.

Answer (score 15):

Just looking at some points you make.

> **Attribution will be required** when you use code found at Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange

I don't get it. Isn't that the case already?

> [image]

Either I've missed something, or... nothing changes there?

Next one.

> We understand that some users feel the new terms are not a perfect fit for certain sites, but we think fragmenting the license across the network will lead to ambiguity – the exact problem we’re trying to solve by updating the terms.

I can be mistaken, but I don't recall different sites of Stack Exchange family to have their content licensed differently. As the footer stays, "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required". Currently it says so on any SE site. Then the license doesn't appear to be fragmented? There's no problem then, let's keep the old good traditions... But wait, you're now changing the license and it appears to *cause problems*. Isn't that a sign that something is done not in the right way?

> This change is just a first step in establishing clarity for using code found on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange

As I've mentioned above, the footer says the attribution is required... linking to [Jeff's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). Anything you mention doesn't appear to contradict with the point of Jeff and hence the rules which we're complying now. In fact, the blog post is being more descriptive regarding the contribution.

> Also, we want to make sure everyone has ample opportunity to provide feedback and we have time to consider it. We are more concerned with doing this right than doing it fast, so please let us know what you think about this proposed change.
>
> ...
>
> We want to hear what you think. Barring any showstopper, these terms and a detailed FAQ will be rolled out March 1, 2016.

Woops. Doesn't it look like you won't consider the feedback provided there? I mean, possible at first, and evident now, the "showstopper" is the feedback posted here and in the previous thread of yours. This means that asking for the feedback doesn't make any sense... Or probably the question should be reworded (note that some of us have been already tempted to close it as "unclear what you're asking").

---

I'm not discussing the advantages of one license over another, just because I have no idea what it gives. You change the license and the reason of the change seems to be missing - if you'd like to receive more valuable feedback, probably it'd be better to list the FAQ you're mentioning.

Answer (score 14):

**The proposed terms are reducible to any license, including [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) or [WTFPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL)**.

For 'code' (which you can't even be bothered to define), the terms you are proposing possess a gaping license-laundering loophole and are legally reducible to [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) or any other desired license. I'll explain how.

The [post above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956) proposes the following new licensing terms.

> Starting March 1, 2016, new contributions across the network will be
>   licensed to the public under the following terms:
>
> - Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the terms of CC-BY-SA
> - Code contributions will be available for use under the terms of [the MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
> - You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT
>     License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give
>     reasonable attribution. This optional exception to the MIT License
>     will live in our terms of service.

That "MIT License" ([which is really](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MIT_License&oldid=696448101#Various_versions) the OSI MIT License or the Expat License) states:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software **without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to** use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   **distribute, sublicense**, and/or sell copies of the Software, **and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so.**

The *only* restriction the OSI MIT License imposes is the requirement to include a copy of the copyright notice and the permission notice. However, Stack Exchange's proposed terms waive that requirement (see above: *"Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement"*).

This means that:

1. A first generation derivative work would have to include attribution, but would be able to be distributed under a license not requiring attribution or sharing alike, e.g. [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) or [WTFPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL).
2. Anyone receiving such a first derivative work is therefore not required to attribute or to share alike (e.g. in any second derivative works).
3. Anyone will be able to re-license, in this way, any 'code' posted to Stack Exchange sites.
4. 'Code' posted to Stack Exchange sites can therefore ultimately be used in any way a <s>plagiarist</s> derivative author wishes. As such, it is effectively [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (or [WTFPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL), etc) licensed.

This loophole means that your proposed change to Stack Exchange's licensing terms ultimately undermines any desire you (or we!) may have that Stack Exchange contributors should be required to be treated with respect and acknowledgement by users of their contributions.

**Please don't go ahead with your proposed change to Stack Exchange's licensing terms.**

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The MIT license would apply to any downstream copies you provide, or any combined work. The downstream recipient is free to not carry the license, as you were - but the second they remove the URL, they forfeit their privilege to not reproduce the license. It's MIT (which, fortunately, is compatible with every less-permissive license known, so it's not a big problem) but we'd in no way become a 'laundry service' for code licensing.

Comment: @TimPost, I believe you are mistaken. A person who receives a work that purports to be under some specific license conditions is only bound by those license conditions in relation to that work (and of course also bound by the (inter)national laws in place in the relevant jurisdiction).

Comment: They're bound by the _terms of the license in which the work is granted to their use_. Much like I couldn't take code from GNU Bash, post it on Stack Overflow and say "Hey look, this is CC-BY-SA  (or, soon, MIT) now!" It's not, it's GPL3+. There will always be bad actors that don't respect the terms of a license, and some areas in the world where the sparse amount of copyright law doesn't make them enforceable (or even legal) - but this is not a new problem, and not at all specific to us.

Comment: @TimPost, have you even read the [OSI MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)? It explicitly states, *'Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software **without restriction**, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, **distribute, sublicense**, and/or sell copies of the Software, **and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so**.'*

Comment: @TimPost, *"I couldn't take code from GNU Bash, post it on Stack Overflow and say "Hey look, this is CC-BY-SA (or, soon, MIT) now!"* That's because GNU Bash is under GPLv3+. However, if GNU Bash was licensed under samthebrand's proposed terms, you could legally do *anything you wanted with it*, including claiming you wrote it yourself, by simply following the steps that I outlined.

Comment: @TimPost, the *only* restriction the OSI MIT License imposes is the requirement to include a copy of the copyright notice and the permission notice. Since your proposed terms waive that requirement, your terms are effectively CC0.

Comment: Again - if they got the code from one of our sites, they _can't_ distribute it unless they keep the URL in tact or reproduce the MIT license as required (their option). And again - there will _always_ be bad actors that don't follow the rules, but _most_ developers (at least that I know) are pretty careful to do the right thing when it comes to licenses, and just giving people credit. There is no _perfect_ bullet proof scheme, and if there were, it would be so rigid that nobody could use it.

Comment: @TimPost: We're not discussing "got the code from one of our sites", we're discussing "got the code from an intermediate", where that intermediate got it from StackOverflow, and elected to use attribution without including the MIT license, via the crayon option samthebrand wrote in.

Comment: @TimPost, you are factually wrong, sorry. Follow the steps and you'll see that each one is legal.

Comment: @sampablokuper Step 2 is illegal. The person doing it just has to hunt around and find the Stack Overflow link buried in the code to know that. They're ultimately re-using code licensed under SO's modified MIT license, so they have to meet the original license requirements, even though they were never given a copy. So, really, it's more Step 1 that's the problem, because the code wasn't strictly CC0. The new code in the first generation work was CC0, but the stuff pulled in from SO wasn't, since they don't have the right to relicense it quite that way. I think. Consult your local lawyer.

Comment: @BillyMailman, step 2 is not illegal. Anyone who receives a work licensed under CC0 is legally perfectly entitled to use that work under the terms of CC0.

Comment: @BillyMailman, step 1 is not illegal either. It entirely satisfies Stack Exchange's proposed new terms.

Comment: @BillyMailman, I increasingly think that TimPost and samthebrand genuinely don't know what they are doing. Tim's comments above make it clear that he believes that their proposed new terms do something quite different than what those terms themselves actually state. It is like observing a programmer whose comments and code express substantially different semantics.

Comment: @sampablokuper Re-reading it a bit more, I'm 99% sure step 1 in your scenario is the illegal bit. You won't have to re-include the full license text, but this iteration of the new license absolutely requires reasonable attribution at all times. The person making a CC0-licensed work is including code without attributing it, and in so doing is breaking the law, because they're claiming the code they're releasing is all CC0. The fact that you don't need to include the full text of the license, doesn't change that it's still under that license. (cont...)

Comment: Folks - when you get into these kinds of waters there's a subtle difference between being _not wrong_ and being _correct_. I believe I'm not wrong, but I'm not entirely certain that I'm correct (you can be correct in all cases _but_ something). I'm going to check with our counsel (this could take a few days), and I'll relay his take.

Comment: (...) On the other hand, say they do release it with proper attribution by having a brief mention in their CC0 license that some included code isn't theirs, it's under MIT, credit goes to this person, etc. In that case, the onus falls on the person re-using that CC0 code to have looked into it, noticed the attribution, and respected the MIT license that the SO-originating code is under. Easy enough, since that just means preserving the attribution, but that's still a bit of a minefield, having to look through code you use to see if there's an SO link anywhere. Not sure I'm happy with that part

Comment: As far as being CC0 [take a look at section 4a of the full language](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode) - it's _not_ CC0.

Comment: @BillyMailman, *"Re-reading it a bit more, I'm 99% sure step 1 in your scenario is the illegal bit. ... The person making a CC0-licensed work is including code without attributing it..."* Wrong, sorry. The person in step 1 **does** attribute and thereby satisfies SE's proposed new terms. *"... and in so doing is breaking the law, because they're claiming the code they're releasing is all CC0."* Wrong again. The proposed new SE terms explicitly give the person in step 1 the right to sublicense the code without restriction, which would include (sub)licensing it as CC0. So no law is broken there.

Comment: @BillyMailman, *"the onus falls on the person re-using that CC0 code [in step 2] to have looked into it, noticed the attribution, and respected the MIT license that the SO-originating code is under."* Wrong yet again. That code was legitimately licensed under CC0 (or WTFPL etc), and the person in step 2 therefore has no such onus as you describe; they merely have to abide by the license under which the work was legitimately distributed to them.

Comment: Errr, MIT does *not* give you the right to relicense as CC0. It gives you the right to relicense as any [compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility) license, but CC0 ain't one. Never has been, and I'm not sure where you got the idea that it is.

Comment: @sampablokuper you forgot to add "... subject to the following conditions: The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software." So no, even with the MIT license, you cannot do as you please. You have to retain the copyright statement and the permission notice, which essentially means you have to sublicense under MIT, no matter what you do.

Comment: @miraculixx, no, I did not forget to add that. The proposed new SE terms waive those conditions. Please re-read my post.

Comment: @sampablokuper just re-read your comment. You linked to the OSI MIT and quote from it, however stopping just before the part that I mentioned.

Comment: @BillyMailman, *"MIT does not give you the right to relicense as CC0"*. Whether the OSI MIT License by itself does or doesn't is irrelevant here, because the proposed new SE terms *do* give you that right. Which part of "sublicense without restriction" and "permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement" is unclear to you?

Comment: @miraculixx, right. As should be clear from my reply to you, and from my post, I omitted that part because the proposed new SE terms **waive** that part.

Comment: Where are you getting the quoted text "sublicense without restriction" from? It's not in the proposal.

Comment: @sampablokuper I had understood "reasonable attribution" as a statement of copyright and terms, including that the licence is still morally MIT (with the warranty disclaimer, etc.). For example, "Copyright 2016, <Name>. Available under the terms of the MIT licence from <StackExchange link>." In this case your scenario would not apply. But you are absolutely right that it is not clear what "reasonable attribution" means exactly. I find it hard to believe that any court would countenance relicensing in the way you describe, but maybe I would be surprised.

Comment: @TimPost, *"I'm going to check with our counsel..."* If that's the same counsel that advised you in the first place, they're unlikely to be any the wiser. Please check with counsel who are knowledgeable and competent in this area. Maybe [Eben Moglen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eben_Moglen), [Larry Lessig.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Lessig), or [Jennifer Granick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Granick).

Comment: @BillyMailman, *'Where are you getting the quoted text "sublicense without restriction" from?'* From the OSI MIT License. I should have put an ellipsis in there, sorry: "sublicense ... without restriction" (or, if you prefer, "without restriction ... sublicense"). But my post and earlier comments make it clear.

Comment: @OleksandrR., *'you are absolutely right that it is not clear what "reasonable attribution" means exactly.'* Actually, I did not make any statement to that effect. Moreover, samthebrand clearly stated, "A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution." However, I'm glad you raised this point, because although he said that in his post, it **does not** appear in the proposed new terms. Thank you for alerting me to that :)

Comment: @sampablokuper Ahah! You're ignoring the "subject to the following restrictions:" bit, then. There are two such restrictions. One is attribution ("The above copyright notice... shall be included in all copies..."), the other is reproducing the license ("this permission notice shall be included in all copies..."). They're in the same sentence, but they're still two separate things. Stack Overflow's only planning to remove the latter (license replication) one. The attribution requirement will likely be modified (to allow a simple URL to be enough), but won't be being removed. Thus, no CC0.

Comment: It was not intended as an exact quote but, as I understood it, that was the main thrust of your objection. Maybe I understood you incorrectly, or I am being too charitable towards the proposal by assuming SE do not intend to suggest that one can just disclaim the licence terms altogether. I think for example your apparent suggestion in the last few comments above that the MIT licence allows its own terms to be disclaimed is not a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @BillyMailman, *'Ahah! You're ignoring the "subject to the following restrictions:" bit, then.*' No, I am not ignoring it. That part is **waived** by the proposed SE terms, which - for the umpteenth time! - state "permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement". That permission states that no notice preservation is required. Therefore, neither the copyright notice nor the permission notice need to be preserved. Therefore, sublicensing as CC0 (or WTFPL) is permitted under the proposed terms.

Comment: @OleksandrR., *"your apparent suggestion in the last few comments above that the MIT licence allows its own terms to be disclaimed is not a reasonable interpretation."* I made no such suggestion. However, the proposed new SE licensing terms introduce an explicit waiver of the relevant parts of the OSI MIT License. No interpretation is therefore required, and I cannot therefore to be held to have made an unreasonable interpretation :)

Comment: Clearly what you intend is rather different to my understanding of it, then. Anyway, I honestly think that failure to preserve the licence notice will just result in *no licence* and an unusable product, not *any licence* and something that can be used however anyone sees fit. SE should not advocate it knowing that it will cause problems, but I don't see how they can be held liable for giving bad advice: the user ultimately has to take responsibility for their own bad decisions.

Comment: @sampablokuper I firmly believe that "permission to ignore the MIT License's notice preservation requirement" does not include permission to ignore the copyright requirement. But at this point, you'll need to consult your local lawyer to be sure. I'm sure Stack Overflow will. If nothing else, I understand what you're expressing here, even if we disagree.

Comment: @OleksandrR., redistribution without *any* license would indeed result in *no license*. However, legitimate redistribution under a different license would result in the latter applying.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how redistribution under a different licence can ever be "legitimate", because regardless of whether the copyright notice is preserved or not, the MIT terms still apply. Just because "MIT without notice preservation requirement" is basically the same as CC0, it does not mean that one can arbitrarily decide that the licence *is* CC0. If one has any sense, one will preserve the notice. At least that would be my position on it. I (think I) understand what you are driving at, but your interpretation seems to be borderline pathological--not that this is a bad thing.

Comment: "that does not prevent the work being sublicensed under CC0/WTFPL/etc" You seem to misunderstand the word "sublicense". It emphatically does not mean the same thing as "relicense". As a licensee, you may grant a third party _only those rights that you yourself have_. You may not change the terms of the existing license, nor may you lessen the restrictions of the existing license. Your procedure fails at the first step: the MIT license does not permit this kind of relicensing.

Comment: @BillyMailman, I hope we at last at least agree what we are disagreeing about :) I'm not totally convinced, we do, though! ;) The proposed terms simply require "reasonable attribution" in step 1. They do not necessarily the copyright notice. ("A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution", acc samthebrand *outside* the terms.) Regardless, even if the copyright notice *is* preserved in step 1, that does not prevent the work being sublicensed under CC0/WTFPL/etc. And once that happens, then the copyright notice can legally be ignored/removed/modified in subsequent derivative works.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I refer you to my [earlier comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required/272963?noredirect=1#comment886725_272963).

Comment: And I refer you to the definition of "sublicense", which you've incorrectly conflated with "relicense" there.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, show me what's incorrect about my interpretation of the proposed new SE license terms. I don't think you'll find anything :) Note the "without restriction, **including**" part of the OSI MIT License. Which rights are granted under the proposed new SE terms that can't be granted by the licensor under CC0 or WTFPL?

Comment: It's not the rights, it's the other terms. You cannot remove requirements that you're bound by when you _sub_license. Which means the requirement to include attribution/a copy of the license.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, *"It's not the rights, it's the other terms... the restriction to include attribution/copy of the license."* Sigh. The restriction to include a copy of the license is **explicitly waived** in the proposed new SE terms, as I mentioned in my post. As for attribution, I took that into account as well when I wrote my post. It is also addressed at length in the comments above, with exactly the same conclusion.

Comment: The requirement is to _either_ include the attribution _or_ the copy of the license. You can't do _neither_, and nor can those to whom you _sub_license.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, earlier, I said, "... can't be granted by the licensor..." That was a typo on my part. I meant licensee, nor licensor. Now, to your point: *"The requirement is to either include the attribution or the copy of the license. You can't do neither."* If you read my post, you'll see that that requirement is taken into account. In step 1, the licensee gives attribution, precisely in accordance with the proposed new terms. Nothing in the proposed new terms prevents the licensee *also* distributing the derived work under a new license. They may "deal in the Software without restriction".

Comment: I think I've made my case here adequately comprehensively. The latest comments seem to me to be rehashing arguments already made. Please, if you're thinking of commenting, read and re-read the post and comment thread first. If you *do* decide to comment, please understand that I probably won't reply unless you point out something I consider truly novel and relevant.

Comment: "Nothing in the proposed new terms prevents the licensee also distributing the derived work under a new license." The license itself, and its enforceability via copyright law, do so. If that weren't the case, any license would be literally useless. "They may 'deal in the Software without restriction'" "Deal in" means "sell", **not** "relicense".

Comment: You've comprehensively rehashed the same misunderstandings, yes. Carry on.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, *"The license itself, and its enforceability via copyright law, do so."* Other licenses might, but not that particular license under the proposed new SE terms, for the reasons I have given. *"Deal in" means "sell", not "relicense"* "Deal in" can mean "sell", but it does not only ever mean "sell". If I give you something free of charge, I am nevertheless dealing in that thing. And in this case, I can do so without restriction, thereby allowing me to relicense as part of that dealing.

Comment: I think TimPost et al. appreciate what you're trying to do by carefully analyzing the proposal looking for potential pitfalls/loopholes, but now that you've raised the issue it would probably make more sense to wait for an actual lawyer to chime in than to continue debating the point yourself against other non-lawyers.

Comment: Also, FYI, the first link in your "about me" text on your profile appears to be incorrect; you mention "Michael Richter", but the link goes to an article about biology that appears to have nothing to do with free-software concerns (Ctrl-F "Michael Richter" finds nothing.)

Comment: @KyleStrand, thanks for pointing out the incorrect link. That is now fixed.

Comment: It seem to me that a core part of the difficulty in this conversation is the attempt to create a crayon license. We don't actually know what the terms of the license will be, because it's only been presented as "MIT with the preservation requirement waived". That's incredibly unhelpful when it comes to evaluating the precise legal impacts of the license. It would be far easier to have this conversation if SE would just create a new license that is explicit in its legal requirements, or if they're not willing to do that at least give us the wording of the waiver.

Comment: @sampablokuper I believe the confusion here is because it is easy to imagine that code published with no license is therefore free for anyone to use as they wish. In fact, the way copyright law works, the lack of a license means that no one may use it. So if you find code which has no license but only attribution, the lack of a license prevents you using that code for any purpose, but the attribution allows you to find a version of that code that does include a license.

Comment: (I'm still uncomfortable with the crayon license but hopefully that clears up this particular worry.)

Comment: @trichoplax, *"the way copyright law works, the lack of a license means that no one may use it. So if you find code which has no license but only attribution, the lack of a license prevents you using that code for any purpose, but the attribution allows you to find a version of that code that does include a license."* I am well aware of this. In the scenario laid out in my answer, there is no step predicated upon a person finding "code which has no license but only attribution". So your comment, although accurate & truthful, is irrelevant to my answer, & I believe my conclusion still stands.

Comment: @Tim yes, and of course the crayon license has not been tested in courts, which adds to uncertainty.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>If there *has* to be a new code license:</sub>

Please license code *additionally* under CC BY-SA.

So that everything (like posts and threads *as a whole*) is licensed under CC BY-SA, and code is licensed under the code license in addition.

Comment: As someone who isn't the most familiar with licenses, can you explain why this is important / what benefit this has?

Comment: @Vlad274 CC BY-SA enforces that you can share or alter the original material, but you must leave attribution to the original material and must release it under CC BY-SA. As for benefits, I am unsure. [More info](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) on CC BY-SA.

Comment: @unor, I don't believe this makes sense, on two fronts. 1. Dual-licensing under CC-BY-SA and MIT won't require anyone to abide by the terms of CC-BY-SA, as long as they were abiding by the terms of MIT. 2. Despite what he says, samthebrand isn't proposing code be licensed under the MIT license, he's proposing a crayon license that is significantly different from the MIT license.

Comment: @Vlad274: It makes it easier for people that want to use CC BY-SA, e.g., for sharing/publishing/archiving/etc. whole questions with all answers (like it’s currently possible): they shouldn’t have to look into MIT at all.

Comment: @MarioTrucco That doesn't matter. Compatibility means using work licensed under one license in a project licensed by another. You can multi-license your content under any licenses that you want. It's your content.

Comment: @sampablokuper: Regarding 1.: Yes, it’s for people that *want* to use CC BY-SA, without having to worry or care or attribute according to or read about the (additional) code license. The proposal should ideally keep everything like it is (licensed under CC BY-SA) and license code **in addition** under whatever license.

Comment: @ThomasOwens But can you multi-license your content under licenses contracdicting each other? I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @sampablokuper: I don't think anyone here believes that dual-licensing means that both license terms would need to be followed. It just means you can choose which license to use the work under. I definitely agree that a post *as a whole* should still be CC-BY-SA, no matter what licensing applies the "code parts" of it.

Comment: @MarioTrucco Yes. If it's multi-licensed in one location, the user gets to choose which license he uses it under. If it's available at different locations, the user needs to abide by the license by which he or she received it.

Comment: A big reason that we're doing this is the wording of cc-by-sa is _really_ ambiguous when compared to wording in strictly-code licenses, which makes compatibility a frequent point of consternation. And it's a growing problem. The MIT license is compatible with _every single_ OSI-approved licenses in existence (and most of the ones  that aren't approved too). What the problem means to some people is their boss telling them they can't check in any code from SO, even if it's their own code someone was nice enough to help them fix.

Comment: @Bergi, AFAIK the OSI MIT License is CC-BY-SA compatible. That means that it is perfectly legal for work licensed under MIT to be incorporated/adapted into a derivative work that is licensed not under MIT but rather under CC-BY-SA. So, if a work is already licensed under OSI MIT, then dual-licensing it under CC-BY-SA is, although not harmful in any way, also completely pointless. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sampablokuper: Thanks, that's a valid point (if you're right, and if the same applies to the not-quite-MIT-thing). But apparently nobody knows this. Dual-licensing the code might be pointless from the legal standpoint, but imo it makes my choices easier to understand.

Comment: @TimPost: So the reason for not licensing code additionally under CC BY-SA is to enable people to post code that currently aren’t allowed to (e.g., their boss says: permissive = yes, copyleft = no)? If that’s the case: I could take MIT-licensed code posted to SO and share it under CC BY-SA (if I add, or keep in tact, the MIT notices), right? So the boss wouldn’t be happy anyway.

Comment: @TimPost It's not clear the advantages of these changes (the first post pointed the problem being that code licensing is currently covered with some uncertainty). Your comment showed a new aspect of it for me (despite I still don't understand what's the problem in checking in SO code). Exploring the reasoning behind that move would be important to better understand the whole change motivation and know what's the real problem with the current (well accepted) status quo. We're having all these discussions, and we still don't have an easy way to properly identify the trade-offs of each proposal.

Comment: @Bergi, *"But apparently nobody knows this."* I think it's pretty well understood by everyone who pays adequate attention to FLOSS software licensing. (And yes, since the proposed new SE licensing is [effectively CC0](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272963), it is CC-BY-SA compatible, too). I see your point about being explicit, but then you should perhaps dual-license under every possibly OSI MIT-compatible license, which might be even more confusing for people? Better just to stick with CC-BY-SA :)

Comment: @TimPost IMO, the best way to resolve that problem, which will comprehensively address it without introducing new problems, is simply to declare the new licence to be CC-BY-SA 4.0 rather than the existing 3.0. It does not contain any unwarranted assumptions about the work being artistic or creative in nature, and overall it is quite clear how it can be applied to code.

Answer (score 13):

This whole thing is moot, because you have no idea about the status of anything that is posted to this site.

Simply demanding that it must be MIT licensed doesn't *make* it MIT licensed.

```
#include <std/abe-lincoln-dog-leg-tail-quote.h>
```

People **will** do things like, *"Oh, we solved that problem here at XYZ Inc. with the following code; I'm sure my boss won't mind if I share a few lines ..."*. Only they won't say that part, but rather only **think** it as they copy and paste.

And what about all the people who contribute answers to SO, but are doing it on work time, using company equipment? That code could be owned by the company, according to the employment agreement, even if it is invented on the spot and doesn't appear in any company product.

**Therefore, everyone in their right mind will not use anything more than a three-line snippet from some random website without paraphrasing it so that it doesn't resemble the original.**

Attributing it is the stupidest thing you can do; you're exposing yourself to legal problems when your program clearly reveals the origin of some section of code, and that section of code is under a legal contention (it was posted to a website, but is in fact proprietary).

As a developer using snippets of other people's code of uncertain origin, you have two main responsibilities:

1. Don't do it.
2. If you must do it, make it yours. Paraphrase the code into your own expression. Work with it. Understand every detail as if you had written it yourself. Basically, use the original as an implementation guide.
   If there is ever the slightest suspicion that it is a knockoff of that original, you will easily be able to play dumb---by playing smart! You know that code inside out and can answer questions about it as if you had written it yourself, and can probably reproduce most of it from memory.

Basically, the honest thing in StackOverflow is to just have a big disclaimer:

> **We don't really know where any of this code came from, or what is its licensing status; if you incorporate anything verbatim into your product, you implicitly acknowledge that you do so at your own legal and technical risk. Stack Exchange offers no protection from infringment claims arising from third parties, and makes no warranties about the correctness of any code or its suitability for any purpose. Imagine the most draconian legal disclaimer that your eyes have never seen. Now multiply it by two.**

That's it! Everything else is superfluous posturing that doesn't mean a thing and won't hold up in court.

Here is something to consider:

**When you contribute original code to a GNU Project project, you will be asked to assign the copyright to the Free Software Foundation. Not only that, but you need some affidavit letter from your employer that the code is really yours to give away; that they lay no claim on it. (I have been through this myself, so I know!) That's what then enables the GNU Project to claim that the code is under the GPL, with a fairly certain copyright status.  StackExchange neglects to put contributors through anything of this sort (for understandable reasons, such as it putting a huge damper on the party). But that means there is no basis for asserting any fact about the copyright or licensing status of anything that is posted.**

Comment: A large part of why we have content licenses is to protect content consumers from the unwitting actions of employees as you describe.

Comment: @SeanAllred What does that mean? Will StackExchange take the fall for me if I use something and end up in hot water? "Protect" is something to which we can attach a dollar figure. For instance, when you buy some kind of insurance, it is spelled out what is covered for how much: everything is in dollars.

Comment: In case proprietary code is posted on SO, wouldn't the user who posted it be held legally responsible? I can see how removing code that turned out not to be under MIT from a program might be problematic, but I m not so sure about who would be in real ($) trouble.

Comment: Re proprietary code: You can't post that on SO, it's aginst the terms of service. See [§3 - Subscriber Content](http://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent): *"You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange... Subscriber warrants, represents and agrees Subscriber has the right to grant Stack Exchange and the Network the rights set forth above..."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you absolutely can post propriertary code, it's just that you are not allowed to. Else this whole legal thing would not be necessary.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: There's no question what "can't" meant in my comment, fiddling about with semantics is not useful. You *can* rob a store, drive while drunk, and evade taxes. You're just not allowed to. Further, the change under discussion has nothing to do with posting proprietary code and "not being allowed to" isn't the legal issue at hand. The legal issue at hand is *using* code that *has been* posted, and what the license says about what you need to do when doing so (and what license you're granting when posting).

Comment: Funny, I was thinking the same thing re semantics. I don't want to argue, I am saying that - since clearly people "can" steal code and post it here - the only "protection" that is added by the license is that I can try and argue that I used the code in good faith. This will not help me in a court of law.

Comment: @Kaz I'm on mobile and can't respond to everyone, but to clarify: SE licenses content CC and makes this known. This would mean (to my understanding) that liability rests solely with the employee.

Comment: This answer is **the** answer. This whole ordeal by SE appears to be a way to "legally" enforce a "solid" system. As you point out, this is impossible. Maybe the code I've shared, I've decompiled from someone's closed-source project. Maybe I stole it from work. Then there's the other side of it. I've spent 5 years part and full time developing a very complex program. I want to share part of it on an answer here, but I don't want my license changed to X. Therefore, I pack up and take my knowledge elsewhere. This is all bad, they should have left it alone.

Answer (score 13):

We're talking about a somewhat drastic change and I can't even give my voting input on this; this is problematic.

Additionally, I'd like to suggest the **FAQ** created not be an incomprehensible collection of legal jargon. *Many people are just starting with programing in general*, let alone licences. To add to that, *this is a site where many people's first language is not English*.

You *must* be able to present things in a way most people can understand.

Comment: An answer is a far better way to express your position than a single, silent downvote.

Comment: @Adam, as of now 486 votes (both sides) have been cast on this question. Had everyone posted an answer instead of voting, the whole thread would have become unexploitable.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sure. There's the option to upvote existing answers that state whatever points you'd make, though. The whole "I'm posting this answer only to gain rep so I can downvote" thing (see revisions on this post) is pure noise either way.

Comment: @Adam, you have a point, I did miss the first revision of this answer.

Comment: @AdamLear An overwhelming majority of downvotes *is* a message in itself.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not arguing against voting. See my previous comment.

Comment: @AdamLear The post was pretty much a knee-jerk reaction to the **"Your response to the proposal was positive – 85% of votes on the proposal were upvotes."** line. I really agree with you, an answer is a much more efficient mean to transmit ones thoughts. The problem seems to be that conclusions are based on vote count, not answer content.

Comment: @Jim Yeah... we took a wrong turn there, I agree.

Answer (score 12):

### But what is code?

As non-SO user, this is the *central* question for me here.
My main hub of activity is [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com), and we have quite a lot of maybe-code there.

You say:

> We will give you guidance on identifying code in an upcoming FAQ, plus guidance on how best to comply with the attribution requirement.

Before you do this, it is impossible to give feedback. Please provide this FAQ asap.

> But ultimately, identifying code will be a judgement call on your part. We have full faith in your ability to do this.

Who is "your"? Authors? I guess. Other regular users? Maybe. Visitors? No way.

Drive-by visitors can on average not be bothered to adhere to even the most basic things prominently put in the FAQ, and you want them to read the ToS? Do they even have to accept them when they to not register? They certainly don't when they just google upon some content. The footer? Good look expressing the rules clearly in *that* format.

Even if I *do* read the rules as a visitor (a popup when I hit CTRL+V maybe?), what am I to do? Risk that somebody sues me?

#### Summary

Case distinction:

1. Most users of SE (visitors and registered users) are not aware of the license-for-code topic. "SE is CC, right?"

   *Consequence:* the code license is useless.
2. Users are aware, but we don't actually punish violations of the license, because we have to assume it was by accident ("Ah, they probably thought that was not code") and we don't want to be dickheads.

   *Consequence:* the code license is useless.
3. Users are aware, and we actively try to punish violations of the license whenever we notice them (an event I estimate would have extremely low incidence).

   *Consequence:* nobody copy-pastes anything from SE anymore because they won't want to open themselves up to litigation. Plus, we have become dickheads, arguably.

#### Conclusion

Without strict objective guidelines and visual indication about what constitutes code (and thus which license applies), a code license is useless and/or harmful for non-programming sites that deal with any kind of "code" (read: sites on which there is any amount of ambiguity as to what is code and what is not; some SO answers may even be affected).

Please don't.

Comment: It is also not possible to form popup on event - just block JS or visit from text browser - any agreement on license if not explicitly stated before downloading the code is problematic. If code was taken from copy of content, and there is no explicit license - it has probably none (it was released, author is not embeded, license is not given).

Comment: @EvilJS I agree. That parenthetical remark is mostly a cynical joke; even if possible, it would clearly be a horrible idea.

Comment: In some cases - to honor authorship - full name and contact info is needed, and author is obliged to provide license. So attribution goes like this "I credit EvilJS for code given via chat". Seems cool, but I do not need it, and when this is really needed - somebody would have to contact me. Here is a problem - nobody can assure 100% success. And still several years ago it was easier to buy cd with linux than download it - there was evidence of rights to use it... If I am needed to show that I wrote it I would need court to get ISP logs - which in other case are unavailable even to me.

Comment: "Do they even have to accept them when they to not register?" - If I get it right, you imply that someone can avoid accepting ToS/not read ToS, and do as he wishes with the code he copies? The copyright of the code won't just magically disappear because they didn't care to read it. This answer looks so incorrect.

Comment: "..because they won't want to open themselves up to litigation." - Currently everything is under CC-BY-SA. Using content  *already is* under legal restrictions.

Comment: @Fermiparadox There already are rules, but they are the same always. Not with the proposed changed, which introduces uncertainty about what the rules are. The issue with the ToS is tangential; it's an argument that the expectation expressed in the proposal that user's will *all* be able to identify code *in the same way* is overly optimistic.

Answer (score 12):

The core problem that all of this is intended to solve is that people are *copying* material from Stack Overflow into their code... and that the license for CC-BY-SA isn't ideal for code.

The question *behind* this problem is "why are they copying the code?"

---

Let's take an old post on SO: [Apache POI autoSizeColumn resizes to minimum width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20924299).  When one looks at the code in the question, it is clear that it is an MCVE. It does *stuff*, but it clearly isn't actual code.  Likewise, the answer presents *knowledge* of essentially "you need to call this method."

As the code presented in the question was an MCVE and the code in the answer was in the form of knowledge, it should be fairly clear to people that there will be no copyright or licensing issues generated from this Q&A post - no one is copying any code.

However, I believe that this question is the exception to what SO has become. The vast majority of the questions are not MCVEs but rather "here is my actual code from my homework or real code from work" and the answers are snippets of *code* rather than information about solving the problem.

> #### Question
>
> I have a problem.
>   Here is my code.
>
> ```
> {large block of code}
> ```
>
> Thanks.

> #### Answer
>
> Try
>
> ```
> {block of code}
> ```
>
> Hope this helps.

And here, the licensing of the question and the answer is *critical* because the answer *will* be copied directly into the code outside of SO.

No longer is this about transferring knowledge about a problem - it is a code writing and debugging service.

There are many individuals on Stack Overflow who are providing *knowledge* to people - knowledge about how to fix the problem rather than the fix itself. Yes, this is a gray area. There are some that are clearly on one side of the line, there are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13441470) that are clearly on the other side of the line.

I contend that questions that ask for solutions rather than knowledge are becoming by in far the dominant type of questions on SO. And likewise, answers that hand the actual code that can be copy and pasted into the problem code are likely the dominant type of answers on SO.

This isn't the case on most other technology sites, even where code is presented.

Trying to apply this solution to an SO problem across the entire network, while consistent, makes for many headaches on other sites where it is *knowledge* that is being transferred and any code is demonstrative of that knowledge and not intended to be copy and pasted into a solution.

---

One thing that should be looked at in part on this is an attempt to redirect the culture of asking and answering on SO *back* to transfer of knowledge rather than 'fix my code'.

If, on the other hand the 'fix my code' with 'here is the answer' is the intended state of Stack Overflow, reexamine how to fix Stack Overflow's Q&A model to better reflect that along with the necessary licensing changes. Don't change everyone else's licensing because people are indiscriminately copying code from SO answers into their code.

Sites that go more into *explaining* code may need to use material from other projects that isn't compatible *as code* into CC-BY-SA, but is acceptable under fair use; that the material there is intended to explain - not be copied into other projects.  Pulling a method out of some GPL code to show an of mapping something too large to fit into the return type of hashCode() when talking about the pigeonhole principle.  Applying the solution to SO's problem that the code in the post is MIT licensed will have a significant negative consequence on the ability to draw upon other resources for these sites to explain and transfer knowledge.

Comment: "the answer is critical because the answer will be copied directly into the code outside of SO". No, it won't. The example you chose is good to see this. Consider the first line, a package directive. In your own project, you wouldn't copy this. The next few lines are import statements which are simply required for Java to work properly. The next line is a class declaration. In your own project, you wouldn't copy this, but you would choose your own name. And so on... the result is simply *not a copy*.

Comment: @Brandin the POI one is where the code *won't* be copied.  However, you should look at the [others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13441470) link I provided and reconsider the practicality of C&P.  I contend that the POI question is an example where the *knowledge* is more important than the code - but is the rare exception of questions and answers on SO.

Answer (score 11):

**The terms under which users are willing to share their code can vary a lot.**

Some don't care about attribution, others consider it mandatory. Some want to release their code with no restrictions whatsoever.

**Votes on OP *and* answers are biased**

Votes on the OP or the top answers are biased for two reasons:

- Many users don't have down-vote rights on MSE, so they can't express their disagreement.
- An answer (especially on a matter we aren't experts on: law) can sound very .. accurate, while on the contrary, is completely wrong. I'm not saying most votes are bandwagon-votes, but some of them definitely are.

**Find out what users want the right way.**

If you truly want to accurately know how many users will be displeased or happy with this change, it might be best to make a survey.

Ask users how strongly they agree or disagree with *specific* proposals. Also, make sure you take into account that many (most?) users are unfamiliar with licenses and are not lawyers.

Comment: I don't think a survey would help at this point, judging by the way our SE overlords have handled this discussion so far. There's a huge difference between the question “Do you want to be able to freely use all code you see on SO?”, and “Do you agree to publish all your future code contributions under a liberal license so that other people can freely copy&paste from your questions and answers?”

Answer (score 10):

Let me break this down, because it appears no one is:

### What does the “Stack Exchange license” do?

It allows you to use code for any purpose, good, evil, and commercial, under these conditions:

- You provide attribution to the author
- By using the code, you agree not to hold the author liable for any damages for anything that may occur.
- A license file or header is not needed: attribution in the source code is sufficient

Quite frankly, *this is nearly public domain*. [This excellent question on Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1372/69) tells us how this is public domain. What’s happening here is that the author retains all of his or her moral rights - these are also rights which can’t be revoked by law in many jurisdictions.

---

Coming back to me, *stop complicating and confusing things.*

While the proposal is well-spirited in nature, we don’t have all the answers. When you’re speaking of something that strides into legal areas - *You need to have all the answers.* Simply saying, support us and we’ll think about it later just doesn’t cut it. You’re like me: I think of a wonderful idea, only to find that it sucks.

One other thing that I’m confused about: What was wrong with the status quo?

Stack Exchange endorsed the concept of attribution in posts. Under the Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license, people could take the information in posts, and use them in their works, providing that they give attribution to the original authors. It also included a ShareAlike/Copyleft clause - Any derived works needed to also carry this license.

I learn, take code, and participate in many Stack Exchange sites, especially Stack Overflow. Is any of my code under the Creative Commons license? No - And that’s the way it should be. I’m not directly copying code, I’m providing my own implementation for the ideas presented, and applying what I’ve learned in various answers. Regardless, [most of this stuff doesn’t meet a threshold of originality to be copyrighted anyway.](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/214/69)

If you’re seriously concerned about the legalese, quit making yet another license. Don’t make random exceptions that half the users here will even understand. Keep a simple, well-known license, that’s proven. The [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

This license is what many projects use anyway, including many of my projects, as well as in other projects. Look at [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org).

Here’s what it offers:

- A patent license - No one can trip anyone to copyright ideas (after all, what would be the point of writing an answer)
- Copyright assertion - Honestly, simply the NOTICE file with your name in it is fine
- No use of trademarks - I don’t want my name to be used to support an evil thing.
- Disclaimer of warranty and liability - If my code screws something up on your side, then you can’t come after me. After all, I just wanted to help.

---

What applies to what?

Honestly, just dual-license the posts. [I placed a bounty on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271117/289845), but didn't really get a good response. If we can't define what code is, then just make the entire post under both licenses. Don't overcomplicate it. People will choose which one naturally applies - It's common sense. I can't see how big of an issue dual-licensing could be.

Quit overcomplicating things. Please.

Comment: "You provide attribution to the author" - Debatable. In a closed-source project, there is effectively no public attribution since the attribution only exists in a source file. That's not attribution, IMO. | "Regardless, most of this stuff doesn’t meet a threshold of originality to be copyrighted anyway." - That's true for SO, but not necessarily for Code Review or Programming Puzzles.

Comment: @ThomasOwens What is this Programming Puzzles you speak of? Perhaps you mean [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)? All jesting aside, I think most of PPCG code wouldn't meet the threshold either. A huge amount of our challenges are things that have been done before, but this time with an emphasis on short code. Some of the code is original enough to be copyrighted, but the community consensus is that attribution is always required for copying/improving someone else's golfed code. Putting that in a copyright license would just be repeating ourselves.

Comment: Nearly "public domain", except that it's a crayon license so it's nearly "all rights reserved". Once again, it seems StackExchange actually desired CC-0, but can't admit it.

Answer (score 10):

## Don't assume what license the developer would prefer:

Instead of installing a global standard, give users the option (in their profiles) to choose which license they'd like to use for their answers or questions (two options).

The MIT license could be made the default for those who haven't chose differently, but effectively, let the user choose.

A button titled "attribute answer" similar to  The Science SE sites' Cite button could be added, which *using the user's preference* could generate a correct and relevantly formatted attribution block.

[image: freeeeeehaaaaaannndddd ciiiircccleeeeessss]

Of course you can't force users to attribute, but you can make it as easy as possible.

Additionally, this wouldn't only apply to the sites using code blocks, right? The other sites surely would like license freedom beyond Creative Commons?

Comment: I like this idea. When you see something, it is, via its author, attributed to some license, which is the author's best guess.  For instance, an author who posts mostly while sitting at his desk at XYZ Inc can simply say, "according to my employment agreement, every solution I post is owned by XYZ Inc, and may not be used in any product without the permission of XYZ Inc.".  Thus, when we use that user's snippet of code, we paraphrase the heck out of it so that it is no longer recognizable.  To be safe...ish we do that anyway even if the material purports to be BSD licensed.

Comment: And add a public domain option too. And tie the license at the time to the post so that it can't be changed. As it is I plan to explicitly release to the public domain everything I post to SO. The lack of the PD option is stupid. The paraphrase comment is insightful, as I rarely copy from SO, and if I do I refactor it into a better fit for my problem.

Answer (score 9):

As a Stack Overflow contributor, I want my *answers* to be CC-BY-SA, but the *code* therein should be considered public domain (or as close as is reasonable). My intent when answering someone’s question on Stack Overflow is that the answer should help others; I would be offended if some other website reproduced my answer without attribution, but I am *most certainly* encouraging others to use any code snippets I write on Stack Overflow.  Licenses that require attribution are *not* necessary in this context and while I’d appreciate a comment in their code if they copy something verbatim, and if it’s crucial to their product maybe a shout-out in the About box, **I really don’t want to force that**.  Especially so, in that sometimes those of us who write answers on Stack Overflow do so in order to encourage better practice, even among copy-and-paste "programmers", and I don’t want the world to be a worse place because some paste-jockey decides not to use my code because the license requires attribution.

For code large enough to think attribution is required, I will instead host a project (probably on Github or Bitbucket these days) and include a `LICENSE` file there to make clear my intent. You might say that “linking” answers on Stack Overflow should be discouraged, but I think it’s also true that answers with significant volumes of code are probably a bad idea, and **certainly** a bad idea if there is going to be any doubt about licensing.

There may be some other Stack Exchange sites where it makes sense to apply different rules; I accept that. But on Stack Overflow, I think a lot of contributors will feel similarly to me.

Accordingly, I have up-voted *the original proposal*, because that’s the closest to what I want, *and down-voted this one*.

**Addition**

It has been pointed out by some others that code in *questions* is a different matter to code in *answers*.  Those asking questions are generally not looking to provide code for others to use, so a more restrictive license might be applied there.  This is such a good point I thought it worth reiterating.

Comment: You know, just add a note to your profile, like "All code I contribute on SE sites is licensed CC0." There's nothing stopping you from dual-licensing to grant additional rights, you just cannot revoke any rights granted.

Comment: @Deduplicator That’s true, but that then creates a problem for *everyone* because they’ll have to go check peoples’ profile pages before using anything from an answer in their code. It might also change the way people vote on answers (maybe the best answer has a more restrictive license and so doesn’t get upvoted or accepted).

Comment: I have one request: if you’re stating that something is PD, please *also* include something like this: **In countries where the Public Domain status of the work may not be valid, I hereby grant a copyright licence to the general public to deal in the work without restriction and permission to sublicence derivates under the terms of any (OSI approved) Open Source licence.** That’s because it doesn’t cross country boundaries. (For this wording, we assume OSI doesn’t ever unapprove licences unless they should never have been approved in the first place.)

Comment: @mirabilos I have yet to see a cogent argument that a public domain declaration is not sufficient. No court is going to apply a restrictive license (which one, anyway?) to a work declared by its author to be public domain (the intent of the author is clear), nor is a court going to support copyright action by an author on the basis of an implied license in such a case (again, the author’s original intent is clear and such action would be a violation of natural justice). There *might* be issues with moral rights, but you can’t give them away by license either.

Comment: @alastair two things: First, the author – in some countries, one cannot relinquish all rights, and/or there are good reasons not to do it (such as liability; some can be disclaimed, but if you don’t have a disclaimer you’re liable for more by default).

Comment: @alastair Second, the recipient – the Berne Convention harmonises copyright internationally by making copyright protection (and thus licences, which build upon that very protection) work across country boundaries. It does *not*, however, do that for Public Domain works. For those, only the PD-after-copyright-protection-ended part of the copyright law of the country of the recipient applies. (In fact, someone working for the USA government could sue someone in Europe over using his PD (in USA) code, someone on the OSI mailing lists remarked, though nobody would probably do so.)

Comment: @alastair To mop it all up though – if you want to add code to a work of your own which you then wish to licence to someone else (no matter whether commercial, copyleft or permissive) you need a licence to do that for the code from others you add. PD is not a licence but the absence of requiring one, and, as I pointed out, does not work in many cases. (Not suing is not “having a licence”, only “not enforcing the rights I reserve by not giving a licence”, meaning taking PD-in-USA code then redistributing under, say, GPL, is a crime in other countries.)

Comment: @mirabilos None of those arguments hold water IMO. The first relates to moral rights, which would only be a problem if e.g. you used software to facilitate prostitution or WMD or something equally controversial and credited the author.

Comment: @mirabilos The second is only kind-of true (not least because not every country is a Berne Convention signatory in any case), but if you declare something public domain, no foreign court is going to support a claim that you didn’t mean it in their jurisdiction. Why would they? The US govt case is interesting though, because it hinges on the fact that US govt works are not eligible for protection *under US domestic copyright law*; it doesn’t actually involve any kind of declaration stating that the work is public domain.

Comment: “if you declare something public domain, no foreign court is going to support a claim that you didn’t mean it in their jurisdiction” doesn’t matter because declaring something PD does not *exist* in my jurisdiction. And the absence of a licence clearly makes a work proprietary and most uses of it forbidden. That’s a by-default ever since the Berne Convention (it was not so in the USA before 1989/1990).

Comment: @mirabilos Nonsense. There may be no mention of an explicit mechanism for declaring something to be public domain in the law, but that does *not* mean that a declaration of that kind is not a clear declaration of the author’s intent. If you went to court, having declared XYZ to be in the public domain, seeking licensing fees for its use, you would lose, in any court, anywhere, because your original intent was clear and it would be unjust to allow your demand for fees. The only time you might not lose is if you have moral rights that are being infringed, and licensing doesn’t help with that.

Comment: @mirabilos If you know of a case where a court has supported a plaintiff who has declared work to be in the public domain *and then successfully sued for infringement*, cite it. Otherwise, I say you (and others like you) are being needlessly legalistic.

Comment: No, that’s completely irrelevant. If I release a work foo, which contains (relevant) parts of bar, and I wish to put a licence on foo, the licence I get for bar has to allow me that, for my own licence on foo to be valid. This is completely separate from whether the author of bar would sue me over it.

Comment: @mirabilos If the author of bar has declared it public domain, I say no court is ever going to object to your license, and the court will hold your license valid. *If you know of a case where a court has done otherwise, cite it.* Otherwise, I say again: you are being needlessly legalistic.

Comment: In front of a court (and on High Sea) you’re basically in God’s hand. I would not trust your *overly optimistic* interpretation, especially when I have a lawperson’s different advice (not legal advice, but still advice from a lawperson). IANAL so I don’t have the means to search for actual court cases myself, but the absence of such does not even prove your point (negative proof fallacy).

Comment: I do have advice though that, if something is lawfully PD in the USA, a US-American citizen can lawfully create a derivative work of it and licence the whole. This is extremely USA-specific though, and I doubt you’d want to make most non-USA-citizens go through an intermediate (plus, Germans couldn’t even post here any more then).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/974/discussion-between-alastair-and-mirabilos).

Answer (score 8):

I find this is workable.

1. I generally use inline links to SO when code has been significantly influenced by the answer, **AND** the code has a level of sophistication likely to confuse future and junior developers.  This is a practice I use sparingly – often near advanced object patterns or specific algorithm conventions.
2. I put SO links in the body of a commit message when code has relied on SO answers.  This let's me reference things again later, as needed, but keeps the comments out of the project files.

#### When Not To

1. If the code is demoing how to use a basic API feature of a language or framework, I consider the SO 'answer' more useful than the docs.  In this case, I do not make a link attribution because SO and community have only succeed in being better than the public-domain documentation.

I still agree with [other comments — *that this direction has issues.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271113/194328)

Comment: It isn't clear to me that a link in a commit message is considered sufficient attribution. Since this is such a sensible place to put the link for future reference, it would be very helpful to have confirmation of whether this also counts as sufficient attribution.

Answer (score 6):

## Copyleft to copyright

### Openness

Overall, this is a great decision. Given that Code Review is pretty much a repository of code, it's ideal for new posts to hold the [MIT license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/). It is the most permissive open source license, before hitting the public domain.

- Provides zero warranty on the code, placing all liability on the end user.
- You may use the code in closed source, private software.
- You are not required to list modifications to the original code.

### Using in source code

The only thing I am unsure about is the requirement to include the MIT license in your code.

- If I use MIT code from SO, where, if at all, do I place the MIT License in my source?
- If I take source code and use it as an SO answer, will it become MIT Licensed?
- If so, can I explicitly state a different license for my answer?

---

## Attribution

### Within [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Most do not realize that the current license, CC-BY-SA], *requires attribution*. (And, as mentioned above, explicit notices of modifications.) With even stricter guidelines, that means everyone should be citing links to Stack Overflow in their source code.

**But they don't, and this won't make them start.**

If you take the time to read the license, you will see:

> **Attribution** — You must give ***appropriate credit***, provide a link to the license, and ***indicate if changes were made***. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

Given that all previous posts will remain (so far) under CC-BY-SA, that means I would need to cite when I use code that joins tables in MySQL, or tells me how to amend commit messages in git.

### Within vanilla MIT (which this isn't)

If anyone does link to an SO answer, it's because they want to reference it later, not because of attribution. So a vanilla MIT license would be perfect for everyone.

**But a vanilla MIT license is not being proposed.**

Rather, one that includes, no, *requires* attribution, much like the original license.

### On the legal side of things...

With either CC or MIT, I could, in theory, write a web scraper of all public Github repos and ensure that my code was attributed. But if someone were to do this, they would be suing a lot of people. Again, because **most people just don't care**. Does StackOverflow have plans on how to handle this? Or even address this concern?

---

## *What is code?*

We need to know this definition ***now***, before anything changes with the current system. Here are some questions:

- Must the sample successfully execute? (Many *questions* include errors in code.)
- What about pseudo code?
- Will Documents place a [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) license on answers that spit out documentation? Such as `git amend -m "message"`? I *will not* attribute to using simple scripts like this.
- How about languages where `(()()()((((()))())(` is valid code? Or even the *public domain* works of [Shakespeare (lang)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_Programming_Language)?

This brings up even more concern. What about the *words* used to explain something? Given an answer does not include code, to help the asker figure it out themselves, **would my *explanation* be licensed MIT?**

I don't think it should be. As [someone mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273072/261278), **I want my *explanation* covered by CC-BY-SA and require attribution.** But I want my code open-sourced without restrictions to help everyone out.

Answer (score 6):

Others have already said this, but I figured I would add this in. Your argument is seriously flawed. Specifically, you are under the belief that your recent proposal was accepted due to a *percentage* of up-votes that you received. However, you are making the following underlying premises/conclusion.

1. All Users on SO/SE can Upvote
2. All Users on SO/SE can Down-Vote
3. In Order to Upvote or Downvote on a "Meta" Issue, you must be part of the "Meta" community
4. All SO/SE Users are part of the Meta Community
5. Therefore, all Users on SO/SE can Upvote/Downvote a "Meta" Issue.

On top of that, you are making the following assumptions about the Upvote/Downvote process.

1. Upvoting indicates factual evidence of approval for the *Entire* Post
2. Downvoting indicates factual evidence of disapproval for the *Entire* Post

This isn't true. One can upvote/downvote a post because of a *single* sentence. Not only this, but upvoting/downvoting is often done for reasons other than objective reasoning. For instance, (we have all seen this) someone may downvote a Python answer because it wasn't *their* preferred method of handling the question.

Therefore, upvotes/downvotes shouldn't be taken into consideration when making this decision.

What should be taken into consideration are the ANSWERS to the QUESTIONS posed by the community. A collection of this QA is seriously lacking, and something you should really put together.

In addition, here are some more assumptions/conclusion you are making, and these aren't even underlying, since you *explicitly* state them.

1. The community will understand how we will "distinguish code covered by each license regime" through a FAQ that has not yet been created.
2. The community will understand how we define "code" by a FAQ that has not yet been created.
3. The community will be able to ask questions, identify problems, and pose academic scenarios based upon the FAQs we have not yet created
4. Therefore, the community will have opportunity to respond to our FAQs on defining code, and how SO/SE distinguishes Code Licenses.

Obviously, (4) is not sound.

I believe you need to break these issues apart. You need to identify the main issues, create discussion posts, and provide QA sessions for *specific* issues. As this post, and the post before it stand, the variety/number of potential problems with the proposed change is too large for a single Meta post.

In fact, this post should be considered **too broad**.

Break apart the issues into their own discussions, link to them in this post. You will be able to get a better feel of the issues at hand in a more specific context.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** Expecting users of an Q&A site designed to inform/educate to cite where they learned something every time they use it does not work.  We need something specific to how our users use our content.

---

**Simple suggestion:**  You can use the code, but you may not republish it in a format intended to inform others unless you include the URL (and maybe the copyright)

---

**Rant/Explanation:**

It seems like you are approaching this from an open source project perspective, when this is a Q&A site, which is preventing the issue from being addressed.

Unlike an open source project, the question and answer format rarely lends its self to copyright compatible code.  It is usually too short, the names are chosen for demonstrating the principle, and it is out of context.  The only time I have ever been able to copy/past the code was when I made the question, included code, and the answer was an adjustment on my code.

Most users come to the site to learn how to do something, not to obtain code which solves their problem.  The content providers realize that this is the purpose and intent of the content they are providing.

What we need is something that recommends a comment with the URL be added to the code if they copied the code verbatim from the site and requires anyone republishing the information (blog posts, websites, pod casts, books, etc) to list it as a reference.  If they republish verbatim, they must also include the copyright notice(s).

Comment: I really like the use vs. republish thing. It probably should be a separate proposal, though, as it's tangental to the kind-of-MIT vs. CC-BY-SA license change; both the kind-of-MIT (as described) and CC-BY-SA already required attribution.

Answer (score 3):

I would *prefer* a solution that **removes** existing requirement for attribution.

If a user wants attribution and it makes sense (the code is **large and unique** enough), (s)he always may publish code on GitHub or elsewhere under any license and add a link and necessary explanations and excerpts to the SO post.

If Stack Overflow, Inc. wants attribution... Wait? Oh shi~

<sub>Although, attribution requirement will not stop me and (I think) many other users from posting answers on SO, just as it doesn't stop us currently.</sub>

Comment: We don't want link-only-posts. Or any other posts using other sides as a crutch any more than really unavoidable.

Comment: @Deduplicator, link-only posts are bad of course. But if someone wants to provide a solution large enough to think about attribution, it makes sense to host full code on GitHub and add to answer only general description and probably smaller code snippets. IMHO.

Comment: The attribution requirement is there only to compensate people for waiving the requirement to reproduce the entire MIT licence. Attribution is the bread for BSD programmers, we normally use the licence for that (plus the fact that it’s not normally permitted to remove copyright notices), but an attribution requirement is one thing I could consider waiving the reproduction requirements for.

Comment: I don't think people should require attribution for posts on Stack Overflow. Maybe on some of the Stack Exchange sites it makes sense, but on Stack Overflow, it's crazy. A lot of the snippets of code are small and probably would be exempt anyway because of copyright law, but while I think CC-BY-SA made sense for answers *as a whole* and is what people expect in that regard, I reckon most people figured their code would be copied and didn't expect attribution. Some level of attribution may still be polite, but I say let’s not force it.

Comment: @alastair small snippets aren’t covered by copyright law *anyway*, this is only for “significant enough” posts (threshold of originality). If you don't want to attribute, use the full MIT licence (which requires you, among other things, retain the copyright notice), so credit goes to the author of the code in both cases, which is all we (BSD people) want.

Comment: @mirabilos I’m aware of the threshold of originality — which is, I might point out, independent of the size of the snippet (though obviously harder to achieve in a small snippet). Having code on Stack Overflow under multiple licenses (or any kind of attribution license) would be a disaster, IMO, for reasons I gave in my own answer.

Comment: I upvoted this answer not because I agree with it, but because it makes sense. Do you want public domain? Just adopt the CC-0! At any rate don't invent a crayon license.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a very active user on Stack Exchange, but this solution seems a bit chaotic to me, and I think it might introduce more problems than it is meant to solve.

Most of the answers I'm looking for when I browse Stack Overflow are one-liners or very trivial solutions in a programming language I'm not skilled in. It would be rather ridiculous to flood my code with comments linking to entry-level Stack Overflow answers when I submit a pull-request on a Git repository written in [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29).

Also, I completely agree on the fact that the consensus was very partial. Stack Exchange is not only made of super-expert and super-active gurus, but also of thousands of programmers that give sporadic contributions with their humble (possibly wrong) answers and obvious questions — just as I do. This way, you have probably lost a huge slice of Stack Exchange contributors and users that just don't have enough rep to express their agreement or disagreement. For instance, I could not even upvote the answers that were in contrast with the proposal!

Please, reconsider, 
a Stack Overflow lurker.

Comment: Seems you are saying the code you adapt fails the boundary of copyrightability. So, what's your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the stuff I read here has been copied and pasted from another site anyway (like php.net). And this isn't a bad thing, people are answering a question hopefully in a way that helps someone but the idea I have to post a link to every SO article I read to get a couple of lines of code in my source is entirely absurd and completely unenforceable.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, this is still not thought trough well and I am against it. 
I upvoted the last proposal because I couldn't downvote yet and I thought it is great that you think about this and asked the community for feedback.

You choose to ignore the feedback and I have enough points to down vote, so take my downvote!

If you want constructive feedback:

1. Define what your goal is
2. Describe how your proposal helps reach this goal
3. For the 15 or so top answers to the last post, describe how they would influence reaching this goal
4. Discuss this with the community
5. Listen to the feedback

Comment: " I upvoted the last proposal because I couldn't downvote yet"... You can always no neither you know?

Comment: @Tim as stated, I upvoted because I think it is a good thing that they think about the (potential) issue and ask the community for feedback. My upvote didn't mean "I totally support exactly this proposal 100%" but more "Good that you are thinking about that, in my opinion the proposal is not very good this way, let's discuss". I merely stated that I couldn't downvote if I would have wanted to do so. Since now this upvotes seem to be understand in the first way and I can downvote, I downvoted this question. This means "The proposal is not very good this way, let's discuss it."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the change to a (default) attribution-required license, as consistent with CC-BY-SA for text.  If a user posting code feels this is an undue restriction, the dual licensing option (including placing code in the public domain, or others) is available.

I've upvoted this Question (as I did the original) not because I think it presents a final framework (although this is progress) but because I think MIT-style licensing with attribution is a better default than (what many would overlook) licensing code the same as the accompanying text exposition.

Here are some points, about which I can imagine consensus emerging:

(1) Simplicity of license requirements is good.

(2) Consistency of *default* licensing is good.

(3) Clarity about code licensing philosophy (as expressed by the default value) is good.

Various proposals to expedite code re-use are [cropping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272957/add-an-indicator-for-the-license-to-code-blocks-and-a-tool-to-copy-code-with-the) or [have been pending around a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow).  This isn't the place for addressing those details, but I would not downvote `this` as a proxy for not having optimized implementation details in place.

Comment: A crayon license is the opposite of your point (1), so the current proposal goes against your stated desires.

Comment: @Nemo:  I'm not sure we are on the same page re the meaning of "crayon license" and what it is the opposite of.  This [OpenSource.SE post](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem) gives Bruce Perens remarks on his origination of the phrase.  How does "crayon license" relate to the current proposal?

Comment: Does http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272993/248268 answer?

Comment: @Nemo:  While some of the answers on this thread use "crayon license" as a pejorative characterization, neither that Answer (by abligh) nor my Answer used it.  I was responding to your Comment trying to put your use of the phrase in your intended context, so that link doesn't help with that.

Comment: Ok. The original "definition" is «Crayon licenses show a lack of understanding of copyright law, license structure, and most important: what would happen if the license were to be interpreted in court»; two of the problems they pose are "License proliferation" and "Legal uncertainty" per the OS.SE post you linked. I'm stating two things: 1) all these characteristics apply to the terms proposed by SE in this post; 2) all of that is the opposite of "simplicity of license requirements".

Answer (score 2):

I get the reason why this is being done. From SE's perspective it is more protected against certain legal actions.

I love SO and use it all the time. Everything that I've submitted I want free and open to everyone who wants to use it.. period. (That's the reason I joined in the first place) I always saw SO as a community for sharing knowledge. Not as a potential paycheck for trolls.

The reason why I use SO is because there are great and intelligent people here who genuinely want to help people out. But if I start needing to have to add in code links to SO or possibly face legal action for using a snippet, I will reluctantly stop using SO.

Also, you talk about this increasing productivity. Well.. how about this hypothetical situation. I use a code snippet off SO that wants Attribution. I change all the variable names, I change the types of loops, I restructure it a bit. Now I have something that is indistinguishable from original code, but I've had to spend a good amount of EXTRA time doing these changes and I am also a criminal...

As someone stated above, you are creating potential landmines for developers with the current direction. Especially for people in companies with strict documentation standards. Whereas they are forced to take the shady route I described above or to spend a ton of extra time figuring out a different solution when the answer is already available.

### Possible solution:

If you want to cater to the subset of people who actually **DO** care about getting proper recognition, then add in a small checkbox into the answer form that says something like "Yes, I want Attribution for my answer". **THEN** add in filtering in your search functionality to remove those answers for people who don't want to have to deal with that crap.

Anyways, just my 2 cents. I get that this move will reduce the legal concerns for SE, but I'm concerned you may irreparably damage this community and open doors for other competitors when people migrate away.

I was actually quite lucky that a co-worker pointed me to this page. Otherwise I wouldn't even have seen this coming and perhaps gotten in trouble in the future. (Ignorance of the law is no excuse right?)

Also, not enough rep on meta to downvote. fml

Comment: Anyone who wants to provide their content under a _more_ permissive license than the one required by the TOS can do so. Everyone still owns the rights to his or her content. But if the default was "public domain equivalent", dual-licensing with more restrictive terms would be pretty much moot.

Comment: I get that, but most of the community seams to want the default to be open.  Why not implement the possible suggestion that I wrote, and then people who click that checkbox have their answer put under a different license than the default. Proper filtering can reduce accidental usage of licenced code. This should not be a hard thing to do.

Comment: I don't think its SE that has the legal problem but rather the *users* who occasionally may be told by their legal department "you cannot include anything that you got from SO."  SE can publish our works under CC-BY-SA without any problem - no matter if it is code or text. It is the users who consume that material that have the uncertainty (that would then extend back to the "should SO be something I am using?")

Answer (score 2):

### This is rather good now…

… considering a few things:

- Small snippets are not affected as they don’t reach the threshold of originality under copyright law. This is just fine.
- People can choose the regular MIT licence for posts, or just attribute. I’d be fine with waiving the MIT reproduction requirement for an attribution requirement. However, people should probably be made aware that, when they include SO code with attribution requirement into their own code, they can only publish it under licence terms that keep the attribution intact (or choose the full standard MIT licence for the snippet they took).

### … except for one b̲i̲g̲ thing:

‣‣‣ [What part of an answer is actually code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271117/234382)

I cannot stress this point enough. This *absolutely **must*** be clear *before* this goes into effect, and the only way to easily make it clear is *to use the same licence terms for the entirety of a posting*, as I’ve already [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271182/234382).

Answer (score 1):

The meta community, as others have noted above, is not representative of the SE user base. Like many SE users I rarely, almost never, participate in meta anymore due to the general hostility to new ideas and the skew of the small number of pundits who dominate meta and downvote anybody that does not share their viewpoints, which seem at least to me to be somewhat parochial, if not downright cliquish. So, pretending that meta votes represent a vote by the user base I think is completely disingenuous.

As for this attribution proposal, it does not have any legal basis for a variety of reasons, so it is nothing more than bureaucratic sound and fury that signify nothing other than confusing people and adding FUD to the site.

No lawsuit ever in history has been won by somebody against another person for "failing to attribute" their open source code (cite one if I am wrong) so saying that attribution is "legally required" is simply wrong. This is due to lack of harms and a variety of other legal issues too abstruse to get into here. The bottom line is that you will not ever prevail in court on this "legal requirement".

Secondly, asserting that SE "owns" the code submitted here is a pretty dubious claim, if that claim is being made. Are you saying you own my code? You would get laughed out of court if you brought that to trial. Since you don't own any of the code here, making dictates about attribution of *somebody else's* code seems highly out of turn to me.

Comment: I would need to read the full ruling, but it appears that [Jacobsen v Katzer determined that all open source license conditions are enforceable as copyright condition](http://newmedialaw.proskauer.com/2008/08/13/federal-circuit-says-open-source-license-conditions-are-enforceable-as-copyright-condition/). That means that I can choose to sue over failure to attribute.

Comment: @ThomasOwens That is pretty interesting. Nevertheless, I think SE would have a hard time trying to enforce an attribution of a user-submitted code snippet, regardless of that particular ruling.

Comment: The copyright holder can also enforce. Granted, it may be difficult (especially if the software is closed-source). But I, personally, prefer to have a solid legal ground to stand on to protect my personal intellectual property.

Answer (score 1):

## Simply use CC0 for Stack Overflow code

I do wonder why everybody looks so reticent to the public domain (or getting close to that), since Stack Overflow answers have always been used that way.

Using CC0 will not prevent well-meaning people to include a reasonable attribution to your answer. Also, it will not prevent other people to not attribute your answer on other works. Again, as always.

CC0 is entirely [reasonable for documentation](https://creativecommons.github.io/labs/2011/05/28/fsf-recommends-cc0-for-code-snippets-in-documentation.html), which is, in fact what Stack Overflow mainly is.

From Stack Exchange's team, the fact is that trying to "not mess up" things by providing a different clause on the terms of use of Stack Overflow, are messing up all other sites on which a permissive license is not that reasonable.

---

If you will downvote, please comment reasons. No replies will be given from my part.

Comment: People downvote because they believe in copyleft, for instance. I do but I upvote this anyway because CC-0 is honest, while the StackExchange proposal is completely deceptive. However, you still have to solve the problem "what is code?".

Comment: I think I can comment, since is not a downvote :P with CC0 does not matter, anything which can be run or written ```like this``` does not require attribution, any explanation does (while is not a code comment, as // /* */ -- #).

Comment: Using CC0 will take away any possibility from Stack Exchange to fight against scraper sites that do nothing but mirror SE content and slap ads on it.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with attribution by default.

I don't want to have to add a comment in my code for [every](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502559/425313) [single](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867228/425313) [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904782/425313) or [trivial function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249777/425313) I copy and paste off of Stack Overflow. Isn't it true that I would now be required to do so, no matter how minor? I add [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071214/425313) in [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521572/425313) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285146/425313) with the knowledge that others will be copying and making use of it. I can't imagine posting anything substantial enough within an answer for me to care about attribution.

<sub>I am really just trying to get an accurate pulse on this single issue.</sub>

Comment: You obviously don't realize that you should have been doing that since ever, given we're run under an _attribution required_ license. It's a problem that is tangential to the MIT license issue.

Comment: It's certainly good practice to link back to the source for anything of significant size, and I do often.  Again, this is more of a measure the pulse answer.

Comment: Not every single one-liner or trivial function would require attribution. Only work subject to copyright can be licensed. There is a [threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality) that must be passed. Many code snippits on SO won't cross this threshold of originality, but entire posts may. However, on other sites (Code Review, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf), the code posted may likely cross the threshold of originality.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sorry, I wasn't exactly clear, and thanks for making it more precise. The point is: the new licence doesn't change the fact that you have to attribute.

Comment: @yo' You're right. However, *most* of the code on SO now doesn't require attribution.

Comment: @ThomasOwens So now for me to use SO, I'll have to be a software developer (student or professional) AND acquire legal knowledge about originality and copyright? Like I've been saying throughout this whole mess, I don't care if you don't attribute any of my answers to me and I would certainly not want to have that burden over my head.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu If you are posting content on the Internet or using content that you found on the Internet, you should understand how that content is allowed to be used and what restrictions there are on it. Things on the internet aren't freely available to do whatever you want with - that's not how intellectual property and copyright work. And as a subject matter expert, I very much care about attribution to myself and receiving appropriate credit for my contributions.

Comment: Having restrictions around how content is allowed to be used is certainly the legal default and one method, but expressly allowing code to be used with absolutely no restrictions is a second. It simply sounds like both Marco and I would prefer that StackExchange establish itself in the second camp, thereby mitigating any negative consequences of making a mistake.  Though by the vote so far it seems Thomas and the majority prefer the first.

Comment: @ThomasOwens really, who is going to evaluate what is original and what isn't? It can be a very thin line... And I'm sure 90% of users don't have a clue about the need for attribution at the moment.

Comment: I disagree with attribution by default also, and I tend not to use code from Stack Overflow — but have written answers there. I would rather my answers were used, instead of being avoided because of attribution requirements.

Comment: @alastair If you disagree with attribution by default, why do you post there now? Everything is CC BY-SA. The BY means "Attribution". I simply want the same types of terms applied to prose to be applied to code - nothing more.

Comment: @BradKoch I don't want restrictions on how my code is used. My preferred licenses for things that I release into the wild are CC BY and Apache 2.0 - two very permissive licenses for content. What I want is attribution and recognition for my work.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Because I take the view that CC BY-SA applies to the answer *as a whole* and that (generally) the code I include is going to be too small for copyright to apply anyway.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe People not understanding the license terms is not a reason to not provide authors of work with a terms of use / terms of service that allows them to take legal action to protect their work.

Comment: @alastair Again, I agree with you for *Stack Overflow*. But this change is network wide. Although most of the code on Stack Overflow likely doesn't pass the threshold of originality. A small fraction, however, may. But what about other sites? I'm particularly looking at Code Review (where it is mandatory that you post complete and working code) and Programming Puzzles & Code Golf (especially the puzzles side - some of the puzzles get non-trivial implementations posted).

Comment: @ThomasOwens Agreed, the fact this change is network wide is part of what has made it so controversial; different rules make sense for some sites (Code Review is a great example).

Comment: @alastair With different rules for different sites, I'm worried that it would get more confusing. Especially since posts can be migrated. If someone posts a code review question on Stack Overflow where code is licensed one way and it gets migrated to Code Review, that's an issue. Other users or mods can't relicense code. You'd effectively have to tell people that they either need to go to a new site (and, oh, by the way, agree to a different set of terms of use) or not get an answer because it's off-topic on one site or the other.

Comment: @ThomasOwens That's certainly a good point, though the license for code in *questions* might reasonably be different to the license for code in *answers* (indeed, I’d support that idea; people asking questions usually aren’t providing code to be used, but as a discussion point).

Answer (score -1):

> Change 1 was made to accommodate contributors who want credit, plus to help developers identify the provenance of a Stack Overflow code snippet when they find it integrated into a project.

For these contributors that you speak of, this modification changes **nothing**.
These contributors were already covered by a clause in the original proposition:

> You don’t have to include the full MIT License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution **upon request of the copyright holder** (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in our terms of service.

The only difference is that instead of being an opt-in for those who want attribution, it's a mandatory for *everybody*.

What about those of us who are fine *not* receiving attribution?
What accommodations do we have?

Comment: Anyone who wants to provide their content under a _more_ permissive license than the one required by the TOS can do so. Everyone still owns the rights to his or her content. But if the default was "public domain equivalent", dual-licensing with more restrictive terms would be pretty much moot.

Answer (score -1):

I don't cut and paste code from here anyway - I mean, how many answers are complete solutions to begin with?

I give code away all the time in forums - just "hey, this should get you moving in the right direction" stuff - and it would be asinine to insist on attribution for all of it.

It's all cool with me, though - like I said, I don't cut/paste anything anyhow.

Comment: There are two halves for this. There is the legal department freaking out about copying someone's code without a license. There is also the *lack* of a disclaimer of warranty on the code. If someone uses the code you have provided under the CC-BY-SA license and it breaks things badly, things can go badly for the person who said "this code would solve your problem."

Answer (score -1):

Instead of one fixed license for all answers/code, why don't you offer one choice from multiple possibilities of licenses for each answer, similarly like YouTube videos can have one of two different licenses?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't we just have a supercomputer generate every combination of 20 lines of machine code and make it public domain, then 90% of the answers on SO would just be re-implementations of the same thing using different variable/function names.

The point is that SO is intended as a reference as much as a problem solving site.  Most of the usage indeed involves just reminding ourselves how a few lines of code work and pasting in/modifying/adapting to the current problem. It is a memory aid that saves us a few minutes of re-working through a problem in our head, or looking up in other less-efficient "spec" type references.

Forcing attribution for this is nonsensical.

Anyone requiring attribution should do so by having their own repository / blog post and by **requesting that Stack Exchange REMOVE any post which reproduces a significant portion of their project.**  So "attribution-needy" people can work it out with Stack Exchange.

There is of course the issue of people having a "3rd party"  post a codebase on SO, then quickly "use" the code, and when SE takes it down, they claim they got it from StackOverflow.  However, these are RARE cases and the POSTER can be tracked down and sued for damages.  But once code is on SO, it's of necessity open, for ever.  It becomes like E=mc2 .

Regarding Disclaimer, no one should be allowed to view any code without agreeing that all code is without warranty and NO ONE is responsible if the code damages their system/causes loss.

Answer (score -2):

**TL;DR**

I upvote your proposal; because a simple, single URL as a comment e.g. ...

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object
```

... is what I want to have in my code if I grab a fragment (even a large fragment) from Stack Overflow.

---

**What you are changing, and why you're changing it**

It's not wholly clear why you're making this change: neither this topic nor the previous one explains, very clearly, why you want to change something.

See also [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1#comment886549_272956) which says,

> What exactly is the problem that you are trying to solve here? ... there has been little justification for the change ...learn to use meta properly and write a feature-request that details an actual problem that you want to solve.

But I think I gathered that the problem (which you're trying to solve) is that the current CC-BY-SA license requires an attribution whose format is unreasonably large and detailed for developers who want to grab code fragments from StackOverflow.

The current attribution requirements are detailed here: [Attribution Required (2009, by Jeff Atwood)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this
> content, we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn't have to be obnoxious; a
>    discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

The new attribution requirement which you're proposing now is less onerous, i.e. it's simply:

> A URL as a comment in your code is reasonable attribution.

---

**IMO you could alternatively make this change on Stack Overflow only**

One further suggestion: maybe make this change for StackOverflow only, not for other SE sites.

For example maybe this new suggestion is less appropriate (maybe a more detailed attribution remains more appropriate) for code on CodeReview.SE, for example.

Comment: I don't think simplifying attribution is their main purpose, but to allow code to be used under a permissive license, like the MIT. But then the MIT's attribution requirements are stricter.

Comment: Usage of code is something else than republishing content. The latter is an effort against content scrapers.

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to present my solution to what I see as the true base problems we're trying to address here. At least part of my answer probably belongs on a feature request, but it seems relevant to the discussion so I'm posting here first.

**The problem(s)**

In looking through the answers and comments on this and other SE topics, I see two problems we're really facing – **legally protecting end users**, and **legally protecting contributors**. The two problems unfortunately have conflicting ideal solutions. The first is a *very permissive license* that allows any use of any knowledge/content/code on the site without attribution. The second is a *very restrictive license* that conserves all the rights of contributors, allowing them to contribute under as permissive or restrictive license as they desire or are able. Users themselves might need to contribute questions under more restrictive licenses, as well.

**The solution(s)**

What we really need is a reconciliation of those two, and a lot more official support around licensing.

First, protect contributors by:

- officially supporting per-contributor, per-post, per-code block license selection
- using a restrictive base license on all SE content which will allow contributors to choose their own license as they desire (this should probably be “choose from a small list of approved licenses of increasing permissiveness", rather than letting anyone choose any license they want). **The base license should be the most restrictive license we want to allow on SE.**
- defaulting contributions to the restrictive base license to conserve the contributor's rights, but making it obvious when posting what that license is,  and *making it easy for the original author to change to a more permissive license*.
- documenting license changes for auditing purposes (maybe separately from the edit history, maybe not).

Second, protect users by:

- allowing users, on a per user basis, to decide what licenses they're comfortable looking at content under. Assume that unregistered users are only comfortable viewing public domain content (Note: I know public domain isn't a license -- and in practice we should probably use CC0, WTFPL, etc.)
- **hiding** content that is under a more restrictive license than they would like to see.
- displaying license information for posts license the user has already accepted prominently. Put the post's license in a hyperlink near the author's name. If a code block has a different license than the encompassing post, display that at the bottom of the code block (automatically). Do the same for a block quote. The license link should preferably have a display text with the license's common name, and link to a page that displays the rights and restrictions in plain English, as well as contains the full legal text (or another link to that). It might also be useful to have visual cues for the license, so that at a glance an end-user knows how they can use the content.

In addition, it would probably be convenient to hide the content of post with a license that hasn't been agreed to, to save screen space. It would also be convenient to allow users to easily view those posts by agreeing via a pop-in notice/dialog on a per-post, per-code block basis. Those exceptions should be recorded so an audit trail exists to maintain plausible deniability, however.

Another benefit is that if contributors choose to re-license their contribution, users are automatically protected -- if they used it previously under the terms of the old license, they're fine. If they need to use it again, they have to agree to the new license beforehand.

To address some other concerns: We don't need to define “code,” as contributors already do so with the code block. We don't need to worry about the legality of the contributor-selected license, or whether it is enforceable, either. That is up to the contributor if they choose to try to enforce it.

The biggest legitimate concern I saw from contributors is that they only provide answers here to build their professional reputation and that attributions are important for that. This approach allows them to continue that practice. It also takes away what I feel should be an ethical dilemma for them: they are in a position to demand attribution for answers placed on a medium most users assume to be public domain -- answers that I suspect would be seen much less if users could hide them. Instead, now they would be able to demand attribution (and any other restrictions they prefer) at the cost of limiting their audience only to those who agree to their terms which is a much more fair proposition for all involved.

Comment: Why should anonymous users be prohibited from learning from Q&A under CC-BY-SA?

Comment: Why should anonymous users be subjected to legal threat without asking them?

Comment: To add to that, though, I think most answers / contributors on this site will quickly default to a public domain license anyway and it will be a moot point, for exactly that reason. I suspect that relatively few people on this site want to limit the audience of people that they can help just to require attribution. Those people will be free to do so. I don't think it's fair for anyone to be able to throw anything out there and require attribution, though, especially not in a climate where 9 lines of generic array code can lose billion dollar lawsuits. Deniability helps a lot with that.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest to introduce code signatures as a common practice in the same sense that paintings have traditionally been signed by the artist.

Such a signature would be some short URL pointing to a site explaining the licensing of the code. Ideally the signature would be partly a personal id, partly a an optional hash identifying the snippet, partly an optional obvious id of license type.
Like: `si.gn/codeguru42[/cc-by-sa][/a1b2c3d4]`

Then, people could decide to either sign their code that way when putting it online in any forum, and doing so would generally imply that they intend their work to be used with that signature included (as reasonable attribution), with license restrictions imposed as described at the link target.

Not doing so would imply that they intend to put their work in the public domain (use CC-0).

Also ideally common license providers should also provide such static links, so that it is possible to add `// si.gn/apache2` as short comment to code instead of the full apache2 header. Because while a full header is legally nice, it is just noise in forums, and prone to be cut out when pasting code to the internet, or back. They just get in the way of everything.

Comment: People cannot relinquish their work into the Public Domain in many countries. That makes reusing such work by anyone illegal. Not to forget country boundaries (the Berne Convention only applies to copyrighted works, *not* to PD).

Answer (score -4):

And this is a problem with a seperate meta on top of the one which is already present on stackoverflow. You gain reputation on one of the sites that lets you interact, but then a decision is taken on another one that would apply to the first one and you cannot down vote it let alone even up vote one of the responses.

This is a problem that should be addressed. I would have up voted one of the existing answers on this question which address my concerns, but I can't when I would have been able to do it on the stackoverflow meta.

Open it up to the sites which would be affected by the change to actually get the feedback instead of adding it on a meta which is harder to participate in.

Comment: That is all true, but this is not an answer to the question and your concern is already raised [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273000/change-rep-required-to-downvote-on-mse). For normal site meta's you'll need 5 rep so I don't think it is strange to have a similar barrier on the network-wide meta. Upvote privilege comes at 15 rep. That is 7 suggested-edits (or get the association bonus at 200 rep on any other site).

Answer (score -5):

> Change 1 was made to accommodate contributors who want credit, plus to
>   help developers identify the provenance of a Stack Overflow code
>   snippet when they find it integrated into a project. Change 2 was made
>   to allow you more time to digest this change and socialize it within
>   your organizations.

*Accommodate contributors who want credit*

Contributors already get credit by up-votes and other awards on Stack Overflow. They can even see the views of the answer and their impact to get a good estimated of how much people use their code/answer.

*Contributors still cannot identify the provenance of a Stack Overflow code simple because*

Even if people add attribution, how and when are you ever going to see their source code? Lets guesstimate a little. Say in your lifetime you see 0.001% of all code written. Of that code 0.001% is relevant to any of the Stack Overflow questions you have answered. Of that code 0.001% of the developers saw your stack overflow questions. Congratulations, you now have a 0.0000001% chance of ever seeing a piece of code with a link to your answer on it. Rejoice!

Comment: "Credit" is synonym of "attribution" in that sentence. In fact "credit" literally translates into "attribution" in some languages (e.g. Italian "attribuzione [di paternità]").

Answer (score -6):

The solution to this problem is to make code Public Domain by default, and let the individual code authors explicitly identify which license they prefer, if any.

Comment: What is code? You have to answer this question before making any further changes. And please, stop flogging this already dead horse/question. There are relevant threads here on Meta SE explicitly asking for input.

Comment: First, could you give an example of when code is ambiguous? It seems pretty clear to me what code is.

Second, I submitted one answer, which hardly constitutes as "flooding" anything. If the actual moderators have a problem with receiving any new answers, then they can lock down this question.

Comment: This cannot work because people cannot relinquish their work into the Public Domain in many countries. That makes reusing such work by anyone (including SO/SE themselves) illegal. Not to forget country boundaries (the Berne Convention only applies to copyrighted works, *not* to PD).

Comment: You can't meaningfully apply a _more_ restrictive license to something that's compelled to be available under a permissive license like CC0, and I don't believe you can offer a license _at all_ to something that's truly in the public domain. If it's in the public domain, that means that you simply do not hold any copyright to it.

Answer (score -8):

What if a developer writes a piece of code that happens to be exactly the same as what was posted on Stack Overflow, without actually seeing it on Stack Overflow?

Would you the developer be liable?

And can anyone be liable if the offender can claim it's their own invention and never saw it on Stack Overflow?

If it's that the date on Stack Overflow is older, must developers now check for every line of code they write if it's already on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This was never an issue, even before the proposed change. What you describe are trivial pieces of code.

Comment: Copyright law is all about *copying*.  Independent creation is entirely permissible.

Comment: @Mark But how do you prove that it was an independent creation? If it happens to be the same code.

Comment: @MrFox, either the code is trivial and is thus ineligible for copyright (there are only so many ways you can call `fopen()`), or there's enough freedom for individual stylistic variations (eg. variable naming) to show up.

Answer (score -10):

This is a **good change**. It essentially legalizes what is supposed to be good practice anyway (provide a comment linking to StackOverflow), and does so in a manner that is clearer than CC-BY-SA. The only problem is trying to come up with a legal definition of code; it may just be better to license the entire text under MIT.

It is a bit of a shame that this change is divisive within the community, but opponents should keep in mind that if this change doesn't happen, it *won't stop the current status quo*. People will still just copy code from StackOverflow right now and claim it as their own, still providing that link. The only difference is that they are potentially liable to be sued (since CC-BY-SA may arguably imply that the person might need to license their code under a copyleft license), but who actually is able to sue them? It's either:

- The original poster (well, good luck tracking every single repo on your own to make sure that your sacrosanct code is not being copied...and then finding a lawyer to represent you)...*or*
- StackOverflow (which, quite frankly, is more worried about monetization than they are about policing your code)

If a law is not properly enforced, it might as well not exist. Better to change your policy to something that people will actually adhere to.

Besides, contributors are not the only people in StackOverflow. This website is a resource for *all* programmers, to use as they see fit...and I doubt that all those programmers are actually active on Meta. Ideally, programmers should learn from these code snippets that they are using, but think what happens if they don't learn.

If programmers are copying and pasting from SO too many times, then they're only harming themselves and their final codebase (since they got a bunch of code but are unable to comprehend what it does). Everyone looking at the code will know that the programmers in charge doesn't actually know what they're doing, and the resulting codebase will be an unmaintainable mess. I think that's a good enough punishment for them, far more so than the potential of legal threat that may or may not actually be acted upon.

Comment: Many of us can agree that the status quo is not ideal, but going ahead and explicitly *allowing* bad behavior (as this appears to, inadvertently) is not progress.

Comment: *People will still just copy code from StackOverflow right now and claim it as their own* And they will still do that even with the proposed licensing changes...

Answer (score -10):

1) One day a long time ago, I received an answer from a good Sir named @dawg: https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg. He is one of the most talented and friendly people I have ever met on this site. I look forward to citing `@dawg` on my next work so that the whole world recognizes his contribution and finds out from his profile that "On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog".

2) 99% of the people using Stack Overflow do not even have an account on Stack Overflow and, if they do, they probably do not have 125 rep to upvote/downvote any posts here on Meta.

3) Hence, 1% of the people using Stack Overflow are currently trying to make a decision for 99% of the users.

4) If I knew this was going to happen, I would have stayed in Russia: a place known for its oligarchy.

5) Please do not cite `@warship` in any politically sensitive documents.  Too bad I stand to lose this privilege on March 1, 2016.

Comment: *99% of the people using Stack Overflow do not even have an account* where did you pull those numbers from?

Comment: Common sense...