# Worst Voted Question Asked

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

Is there any way I can check *all* Stack Exchange communities to find the worst (or best) voted question (as of now). I found one with -10 votes, and I forgot where that was. For curiousity, how many votes will it take to ban (or promote) a user?

Comment: The algorithm for banning is kept secret, to prevent people from gaming it.

Comment: You mean your own posts, or any posts?

Comment: Which are the worst voted questions and or posts? Is there some way of keeping track?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to know the [most downvoted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166280/most-downvoted-answers) or the [worst scoring post](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/510152/worst-scoring-posts), SEDE is the way to go.

For example, for Stack Overflow:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797328/993547) seems to have the worst score (-62). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/871420/993547) the most downvotes (227);
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21068763/993547) seems to have the worst score (-154). And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/993547) the most downvotes (218).

For MSE:

- [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/245360) has a score of -270 having 440 downvotes;
- [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/245360) has a score of -215 having 249 downvotes.

You can run this query for the site you want, or with some extra work run it for all sites in the network at once.

Note that this queries will only return the posts that are not deleted. Deleted post can't be queries using SEDE.

SE does not release any information on the script determining when someone gets banned or not. That is kept confidential to prevent misuse of the algorithm.

Comment: Worth to mention the -270 scored question got 440 downvotes, maybe worth running the queries to get most voted posts with only up/down votes, not net score.

Comment: Indeed. Updated @Sha

Comment: The worse non-deleted downvoted answer on MSE was posted by Jeff Atwood himself. Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

The worst question seems to be [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/) with a score of -270. The best question is the well-known [branch prediction question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array).

I found them using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/510148/645476/) - keep in mind that the data is refreshed once a week on Sunday morning.

```sql
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #worstquestions (site nvarchar(250), id int, score int, title nvarchar(250));
create table #bestquestions (site nvarchar(250), id int, score int, title nvarchar(250));


open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ';
    insert into #worstquestions 
    select top 1 ''' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ''', id, score, title
      from posts
      where posttypeid = 1
      order by score asc;
    insert into #bestquestions 
    select top 1 ''' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ''', id, score, title
      from posts
      where posttypeid = 1
      order by score desc';

    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #worstquestions order by score asc;
select * from #bestquestions order by score desc;
```

> For curiousity, how many votes will it take to ban (or promote) a user?

For banning, this will not be disclosed to mere users, like you and me. There's too much potential for abuse. I don't understand what you mean by promotion.