# What are the attribution requirements for using Stack Overflow code provided by users before 2016 for non-money-making purposes?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, attribution

Back in 2015 I posted a question in Stack Overflow, asking how to accomplish something in JavaScript. A few people replied, and in the end, I used a line or two from two or three replies. And after I had someone code review my script, there were some requested changes. The final version was restructured and streamlined.

I want to write a blog article talking about the purpose of the script and how it helps in iterating HTML and CSS development. I use the script at work, and it would be a good article on the company's blog. Since I received help with the script on Stack Overflow, I looked around online to get a clear idea of how I'm supposed to attribute that help. I found that the current license agreement applies to content posted after February or March 2016. I thought I also read that non-money-making uses only need to include the MIT license. However, there was something that said Stack Exchange will look into giving users an option to receive attribution for content created before 2016. But I can't find a final word. It all seems unclear and not final to me.

Can anyone shed some light on what I need to do given my particular usage?

Extra notes: The company's blog doesn't require any subscription or money to read the content, and there is no advertising. But it is a for-profit company. My other option is to open source this script in our company's public-facing open source repository. If these two options dictate different attribution requirements, please discuss.

Answer (score 3):

The MIT license switch which you talked about never really came into effect: a notice at the top of [the meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1) says:

> ### Update: January 15, 2016
>
> Thank you for your patience and feedback. We're going to delay the implementation for now - we'll be back soon to open some more discussions.

This means that the CC BY-SA 3.0 license still applies. It doesn't matter whether or not your blog is commercial, if you wish to redistribute the changes to your work you must do so under the terms of [the license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). In other words, you'll have to provide attribution and share your code under the same terms (e.g. by putting it in your open source repository, as you suggested).

Disclamer: I am not a laywer, please don't quote me on this.