# How to give attribution when using the same code on multiple webpages

Tags: support, legal, licensing, copyright, creative-commons

I am very new to the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) community. I noticed that there are several excellent answers here that can help me to build a website. I am a little bit aware of the [License CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) applied to the different content of this website.

My question is about these lines of this license:

> "Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the License, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use."

Suppose I am going to use a single piece of code multiple times to make multiple web pages. Do I need to give attribution on each and every page? Or is giving attribution one time on a different page (let's say the *home page*, which is linked to each of these multiple pages) enough for all these multiple pages?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but I would imagine that the website as a whole could be considered, collectively, as a single "work", which would be covered by attribution on the home page.

Comment: There are some very knowledgeable contributors over at [LawSE](https://law.stackexchange.com/), but you should probably double-check this would be on-topic first.

Comment: I always thought that you are supposed to put the attribution in your source code (through a `LICENSE` file or through a comment block at the start of the code or similar), and not provide attribution in the resulting UI/binary/website. Creative Commons does not say anything about where to put the attribution though, only that they discourage the use of CC BY-SA for source code (!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required, Section: "[What is reasonable attribution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/282094)", and some of the comments.